# I before E, except after C

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, natural-language

You may be aware of the famous old rhyme, *["I before E, except after C"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C)*. It is a rule taught to aid in the spelling of certain English words.

Quoting Wikipedia:

> If one is not sure whether a word is spelled with the digraph *ei* or *ie*, the rhyme suggests that the correct order is *ie* unless the preceding letter is *c*, in which case it is *ei*.

It is well known that this rule is not always correct (e.g. `weird`, `leisure`, `ancient`). That is why you will be asked to write an algorithm which accurately determines the spelling of these words.

### Task

The following wordlist (found [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cXfzCckRM3/)) consists of 2967 valid words, each of which contains either `ei` or `ie` as a substring.

The input is a single word \$ w \$ from the wordlist, **but the `ie`s and `ei`s may be flipped** (all occurrences of `ie` are replaced with `ei`, and vice versa). You are to output a boolean value indicating whether \$ w \$ was flipped. The values do not need to be `True` and `False`, so long as they are consistent. Your program must work correctly for all words, including their flipped counterparts (for a total of 5934 cases to consider). [Here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PKcNFFvMbs/) I've provided of a list of all possible test cases.

**Note that you are not given this list as input.** You must find a way to determine, for any word in the list, whether or not it is flipped but you cannot take the list itself as input.

Just to clarify, no word in the wordlist contains `iei` or `eie` as a substring, nor do a word and its flipped version both exist in the wordlist. As such, these ambiguous cases do not need to be considered. However, words such as `friendlier` or `eighties` which contain more than one occurrence of `ei` or `ie` do exist in the wordlist, in which case both occurrences are flipped (`friendlier` -> `freindleir`, `eighties` -> `ieghteis`).

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

*As a side note, simply applying the "I before E, except after C" rule will be correct for `4954/5934` of the cases.*

Comment: ""I before E, except after C" rule will be correct for 4954/5934 of the cases"; But only test `ie` got `5036 / 5934` score??

Comment: Just created [A jsFiddle for simple regex based test](https://jsfiddle.net/whmr5zLb/)

Comment: [List of the 535 words with an exception](https://pastebin.com/cT5Xx7F6) (obtained by matching against the regex `(?<!c)ei|cie`)

Comment: @hakr14 Note, that list contains 36 instances of `eei`, (e.g. `agreeing`) which when flipped will yield `eie`, which is explicitly excluded from the cases?

Comment: Does it matter what the output is for a word not in the test cases?

Comment: @NickKennedy Don't worry, you only need to handle the test cases given.

Comment: @Arnauld The flipped version of `einstein` is supposed to be `ienstien`; all occurrences should be flipped. I took a look at your answer, and I think the regex is incorrect (`/ie|ei/g`, not `/ie|ei/`). I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Oh I see. I overlooked the last paragraph of the challenge. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Meanwhile, I was taught: "i before e except after c or when sounded as a as in neighbor or weigh"

Comment: Did you mean to tag this [tag:decision-problem]?

Comment: @user Yep, good catch :).

Answer (score 22):

## JavaScript (ES6), 338 bytes

A regex-based solution. This can probably be optimized some more.

Returns `0` (not flipped) or `1` (flipped).

```javascript
w=>/dief|egh|etei|it?ei/.test(w)|/^(a?th0[rs]|d0st|r?0|h0r?[1s]|w0r)|b0[gt]|c0(l|t[es1]|v)|cl01|d0(f|n[1es]|ra|tie|ty)|0([aijop]|c1|[df]o|g[hln]|na?[fgor]|rlo|[rs]u|s[ahims]|tf|tm)|f0n?[at]|g0g|h0(fe|k|n|re)|ip01|k0n|n0t|no?th0|o0s|r0n1|rel01|rg0st|s0(l|ne|z)|t0n[es1]|u0n|un01|v0(l|n[1es])|yth0/.test(w.replace(/ei|ie/,0)+1)^/ei/.test(w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZX1NkuS4kt7@nSKtF9NV9lqd1duR9fRKpyjrMWMGESQrSYANgBEZqZwbyEwbLaV76DxzAR3hyd2/zwHmTFtX@AeHAwRB/DgcDuSP4TaUS172@l9iGsM/rr//4/77vzyPS7h@hGn@CDUsH0v9IyzPv9ZQ6pf714/nf/0y/FHnb99z@fNj/FbqR/7j28f8Lf/x/Tfh3L/lrx8v375P9c@Py7cv60f9Hspvf37cvn5c1m@/SYov14/4/bcgsnn4qEv4qI@vH9@@fB@WH2mXRL99fB@vf6aP6fu8xj8/4vDH9@uUsoiv6UOfenyU78O8bJJDvX7U7evH9Vv84/sgT5y@TVKUL9fw8foRP3L4@rHs8tDXb/EjfqsfMWnJP9K38pG/xd9EQIuUJ32LooWN4eP960f9FlHoQ9IdUURuFmml/vrxkDy8Pn7NYV@HS/jyrDUVnn/59vXvv3391@dTjf3jkmKpT@siP78//TS8LKE8y@@6VKA1vCSp8lFgTHkbWkQJy0pisQYywRInIojGGsJSNsVHHpnFZRjDBnQJpaRMnLZ9iPbIho1/5OECOC/hpkUjbHR0sMkTz9gTaQEJGsuBlfmyjMsVz/7rkIddQkcnZjzz7VHAyKMuN3/FerQaU4xXlPo88MvAmxAtkscrZqrrdYkOl7BKGaZgTzFSjGrFTlImk5qmzKpwtD4EJ9TilAOSL5nZERRFi9aPkiKvtL6ERcm0WGWtS4j4HWpoYGyoOLLsCROTuFyLU@k1TPzmAvNEZJWvREN1yPsStLIbFPYmrdS@gIFqdDpYS/K5HUV5D6B95Vclyh31aEFxWNNEVBMapzyp1Ew4pxsRngyqNQykURPq0ahWZFy25J8zLiXVnHYE4nL66jH6K8Sk/cxQnVMrUV2sKwLuQ50d/@UNy7Bn8raEE5IS7gFS@zI4sKrd2yP2VOdw8dh9DSJhwOrOaCYVgXyZ5cuikrIMIOniHTSTuaUDeeUaHFgWpYTtBbmUx7YF1m8NeIKUwhq10ep0uXQkLeThIU2Y04XvrbU7W3mJhHeMbDAEypK6CiQaLMWCSjQo9Z6Z4VHTy5KmPHhmpxcVvDPFm4x6rLnbsKynMfRG/gtG1xfpmPqWoPJ6L8NroMB6QT8VtEFGqclEH0gE2oAMmkkh85qPvV4oVYftHpZp1pgs/3vyLMVQ4o/KGdkYVUbJ@h2uHSmzVi9krWvA4HHCGnFnee4sTxjAMApG1EeHodTVORU901FRdNQOPBYwn@BJQmFgtFLL@irljWMDoUMdhhxr0mXSUi0/wG@/FpUPzWu94uW1OvA7glxJGEdyw@d/tNAaOnSuszyrmxV/5exE5ACFWvmIKC958WYVMqm0RHsRoyOBJVyks/UmrKNmXIa1AWPJw5fILD8Js4m/LDJzBxIJimbx2p69DmWfMRbIo@r7q7DluWuC8kCQHZQGKpAMZrnUJuFBRN/HjEyO0B94SNefn1/SCzoVn8PMk3ctDGwvaZPmjQJoqycxgWhN0oiFE/NLr8ZXokEdGDKpyR064GcHZI2sv8RxRUCeQlqK5XW334e3S0cilocFxcrozAoKmnjWwTJrSkXCM3R38TvLnYd3ct6ZLgRyDJhMuLMPZ2u4@nsZSuiIUVqTRjOppRZgjYmAstqcMzoAx4@8TOz4jpSZ7lbRoMo4ouihQmob2I6XFxv/CfShx4jqOMZJUxvR4ES6viKBUpOHAgGqAtsOAaUmEPH4I8vY4eO4hKaVn@5AWzs8xBJlL5DP1y9HmRGl1KIKUhayKeWRleyHN9JDh9SrlVNUYe1bICOpstGMZbobNlSSwAvGREGqPjm1qGOLQNuQRbtGNDv1hU1LaLIxDsCyB0DcjswjlJTLsPepTAOXBpd19ZyzyGiLXJ4vjZWRD2aXi88uAEpRfaTGEF2ZedcLIw1YEatrixeZX1fEAkgLdGix8nJKWE5djYyzUzL07UGVIWuc7NKii6CPqF6fUU@GoCydMEQOCuewYT4VWKU3V8f8WETCmweMHAT6coJGqD4dQhKKkaB8OSq@5@wzuaLVOCG8IrEByzGE7KzsLNb8LMFA9V8CXptzuHdqCXSQsF@t4dn6uBF9v46MuTKPBf3OgeUSZfxj0ZfbzWpjTqkgQdr3E7AEopi4RnqZj4hX4ysvNyfeJLUNooqJjIfhmkBzNeRygPkES8cKuRy5rKblg0gzIdKIVNFCCYx1jGQdIx96bCyHAWWlYWXNO5Kk6YKXNGpSl1cbVQSN0gaDUpYewGLYJFO4qjZgJe1YJVZrHokfBxRpVzYxgAeBMdiMBRQugWQVHkYCXU2zi0sgcS1vuGmoGjpiw1zBG5I1zNKldulsWLZqYA1vPWbFy247i7XpeKb6yaYh0eGX6tQEDXlUU79aUL9dw43fmC2LW2h5WNdP1lcnExyPvrJXs8kFi4oOz2xdMl5eZcnsLFkMH@VzCAXpYVmvQiLkmyw/sz9IhuZWTbHsC2ctM90MMtUNTbIu9TiJHrJqbqEatj2JfhFYMQx7Wl2396QSOtqbykLKLBII3WSB7S/u@BRRT9BeEBrUhfNKQnc3Qq6SHL1XEBkztRlGsE9jHDmSd6iytdFCWuy5L9gqIzswYY6hqp/JEIhG1LCVr4esfC2I5tCCLS6HW1oPNXV4@aj7GXAWBmNQMGooHlc9snpsbQlqS2LanGgs13oC@lLyTV0tVhwJXP6dUmHAIANA1uasjSz7SHg4c1zKzmDhCJ2TZ5VaVhw1Mr8OqDEOJvcXSO@MOVyRyYcPI/kIq6MNyqAje4ro2jOZ0TWDTNWKQFmiNSItgLEwlavSeU15E2QNgdO3EDfRXKjyXVzlE5C9YxzUao7s6Woho@JzPqQJ6oA9UoUbh2UljVZMAsl4hKlNaQGF8jpSURt13FyFmG0CRLiymrYCEmhGQZseiUpAvyfVHEPT3sdwGa5XHUlr@BRQKRtVQa7H2pENTAiR3oLT0UF24CJ8XJ95JUDzoyLnoMhhv5KD/nsBm4FHg9UQBe2ZV0rKV8UXHGX1GwMHyTHMxwajrgoLvcAuadjyWZjDcn3gFyVUC9Ro@vEI5XgMnr@OoKqlXfwZq74/4NasQ2OIeEDEs6O1e6NGime3q3XC33jXhpiY2X5QJL@ASgtHci7@x0U0J07T4wJ1UmgfjnRZYWsK@RF9sVGLWcNFp6kTNDZ@tOkZOYtJ0GKr/QyiOShF9lXfUkmFbFUTRewICa1yldYWWVuk/uoAfmAUGJcp8ispqv5KE5ULNeTMDqySjVodZCk0q3HRgXUkzaTON@HS1zgacCu5YBp5HGm7b3A84XzGpQfO2Whg1Rorn2ZYC3v7ESzrC87aEgobTRuCZ5S@pJdAg2YP2Fvo@54RunUPsTAtqN3Ag5DcfXGhWJqo13j5Szcy@ClagDFoDgB8hOFjtBIWeVLxpB6wpGXZlvX0xLroTgAClUzTPJjaceO7zNIaxPs7Kukd096YLkdXWcc0oplQ2x2hjYw2dLCx0NJDqgyYNUEtyzsl8SifkQVMKWI9L5jWdkHHNLsAoGbic@/Y5l5F2VmZLHtvclEc5urxttolVb6q6nzZnPh6ACaf7oWsO/SnsW1QiXqLvnRsmz3WqIZFB7@4TLGZf@ScO3J8eqC7PGA1HR9xwM5LGDCZgsrjgm/ohLadE8zSBaISsN1o63YozIstvL0YQfoPxrxwERXY5sUA00nAtBvwoQNXTYGLJlsMP3Nt7CtjVxmty7XA47mrkg2t4Jq2GZZRM9FfaRLRkI58ak2OV9FPrH99ChUEi3bMEyRbFuJHOEFjzxW/IcQG6gx4TaIxGyJj8TTS@cjaUZMKGSevIE1FtRQBWeMkMI7XpHnVWd9p1c/ndb3q7EP9klMB6nQNqIfthapJG6sIjJPTMqIrhE1XUqzmTYeC3KCvq2T69E@@7RV57dbUQItTFThWjga@DaXTPsoUqQuE2NSCEGVQwhOlBod1J/TYmnULghDUjBVGJLQv@4yVrMzRb0b/ap0n@L5bKLbOkQJyUy7UR1ughMPBTU1HLfHbJcjAx5p5C227smPlL63y3nb5DEMPcDZo8NFg7QiiuYsCjid8EtH@7IGqewXhTSrIqxL9XQg681UUHr6LQI6kgjiNX6noXkXBhWokiIO6o9xRjyZiJht22E4hA1oNI2l26hGNVgEwRV7dFCmgYJ6/Ds0ILbBCqqKZXYNuM2bupImyPEX86kOVWgYKipJY8YtYW1UDaGwbR68BC4kr@5Va2L0LXFXf0J8xbU7BtV/p8vYbnGanjLYnYglt5J7ya0cuDmwiccSv7qc4kIHuir0J/SL6iY2ALcBWBICZVOtqwcgK6gwmsl8Z70g0@ZUvfMWAdaX1UCisawSWUfQP7EjlcrgyRZkxyFypJoFaSqgEV1cJruvwYttdBGC9OmByAGOxjazBo0KPeuv2rOuKWBRtJQsGQAJLk1RvcKoyNIESNI4JH1f0DQCwXsnxInNRSqDpH95aE5QMUBVO2Hu@@gbZlZrQNSVdwArNaOGgJkpUHOLbC/bek2BJIdWipGYyISwOjmwPmfi1Ti5Fgk9Um0Ny6/lVt9aY4A3lf0PxsyyvkSrLRJqpBl5Ff9dN7iv1@GtmfYBqjkS5o@LQQHxfIGZAmzCgRf7lRjasWbmhB7Ja7TQYT0ErucMT114E2B4EeE7pXGdIA9xPEOwMgt/3QGLB1Z@9tsdBkSMA65b8U@QEY4UDZxWO96eARRWXpgVGEHswgLFshswOlCXqHTUG15BaY/BwZgiltd07p8Wp5kQ5DvGHD/HoEipQFtQBgcZB0wc1GY4UB0eKaTDHmWlYB5vvJ52/qBxMA5YqY0PKa5HIevLth2k4LjZAKcIyYlJFLysp80AiKWVkdR8kWDFYIRZwG9WkNgT9dV1sCsmdaATSoiw66/M0D7SCOtJHz6kxm210WkZb54Aaw7YPpgXb/9OSVzb0DsFWKZvYs9OigHXQ9mAEvZPzTpmUNnAMmExCpXJP0@i1ca7kue5okDm0p8DUJ0OW6JXPU4Ir1YR9/SmhG8pKTRaBn5BGQmsVOjFRKs3lwLYfM4g@Jw9QsBwURdjGJ4AU2/AE06xTY7DsudVQdncYRyZWqVsKvDVKDldPBJZHCCNZYWws2tcNWilCHFwscpN@MrPhhN18cx5U57eOyCTHSgnTB6nHk9pXUKAbHw5kKBPIjy2DD74BAFjQvwjAen93MUPGTBd2uuxzmSD1zlM5Mzo7VZkDUz6BCdM1gEBZorEP5qmqBT9sYskOLB5z5XRgnp64CJ7c7jwdFR/jgS4za1@I4yAAvpWzO1cqwFA604trdi8uBaKZYff1HND8dBgk0SAUB1BLmplX9rwyd6Vn7sfPVIJnV4LnAS8BamnqhbrU3EwXc7dcCFzJWpnDA21rRveeueMw0/1rdvcvBXxpGeMwPzhCNBQAB8a6UerGmFuLcCXnhFUCxpg5LNdGlE1Rm@pjA1ojhPrRHXsCo1Gbr1DLLeukTBqAdOxqACz7tWKa4ViqU1fbIMO1WsEy9n9mNZsmHd3VqKx1on6VDcgQ3qGsws6BtctbTsTkViaVoeyxzyf4ia8W3x5SDFWh7d/PC0Yr0TK0S4FosHCZN9MDa4ZTyZxWrbIYFFlOaUU086PCOcuExfiNEVzRCej1kdraeU6ZM4Ej5RVkUWx9oZNZWFkqNSZikJxT9UdVulbM8k25dJgPlv/YBqqPpx2DDpUtSmgYvdmdQxYJv18CfSMq5qT6uaihzzSjgXrYksCSMj8m9Zom1S9GgK@OgMo70iR70j06Tb7YXMztgGWEMiAlaTCfYOnYYSX0upcqSBcH5REvGTY3aSR9A11tt5OrK8v2EppNYFGvgdKwuwYYTKc9nsUcBMw@4bB2tJqAaWQL/QNIV@donrsqAi/90XtWh/zLcGKkl@GTQNozfaV7yLI8aG2QXtsTxNNRBAmMagXygLm9q7OBLlJd/qJLaigBElh2vFb8j/4QyuneCufQA6GJijNCJ68AC7dt@U@h8XPws6z211O4fgrYU8ewcQOGmM/vWzCCD7rHy4rlbEk9BR@nQD1je8jJjGaBBpsNCzj7@52NV0s8mVUksOhmXAvotKQ0dpYsOHPHzhctyB/lUNl9LILYeWySUB8y5Am94D8OPsE6uRHth83@uMTS05Vw6c2spPXWqk@dO3rjKMe5NluofgpYfeoE5h/NcXFcHWf16fGqkKBMrPeOmBg4nPFJ3F6u4VMEGhYDxl827yNqxXd808HTKRIptOYPMDaUO/KkqyeJnIsEL@fOT6@EJefhvLiUcJiOtvGkwZrdTfscktqkJ@Lijohq1Qj0moEzmiybLfQDhwmyAxH@MWBFCaoMXdzBM/RHwG7/Dzp1/wjZmguoyWIL7EcCn25coBp/jM0H/MeBIR/UIqHd/nDl9octoUk0AdMVTg2OyvPrIDP4KIvItIdzQGahppe@2iJRSLjJD00bBPKw15igxRMoSx3C1WKwPq/DS8ru38R14woH2JVeE@tAIjk2@ApBdicsK0k03kfDdXBj0Trc@mPekRrfYQ2DzYKgYLySwewDjJM6p10csP3oxoebJqR69vdlUlrUtkU6OpA2RHQXtVZx3ZLUdEelwVtHyowTdGRHVqqIEWDliL22wXoNtlthRFIvfexYl5eQHbHp6prdmp/@6DP0dBcOZq2MP@xHanWwBzquJ6hyov1QIzphjXiF0kWghV@YdTTrn4C/DvhySEGxsyKgHXha1VhIdPO8bi2vG6wvzfNiNT10JLWwO0asqU3/a8L6AFQzSlN3n1qpnK6iv@KBACYn3zIsSinqB2LYoVXEiwlQGtC4O6PuznjQ23k94P0JqlGyzsRRoVW0T29nCt3@s7J3r9671yOylXJNuvqadD3e0NU39Z/Mg1D3qXCUG1KpSdV8EA3@4Bk6QX4iahteAz/5NrB7qhV3itxykVkRL7npcnrFmu@EVQKq8UZvcKEwrhNYWvVS9rQNq6wMz77o2WTxuQK8Iz06@BZUFyMpSiOCkUGrJVCIV3tvnfpvss5ysFhkw5pUPcVAdYklqxg7FsjHrLAgbWHDuCOK74DWbl4IbIWbbaEM2TFpRplostwCzEOgxpDOMXr32AJeQUbitX2OZYTO4wACbX9o016@LVzUE2jOi/V3kEL6pvQVgjxesanqxgdEP/clcKEGqE3UGwnd3Tb3dtuW4ocCFAY1pUKwYE5xoM0rl3NQp3kGzZZ0wjLwaaj7mG3mXMMlyQbHc0vh5RZBH7u3pbCM7CxbaoPmli48lbelsX0398ImyA20OAW2fJCFqysYtqfNdOvqUrG14RStfROTpJ1tSiDPQzZYT1DbYAuYuLSWIxuozWIsoTozP567khba3yvvbdyVQD1FVC85W6PbWWWaWsGgAXlLxzqCYwAsO2a5uU@sgDqzTzeo7JtJ2dS1HfDkAM2kztdcD2xibcfqA/emO83dTcWDlgthPsGThEL4uRjFu8oKVdZprRIOaGagVoBCRmmMSgYb0mF@eqMDyeTRPvHDdS5HyuvzXqR9OMKs9xxpoYtuoYuflNnYTXMRVjIhoFq3NJQDM0W4vOpXiTQUR7cTR1PH7VcPrnU0S5v5HCo9qL2zBbht1cOPjskOzIrpzOMkSotN7lDfA9WatHwMrM6jNZyINhMxejlVRgxnUOVVEv1Qoh3By6T6qik2x70TVsnYLCAxMZGnoRtZTPyABMZJsBpEnfKR@riowgByEUon53j4aOBIeTGidUSpJ0cV7nwOjGVNoTsANu8/B1LhApcyIHZxN5T08iNcWOz0orcWoDSKff0p@HTyIF0uhzsiGrakALmBFidg5BumhWdcHBjLUi0YK5IOEM9pk5mDH71hidx3GXbcSpSyTF0r0AQCKTgx6pKNcG1AB0vHnkBdrk5ekQ32eHXXOmGPaMLqLyZtFgEgm5BtbzD5BCTDGnyaBbAWDoyUpBbj1q0OjW3zeAPI7e6dxbFI3vhRb1Y1TsHonpp2agPbGTjA0RyLPgWRzNb/DsCiVpHepU@0jWg9AWh5EGQHRcBaELPWjBgD8sH3ATu3pCobC9JEzm6OakfSbRS7XAbYW8lOWCOyOQWxk6ona9BG0VxaBWCzmcA4mQxPU9X5@JSCtDRKQdoF9nZCUS9k8CG8mTH9M3cTZvvaCniydz9rtDscj573MPARAPqIIGVrLlC7aJCrowiaSHOzIxJ3MDbUBLWBKKRpUo1rO7eAdloldrdKCOgHtSRQ@kyEEBtHw8r3bWpHxqvIl/aBXfeqsIbZ52VNhXc37OrezsNDHeczPgsRn2b9fX6IxjfRX1SVfPn3Mki/hB5ivwzocuGZOomRuyiQROpFpcgqa0GKbD/IJDMX84giLQSkTGpAm8JCCfupwzOM2/L7nprP/b5MbHvLyr1xR8ozow6IBmmW3hdYDkC1dpeKlMzqzVLZwCVfcyitc61BJo8hPkN5orIEPWn3hereVqp713FVW70QsBWmtarD5wJBxxbx8D7vsJ6gvnULqPi2h2URymyhFu2pqGUqKmD4ZPrbU32hgU0gLUOG1JmxyVAl2xP7HPcKejafNw8kuFiHzfRo3NV726@UkUBfekigrYd3vUWjreR3daOE@GbH@R2MDTWhDtThR3CbiHfdP/RTIxJgd8qtP@VgIzopUtBo21BxaC0TUHkwJip9Xc/I8sXT8djGEuW2lI5apGmOgNriDVjc5pVhWyK9gpeUOyDvvF8jocvqrpK7juMT0dVt6or7NkQPPTquJ2jlSrpA8kenvVnKLYDjIw2CO4dLh8UFZuzq@i6SHpA57y85TvkE1bv2U2h9nMLnRGwFCGbUuG9XCTKfblKLQgfPB3dOiOTly@PSJ6sDM/MBj5Wd3g26@YVBGyA7QFQlgMVAAFobL0XYH5MNt10XcZQ76tFElci3KxvMJ3iScOjpMJkTKCeQETwM1yC/2avd63W61avf6YVzLfZLEfUcIO0cz9DcBgAyaWHyJiIf1qitkQyRHEYx1RJY4gT1wUF5zjAMZljNMdzXZ/VASs1Nzb2QmhNS5sHCzHu1VE@6grGhHvOwIwXmpDzkQAF@6TyU3RfbzUmJID83Z6XP@yyZvtQ5tPvZFHa/PoTYmbP5iYykmdT5@hqhZRz8Uio9KmMtLwfe3JH17OFenXZOAYBalHmIMfshxuyHGB2UjrTXZT/bmNvZRkHUmBqy6G6MOgUsBmqMAhqtc1uTOcoNaez5aJiE9IIZjGpZL2eBaq@fKrrI5Ka4TztcWRags/6204/ZTjvC1zfTmz27N3uGN7uQTe87CR2NHW54cYa6NDPQ4/xbW1adGMyDoSathqaG@UgFJm0ZxMuQ7dTqCY@nAJN7KMXPISthHIPV8ML3jddwaaLXpKpcQ2OH/q49VHqwQy9Bo6ZrlF4YMsKnwHgOeVJkKsuD2gAFi6xp1o7O3Ja4ejWVOpzS1f4iPHfksKU8shkOsh1hmHIvutrfRbk44/8UyScx5HlWmaQPzxN4PAfKKfA5Tc@/BSF889e4tQZl0JMbZlrintBRqQ20LET5nIZT0lJbjd2WSXctw6eApSvlCE4boxCwSDV4WqCxw9LgWRZl6PuzqkJ2LSiH1Znh@uyXtGXsOmUeVM1@SjX7VWK5HUlV5NcGiobJqVNQGE9A4@j/fVI9BXY7yilQTgEU38dorMRIC4HRfthZApnF3rOXWyfHzanK5HRUjnrmx43GCqjfqcga2Sus7GoLP9VZBb/mTsvzee/f8dpRE2ixLS1mi@q@rw4bQjGP6OW5BXWRMrDy0Ta0OzUG5jIlLBG196a8d929q@6uuf/HuyhycDtSnoe9wOiRZxtQl5fkpsksOjQ3LwBRXzwi0E4IZJk7WXD1fMjDs2jmLyw5r7DJfoVNTunVo3ADSKazd3Zf75xonOalEZl2VvnGeqr7uX9rHsHNfgQ3t83TfEAf4sGA7AcCMhVRvxyi3Q1RhitU8aL3MFi7dGSxduHI6EDF2MoATGSlxEqBilxWf0L0Sb3BAnh4nvD5Le7zW4adeftJ6X5MugzHBcIHlL1ygQ4oFFtsBIjK3AIpFxwmBmUcS0WTa7u15nReoENbhjQr/PPJHl8upieC7nhIdh9khbSNNUg27qxzBGYITRYQbB57UsT9k3I5/JhF8Ws4it/DUXiYuugCnMefi142URv2JUvhpkfxTQ8aSEEsflspsLFR2IUe8iuzs5FNK0qp3pK4dbjPxLqyUm/dHkI2LVB66EFoF4@dscm8B/yOIBkEUSj28q5uJ6Qa0QwNJZyHv4I17a2FaKIkqgaYzglq2UzCtaqoTaYWB1T1jd9QXW@srLe2lCszT9oRaPQM5R4UDLrvC3pl1Kszouezw7PCkcWG5RW/M0kBNcKGYTfB6u/qpIWt@mZsTxjF95@ZDn4iAmKn9tg08g3S6K8A12ehd8bcPeIOI2NDmrWU7JXECmMgN@AiyFKRcQ4fakuzxeC@T/tVdohxUJKzET1qWXjUstgEVjB7FcxShVNUMfM5e4E6cXBCLu3yDUe5IY2Fb0Bx34BCz/HinuOfLnfAZsPlHGDWzXx22o8QaFdXmZ@l6sQsXDytacoCx6@yvNVOtUG@6vwmv2wCr8HHIyIt26s9HG/wakoJPLHlFzMJgcquAb4lBGCFnaywO0u3bkAKqbO1v6sF0FLw8Evxc5@lHfcsK2ctAmVtgdUKYCw4BIIa48BtBwTKij4yRzq2EVhcunNXTiEivcUmGAJAjfEC81JRB3DdTgGwujKkUdpXhGBbvvh5nJLgD0CqFQ5kHxNQ5xig4sA4zddYsF/J3qBym6NJSQk9NcF/BtQen1GsTLlbwHq3oRPTXkOHueey49olUpFRlbINaTvMftQzLycuykiUO@rRhjj97G3@2WFtxb0BdsWW/r6S9@pCEdeANKRSCbfeEJhciq3f7HTCJLBo2gwEaLNEy2oYEotnmv0yHb3vhQ2TCExvWkTKrNjGyg2RmZ2XnVV9HK@0@xBkB4zjQaEGyd6cyd5Ul4sXwWqw@mvUJeOUrl5QjvJWXgNDYIlwLTAoGBg9qt4fgZjsj9JV24TYZgtrENy7G8tK9YvXHCGLftueBnYKLOx19WCVHKyRg13EgFFqSNUPhgtaW1mOPTTk@rzg7Lllr9/Hpl3EiEgfL5jsTS9ogWp4cW9xBoi8PxwvdeWwcHJUP7mpf3JSl3Xxybm98Brf4tf4Fl7jW45t84dGXIZT3Lm3UOUvrvIXeel8XQ/PkxZCgtxAiwPoK1B10mVaHGgvh59TL34ZnABbxg2oonIJ@@kIR7kPcMwk0AT3IbMFExmTDogEYAUbru5tuusX4wv0@/4VztgJqwPaM6jkUYeFzpaC9rAI0Qol0QSo1sqli4wUNBxWUatoOKy0BXinbX220g@puh9S1evvuYlQ1fQ8gljIL@ipotXHvoNmwXZDGkKeBa/u4QHMagdV9TGneyrhjUzku196lmE5ZcNyB55wNGC9wRF5/OxVN3U8e75i8FcMbn9xRCH66VU7F1hx5o97mtzPbHuZvo8ptL/43M5WKcwEtq4CUh2mml9kxZ84qbSgg8osWfnXS6r/8RKAMjdg2wz9ZvXTpeoK8T0AqiZKOULMgEllqsGOwEyDMxNbb11svDKSQQqJRgb996LD33OFnEmZTgDzEgqzbLxQRkfvFUIGLJdIhgc97Iy9Qg@vCRsHNZGQu6zsTrVvUQicdFPIrk5mCEVMvMGAQJ@Q2l/K8KaTjguFjosLwXhBKjK4uNapMSYY1wT9aLfUSSAW7kGcMCMwJjusHclg2jBldS3KpqrBffDrKyV4ozu3zkXlyA6dB7sEgb5NXl4OLqLtQltE@1wLS5p5p9nfE4DXT3Vxryw1F7UK9z/KUWmSea70v6x3Li4JtE0@dvY@gKKgfYOHn6Q/0FYOthT1he9/REhD7e8FHfHzn2fo4U@Ra4@xHJqr4HHyFHSsjUuw/6kDgdiIOuL5KnAJ9X0hmcN830lhPv/VohMDOcP9rYECRA@oI/Y7Eo/IywAIrCr8fiRB3OYR1K8jOQUgfr58pAW1Ovy0uSMT7we5O0YETTQNIQ8/znrE06nUI55pJtXHL6y602V/R@w28SP2wyWC6Z7iyJj9tINiL1Pz4z5is2ofsfmHCWzOUkfse9iGe6mxQXzE3L9l7m2m2/KOeDKwSQDzmwOrmGaaENgXxxJoC4sjulKkrtQjXtRHWHhZ2y/iraIq31YVFpIWRglu9ge6lGZ/yj0M2RHvyhGopdNy3pNX4cNNKMcOL8dDtMXPraczJGk7jX0bLpzCb4PfeXZz140bHm5ksv0Fejre3JsPoLMeQosOojaG3AL@MIS9Ml/YXxcva/cl3rABiDsTb2H1Px7U6oEgN9DiAFw6UoZXmN1EwfU3WXxgV9d2O5p1g4XmBknE3J@bqZ@Gfpr53civ9Kr7lvkEwbaXAgVjT3r9WENg6i/b06fDkRrwfYLb4h56NxmqCczmcUuXfsP47VgnN7/c9Fbg3HX4O5XRu@maVDzPARXxc0132qSFZtr47rjp4c4LHu5tYLn3YcXb5p0XZd554fHd78u8c3V998W1ALOVPcOx1n5f8jJO4dl3Rpp7LX1rObC21n8Pfl7GUfFYva2JyNNX@xiAdhNUh024XQvF4GI3QpwD56ietXMtH0uQR/wGhli0POJZefTH5DEZ0cC64k8cKWpDlwYqK1dd9bwWRC3SyedOjfSO6yBGBTCY2dCA3@A0g9pDYGi6w/37Tvfv@wJFAxQM6A4ExiLDgzBm3P1amHviX4shMBbPyBLIcxOWvKAmkl@hYjZkUnj15FPVncYkUhcxymYJ0DiStw2J@A2kWgUPVMEDao6ImYMVSXl@H6C/vif9a3Yk5adfi8wC9ctPzz99/a9/@5tork@yZEn56fenbxqWFcWv15T/mygKX@5Pv//L03//29OT3gqQ1vCrKEhfvj99@@Xpt6c/f92G/ct1XXYXenrSzGSxJ1n9p78QOf3yVFTQEvyh@Penn8Pys@Cfl/Dz0z8j9M9P5esvlpf@l4PIPV2/SJ5aVrDqkePTd33OLyrwC6R@95x//n//93/@@//@X/Kruf3973i5f/qnp5///f/8j5///PWHDGBffnrSl396@revPfz1b/8mPH9TS/YFif/@9BPq6Ev5@tPXf/x/)

(The total number of errors is reported in the *Debug* section of TIO, so you can collapse the *Footer* and *Output* sections if you just want to see that.)

#### How?

We first get rid of a few edge cases with the following regular expression:

```
/dief|egh|etei|it?ei/
```

which matches these flipped inputs (for which it's especially hard to tell that they are indeed flipped):

```
diefeid, diefeis, ieghteis, ieghteith, inhomogenieteis, pompiei, soceiteis,
wieghteir, wieghteist
```

Otherwise, we replace the first occurrence of either `ei` or `ie` in the input word with `0` and append a trailing `1`:

```javascript
w.replace(/ei|ie/, 0) + 1
```

We test whether the resulting string is matched by a large regular expression consisting of 23 patterns which are associated to words for which `0` must be `ei`.

Examples:

- `ath0stically1` is matched by `^(a?th0[rs]|d0st|r?0|h0r?[1s]|w0r)`
- `rec0ved1` is matched by `c0(l|t[1es]|v)`
- `mad0ra1` is matched by `d0(f|n[1ens]|ra|tie|ty)`
- `ineffic0ncy1` is not matched by any expression

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>770</s> 642 bytes

```python
import zlib,base64
A=zlib.decompress(base64.b85decode(b'c$_7UYjVRd2!yY)S5qWp)5uZ=uru!IySP90V_|rGMa^-E&VNdB;H1S_2f|8290;)j7yV7J%d^Wq23sMpSzu$qo;^u@D9IyHvE~Y_aZ`-##Ee}q7bO~)P3UUc!*KBGJAe35sGn4Dg*q$hg)r7k+@W(Z-3BEF?F-tdS^~S|4-B0443B>&x}e|ad5xF>_ITn*?1VMqLoI4vi7nBIZ6>m-KsG}&MdPkJnYWr$LA@PyH5$<?F;L6Jv~;{Uj}p&oDC6}95|fNJ')).decode('utf-8').split()
g=lambda i:i[:2]=='ei'or i.replace('ei','')in'dst hr hrs hst rn thr thrs thst vn wr brun lorel nucl taip'.split()or any(w in i for w in A)
f=lambda i:'eei'in i or'eii'in i or(not('eie'in i or'iei'in i)and(i.index('ei')<i.index('ie')if'ei' in i and 'ie' in i else('ie'in i)^g(i.replace('ie','ei'))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZ1rtyS7UaY/41/RXnjcpxnbC3zBgMeAPWCwuQxrDGbBzNiTu1JVlWdnprIlZdWuPTZ/ndE1K943dHr1hx1PRYZCSkmpu7ZHuNr1e/8ZjA@nwRv/4ccfPn78OLyYyX/49p9/@Nkwe/O14WUyWfxnt2dpngIrRIRKs3mxo5lGqZXZZEahtlq3DNpew2jTm2kmEYxl4AhM64UImlyDiYEvzGLIi/TIT2Zm2YyKOCY1eIkgpn53o4p@gRD50zCaBdUyQqWT8d46UiuQFO2yDSu@nwN6DeGtHQws7m448bOJodrVTLeUE6RaYhqMiizxxXShV9RpopUUwZd1uk7m8LW5H5GSRwbNUWaeoVNAqTCA/HyaxulMbzEhfF2f9/heTpDCFY0dtnY1MeULpOT6vMdXfTIQcCajRmtPDxKtMIxtiK@IykphmMfCrquUCpWi02pYVGIltguFJHqS36Q8mV08HCWP4psQ0/tmDypEHxLjGFUIijEvzPKdns/Tys8Vho/FWkm8pIuBZM@iB1nWl5f0MiGERMD@5eK4RDc0PxBSeWqkqFU2Gch4WfYIoPK@WKrUIkD/nKEoR@cwkCkSR7IPADjxK/GIMKkr8JJMslpIohflYo7fZhAnI72YYzxIHILRZNTIK4TluzLL9pUt/RiYjtnHIZig2ptjyqNUYwBgVMQzgTdakSXTbEc9I63O5sIf18IgM0UEFXKS6RF36SAyAlV4EuWvYXCbmaCiPphnOBlZ2R5I2FtipsJqP5MAYMJKO4MA8mXnuqZCcD5@CJWa4RppWWOuJ6WEUGmb@etXkesgr5lCkOiVOE28QoKsw2zp/WZESsEurBQRKp3oJRQAVWZBHokPlE0LI@NXe2OtiEgJX3KRZWVciHzkQjVlBlBVrhes47IsK7l1Wqz63lWI/k3eBmc31iwUVdep97k9MCmrrJwRKtlloLKdESrFHpbODwWS4pR7TKg35R4Tqm1DuCq9BFnxs2reVKgVVWwLRMU3o9QSguz4Fr9H9FQkIsNwvbUZ8jECMLBNHItESAWquE2n@KbSe7MxFU/KdKWoulGVnoFj4AnEmDKZDFiF6ibLjmThhYtdlJX7gBWiYixt9qR6YwdGZTZItha7O9aICJUCpkaU@Zlg@BGIq/dmeaEkLAye8o9lMVy3VQiKwdALigACzCVoITmwPJ00id/iB1MZ8pUanxkEBYppQs02YBnXWKuduAwWhtGPld8Vs2xFnhFkwUqEpX3klkElHhC1DSqQdtKQinxkpVhEIAtHFuXzMTfA80n2COD5JMrnY43rOOUqJEX7MtmLGzi1xA/8gC5re6ekRbZ5pbaRn2/TrOq7CkHxNkxzbyjuyVFdGb2RxRca9XvBYb@X2BWDIlWAzNmJyEJWZFGqXoZXqhgywWDmE/XWCiKlhXxJAH2ZF/QlyeDLqgYJKsOgVhzFLMAxwLBXGOUssiMZfXl1@xZO7E2h5E8YlruZLtfAcDIVtudd/K@iWCDadC@ycCVZlKUoqjfi@IU4R4mSAT7jMBGyLG14l2rts3ymIs9sMmd6MBJpKwSV00LgrBbCbKjTLqBXFLrugkmbd84dd5U77pQb7pQbzEA2MgAbZkAbWUYbK7xSk4Zr5c8@zMpmZGwlUAerIc8IMnwlXpI98FN7UCo6tMJcj/kO1IwcK8h1kNdMIsNuJIAJaMhykiE5zzFPrhC/QkyHwShKgx5R/MqOYD4Bo5Ec1WhMxm26yLwxfYn6SoJHYwdqmKVbhYCnmHCT22WizJhRZ8oBVCWo@sDM9NbnPMOQvoAPjeXEw8GUnlIyoyJOE@WGUYTe6nx27P0ZK6lUs6E0ongmkZ4lUaYM0NloxFqswq7cIPfPNJ9RCQPMXbN6mxSHNRaqEzdmnhiVHas5UvAt6zeFDEYm9NZikw0KTJZHAhCvKXZkOo1KwcGvZr9pmS/RAxybfqHx7yS3QtnsPctkIw6EXVZk08rpmwh62I1NLyrc6M0EVdwIVUCWPQJZCLIonp@H06t@142Sqo9OL6yZISpO4f01WpTJXFh8N0LN0iR3JU4Rr0kgBEW7AMfAKxCQxD6j80F70LgKtfyggmoY7d9Hx9GNCB3fTedlFIj@pznEq5Tjz1fxkH2hHkkEYIHTntOZkpTSj4aIosz9Gcv9FxxCerFLbMXS2y4MkjO1nkFl5XBW0qdQV2zLZZkMQOsui2DBckpaSkn7ikEkGR94hRCSKJ9P3XGIY@6fByQYy9xDl07uaSwbjGSCVvY04OzwKWVn5PqrMHSZhyAyIRV3MXbymDQVQnLcUeUOPz5Us68hTwzbc40Ij9wwUWZKBBLElf4oqKyY893gqfkcCbaA3ZDfqEEdnzpVCsnIJhItAbkrl@@cgROiWNwpD7vhnc28q1i8k5F3ipUxbCQT9CUiNJMB@IJt0iSm5VMd5IlB2yIDx4Ccif0Q@NhXwoahEeuojcx9cWfu3D3OCHMJtC2T1OKIhB6RNW6WHcmQkBFAQ6kCsilbog7buDSI4KYL954b8szwJVcibdk7VrwFeCKQ/bMsbezVxCFOkE32oEehKgQ7@8sLjmhXApklIYhUATLB95EqhwgwoPECcc4yPnCRMc6ifP7C@hdSmF8pIglgPOZXjEaSIRY0x16ARwDf/p36EfuykRcJoBfLhl4kGbxYKTfsK7783ZlhV4PDT8zKGCXHT13mocvIDMabf@Vc5FQmcpSHHGchNYlaEAbkKTbUPtipU7Bzc2H3V37iqlXQU38lTz2mhSd18pgfDuxAoOcfqsVZGNpN445nzp4FSsXTMEI3qMgjA49AFMUijiTLAKh9exqweXsa5mGhyqgytDOfaJyuIAx8tg6jM9PamUzA/xlX0kSwLys/ExEqLYOL9TsFViGY515tJmhr5RReKQlXC8NhBUAaFoDPYH@9EHwThWDQaVnDqAjrYKqvuOrhNGydSaKDsuqpo3hSatM8q5QsEBVdDCQ1/eDFZBjL0SQVyRjbcZQONNlwUpMNhRDAhMLZiBPPRhQgZaqPKvBI0GaWwcY@zJzCmWFQ4cRhZYI5JpwotAwgKwa1Xq0yDO42zBRcIbJJ2ZgnhC4UIFprDUFwdYliE@tyv8OoyoO0vveUFvWPV5ZJQRbSIkuF2bzwzFiDGNRieCKpMlRb06IECDIRWuoioFcUVrAIRqFQTRLRzu4lhN45s9AMXmWkFmJfkhOlQFbk@r8izwjKXCXC0nWgLn8lkNOvA3b5K5A5/Zoq7llZKswryNYKQr9olUlB5Lw77YE@PA3KD89VzcIWxNZmtjSDFWNeKYaZYFpFhLHLANLKGKfsOG3HsR3HdmQfOItQYVyxD5rllJc6CNW46r7SwGEEPrWecOK2UZijjVBVbhlR3O6sclfpcedHKDVkZzlLsha8Qp81iy0pkIDSzJ5P1MtpJBBCVyfs@jQAzq9plItycoWQB6fbDQt@IlDIr9Z6cjsS9MhuG6tsG8cjIvUUue3sqlb6HRTjvK9ceCIB@2mv1iiGnyvwRKD6LQBUqKBTKZ9u9PONftZttcJALbW0qAKuyDOCd1MJWKKB20rgVcwDDt1WIF9FJsqlwlyP@Q7UjLwvyHWQ10wiXEZdZCOnggsCB3iR/onX6J9mWBtdRCPmUQuRD6TFpZgehXhCGMkCwM4@sp195Ldm95Hs7CO9tX3ht58J2okI7WQg7dhh5tq4IU8Mq@dGRNzsiQpqBuBRJOBQlsGf06vHqcmC4O2lrvtqpJy2g8hHeGtdJZ4IZNICIBhuBUaCjT1rzueJlvoL6BXFfPdkMtgZWxOWPyYFUGxmbi8V8mBCKvITYenzU2RMkpmaWwU8CIACt18TYRXPWyoaRMXFUCc/EVJJmzW5W9ooq1rev9ugUtQrDp@Ylfe1o7qvSpE37OqtuZmEqTMMIH7gB2IXh3b1HZRVZyokyzarB2fz1gk8U2UOy9OyUVZY0sBOWo@wME07vCptYeTuxcUwkqUnyxBkJp6AWjhzYFnjH0zpKSUV5M2oMKFLaXM36GKIBIxcBGZUyDPRK6QOPpse1JpaTQcMK6AqwiaUXce9s69XcHz9qz/RivQn810Yu23xE7Lq38Jkd/8VmOL7/GE1np/Bxe9P5HtMeAM/Hc5oipnpyZsrxy/G3YbAIz5PzgkZv6q6kDfMytvE8xgHZdUwvOxqhPDJlfoU9p4flbP6Poeho10wKQezbNalGhILbuNtZ9Jhpv6gfG@c7ce83HG9Yq2861xeKKs6m5bOKd2CSfkWmy2qRDToOzT0GGX4SFW2bsxrGDoIsi2tJznRApITj3Vb6iFm2RNAGb8b2HnMokdZim5VDdiKPDFqwFYCtqweH6@QArVrR4/nJLg7bbmBTr1ry41zv@hOcoUUUOg2RCumt5zXj6NfvKI8I/KNVpifLA@gWRo8U8t0CknDP4G0MoNM8KTw8g@M39cDa136zB4Qv3hP7HyX06fv4FrbmZud97RfXWUR9Tu@RVrElEHHBD9FY4IF4EM4IlhktBGUkaCtBMMVW2bsT@DQAgcXtNOh43ZQjgfl@jsZggVAJzecKWaFQGZPSD2FmT1@cdTSyAYh@pGtSmsllXd26V15xNF4J3/MQJ3tQtBKRGgmA7KzKDuLtrOwnYXtwDfAsU1MEajv8RVTak6eviaFoHsRkQ1P443OquSyOrksJ5dVycWdWdpNFWXP4dCCvUQoFFzAF8HOkY6EnuEsZN9VMO/8CAWzq7UAGeHL2VUXOSOM9G5mpWRmVlpoHVRD@BL2BVdCNQKvYV95nrUisrXSTGslaMtzDbF7VUPQCpIKpJ19HCl6hYCdhMBOAWAHZyN3mjZMi9LO1i1CI@bARpoSfph5nnGHzzRNOUZRHeDQIClyfJ2KrqPYOo4sLxDYnfLVqWZ6YeQMViq741gFzyEFz2aDJyMBv22PlDHkyOMj5QI59DjySp@RlvKMwzSTwjSTwooZshKZsmOZ2XX4FKTtONAY4VgOJJIKnhU8KtBavZHOthl50c1Ii27G1H@b4fd6Fl/9GbeGF9kjEFm1iMK8GajMVQJJlRAkVQEyqcwABabIHoH0w2DLbTS0rLgC2cSsCJqRicnJxyrLFDZqne1oTsP5/DwcSsGR6PMUphbqk4KDMLpWxPM@awKDF4WSfDMsjwwcAzZBcYZmfJGrc4RwlKdgBjejwKiIU0SZobfZm0s76IRpQMeWZULP8UFmBaETjs1ivjTbmc0mhA@xw2cqUmcKtHQ0T3360CwQmqjyPuBDoQAEvcYyfSaL8YNIH7EGUfESq28eHjsoql73pZzZCKlTKXoDlQmmblQ94WlmmUHcJorNdH6ghFlnug4Ow0gAIhQ/Oqc0ftljqEiSmVk2PVMezkYd4YSWEZZZjrjGcqyVzvFgGNwDAZbNNCJAciBnQtpPunaQJ4aJHKg4RxC0naDtkCjf1RxfNmeuzDDsOdWISu1mqDgv@rySBlFxpUy3UqZdsbOQAcqYIVfM3iv0JLIMoldFb/Wc3Fva765qkUpJNbU9LadPpaS6c8jbTgG7F9JwL6gQ23ScHAmBEm9jHmkD8zjRWrgIrpZnORukJ7FxMp06Y0kHxUeN/HuUAlXyE9fqqZVxojMiE3yQiGVkMq3qaeEcNU8DorYgBGooyEZiFntmWp1zyAt4hqmPS7TH2pxoj7ZK55Ax8QKnVZDFIYkBXXvWQEg8IlmLJzmoh4J6CCV4PWmsd5/Z2UoxiS8rt1MywkwTSVD5rkBlLXTUUGnFQ4gKwJe0Xq5kJhK2AlVRlqG0uJhRuK6oEC2lAU5IABoDLcArEJBgkuHYZ5E9y9Jd31nkf1B81qvDbiujZuLk@eiNhqDde7CxB10X@g6deoEnOj@YQ2enEtlXONDYYa7HvIaUQAecZQn3/Vk9@QMl/smqT3SFrOjMxtOcT0zKZuGt8A1ivqItDAlgRvP2xfCBb08aFMQpwieEvJnKET@bEXUdn5gzw8Hxu1K5MqIdSAQ7tU9Kb/rAsm3dMFrY1LruBun9xPaIV1VgpaT6OZ1SzpXqQX2H0itukKxiA7kSTucM99EQxM9cAZRqmdUnG/MxEb2KSqO@QykqDUJU/LRMcy/hjx/ogZDWSKvELxRVA9sMZCtPvnOMGvQaYnwaUxZD72EOetJfx9ukPo/v71TC39/5Y/P@jmX@HSeFRnvaO6vfnhgCtCN9j@2In1ZeLjjS0r6RJvpHnLgfc2ebv8QVoh1ayFyBR4K2Pc6ZjJYObysAks/i4W1FhuS7s7N3cpReEc6wjGquceSJxQgudqUdpQ1CUE4drlsQKe2XqwqyMIh6geRJQTIB1GTgqCcDR54MHNVkYCJO2XHajmM7ju1AeVU2MY9wcnF4UKQpaMxMlMrk1AS74KoM@rgvrgLwLa1b5WJaIYZtuZAVgjGzVPIKAKft3bOdu1d27p7s3HFFyqhv5xjV3RzjfqJW/H7CRvy@LPhmM/AI4HVlWVrY5umkPCkQFT3O@yYAceTZv5Fm@kYeUKDhhAc2yB94yN74oLb5gw78Gh/rQKflFyQDMQNNtRUgX54ZcKqtyOLVGXXtgNGXDhi@csCoCwfM4MkVz554dASzkCkHPkA7tbFACNuoDQlbp7KxknOC4JCMsWlPAzAFoZIPgyelhECJ9vcbmvQzuJ3f4BSgoS@vwQ@v4c0LhvcuGNq6YGjngsGFWbxrUO0ZNLBui/YP8u7BttAMOzgHfWgWOmhmPZ4UOOBDoaDJjFoX5Rusl4upKyOYpPitX4HIAZ10sOB63tcTdC2AesQ@yNm5JyK12zDvpoNATZwWnCVjVgXCFdHZiqWOmZDCxGHETgCpbFj6EqJnRKLHL2CQn8V2AFUV4o/jeLbSp3CV72BOVZ4qx42Ct3MewqV1AgdF1TxoSKWpQihAs6EsEwFYWl54brogUqK@fCWeCAS90KkjETg7jdT6Oyiqpk0FXBIrRMXUJWOLmSk1tZ7/oKhqVZW9WK6fly1Qemz4tS3AKxCQYIJt8IEusmdZerHP3M2rDJ7jCxr4coY0JXhhDdxXaFaedMwEVfTMZGWoFvvl9MIyQqVwHeaNtDIjNRVg4OBCbH4rpcSUGuugAm4yzjLow5bjLIqnt2m70qaoylDNvpGOfQOFz7qdWhmpaSVS8bi43XhYqx6zGd/TUhDYCA@9jLtBUNyV1s4qt3RGhI7cgUH57ZQO5eX6oVFUNfpGpif0GkIyHExanHTVVBiqbbE6HpRipazKI5wHe2gWOojCoFHQAz0UCpqgZ67jWWFjD/oOhDG9RgMc0Z2pdrqgscO8ZrK/0mCQZw6bt1jKVR1VIbwR7PxEkbsYDzodxVB/6Dyc1OxHZTKgiHgkqSBS4smvglBpYjsTWZlnmmIviJR4NLEh10FeM4VkeWrEaeIVIhK0bUqAhRYgZjKpcdknVo8jSGUXEoIOhqnAM9EgIMEkwZNkquwJKDkIQGdPndXZU2c6WurMR0tF4HEGLhPO0/pgyMrQwRDInxA4EUJAfwI2bc4m3WLk6E6RRulSkTNMCSZptIsCHgmKl1UEEiX5gpIMKZOAl6LcpJVFo4BTwBOBSpK3eWX5bt1rBynbBeLT60jiJI@1bkR2Xs90GPC5fXlarGHqKcuUSvJLkmoLWYEWmcKLBBc5FuYYeHz5lPsNX4OayMRBoRj7sCyDG3pQrjLI@IYWfZ@5M3c2uJr7TP26dBCt6qY0CIpywjkJNcdLGbVBuohR3CxChk0Ac2MiHmTRC8@SYdmx7BFAXsHtillsmR0JmxVZvcF1REme596AGFU542nW5wlulT4/Z1gF4MSB5lf6mImGQRExQJHPBXIky@pwwqGrIrMCBQJSzeBClMGfKcdlEK5IMP@dcWDlzOdAnemIpyjTQTOVQElNCCM6hyvFdFXf4YY8MzS1qk9rrCnO7HZC6Lhnv71yOxIq6RmxHfTHc8xopvSsZkrPNFN65pnS8zy84NU2lYCVhMBMAWjnVT30yiqcMIXQUxTrAsAONTxmbnbMFAq9aXqBs1FuGe2WYbeMduutcz7JE8O7ndEY5rKZVOmAo0rQvwkPOKoA/LNp1lY@k4EnIsa/qyx94VPPKvGaBELoXTkHTQHp7n6mTkQhaHg/Y@@gALTzymZUTt1fyQjnXN6dVYknAp/qmXZenecHN08j4aappYnnAjypgLuWZp3Plm45PKtbQc4Wbzk88y0hZ17zcKY1D2drA2xZykBmntRNlc3kIkOglXhG@LGLjPsaGVGpt7idvsryjVi1X74iz2B3EBHcOl8BfOWt3hpfmVdklzdSRHbhT0FGmNiO2mAFQEu3Ia8YtZGtW3S3rEIKVSnxZ9469Qh@5q06Z7UgKCrpZhNOg4TQ9Btl6jfO02@Ypd8wR7th4kGRjCAQNwTjeJXSQVHVGLhxMgNZAGiJKu0/OvNq1QSgdiiyTKdKnCaeEYKVAl5pt@DBfI8FDb3vsbXHsSdVWVdT6SmV@M3deowUHckkvhuWUWF95zeVCfm3vrPh9X3Ct5WBbGUXBO/mszo3qEFURNP82SgAqqSKXAd5xYisGNbzjRNaOxgKYUMdLSibhUFSFdQLgbVYoeUSQqjmUETp3ZAIP89ceNQJthlRQswqzrQipxKyg6t0KkA7N6uq8woxXpa2UzfiCWGABZCdfPYEjM8I6jWGsW8Jwa5X/vH5AxmRf3T@QCTccSyE7FDHsQCwkyfFwE6ZJguE0E6ZOBN29nnm6fDKoEzX9RP60yx@gPfZuOurO1KmzEZHB5/zRTCosLJhuvHqnO@KQRsU6EpJwb6SkzwwvauB6dLuDkjQCR6qLu1w6YWfqARX4gmh3QKkYVquWwA6h8t1iwy@cB9@V334nfrwO/XhL4OBQxAvQ9sOVX@eB5wlzkQm/CXN6/CMdoOsaLAd05BnJDN3I9KSDk8FRul7Ucc6X@hU5wsf6nwZ0hpMWARWkWipRTKyXTpm@JKWJDkp@utAovDcrGbgKewGIYoGLucqm625AjgoP@nU8SQHJVUZ2bxSAZvklcEbM3Yx/IYKQ9u2Hit5lluPM84jn2exeuxyHfjEtYYg8a8DnbnWiHwhV6tt2Y4tq2ypA9wu04hr5gsAO9MIa@aLDDbMxYAJU3OIlGViTni68WWCM4gvE105mwCk/OToeTdzU//JPENo4z0R2pf@5LlgGcECPBJIoyJ7CbhE65PaL3xS@0Wd1B7JO5t5V768k5F38sXahYxkgr5Yu6CZDMAXS/UhXxF1yTdCjfAEvMgkn5UNmhsvSNk5kyW1uK0ypcZR16/B8muw6jXgCU2XmY5ouqT2ggg3NQaka3bAHmcC4Cjd@HrBC18vlnqxCYDLdh0tq1TkmekHMb/wBcgXuso4yheOTiSk4vW9wgdFVUd@U7MnX4AkPcY2zqUcMC0fqMQjghU9DXhJ6LLWSnwgBN4UgP5wQ7UgiHQ5MhBVVvUQfM34TMGLU3WM03WM4zrGqTrGDTxw1ZBnBKWyEvAo8PK6ykjtxjo3VtBmbmyFtyVUgtGnrQkVQPSNGdmOGZUdM5IdMyo79EojoCUQhcEccUbwnmHNxoUuh03ybYBlZwdiNdYxIwOngLLBAEZ@M4FjuRuRQ0iRrYNK45WveS2MUnmla14vcHrWBa@XTeKROEhIiTQgW@PG8yrz8yTD1yEBeTx4A2I4JyL@AkdCGWryVKUXQk95rNALQDu06qgSsoPrjipAO@/vyqGMyFJkZCoTsGVP3JXKCEu4ms3JiC3ZGzkVCYafD9cEjX3jwNNpm/gI@rLT7HEl6N2Os8cVgLt8lW0lZAcvs61A2tmH@D0IOO7eILVN9jwb4BSBIPc8PyCCLACCpImyC93Se9lpgjQBVPDsiFd@eHLDsxeBav09YA3/4O7EA7sT19SaX0fRY7mm1nslVYVWThUgHb3mNaQOHgFHE6CRw4xgfDDfZocBrSMHtI4Y0DpSQOv4ahzd8Cap72BZi0oo0ykNpMGjeCp8AhPE5RXTmWbQC8C44Wx5kSFujtPHqfRxlD6O08fxfYoFobM0733lpaNXtXT0SreUXmkp6ZWXkl4Hyv8FYGww/xcZYhNOvKKmMoyP2iZ@7ewSv6pN4le9RzyimS3NnBT7TFZmivqDmkKJQEPoSl3dK5@QfcWO7pXOx74aamMUABYMti@KTDa40CaEhdYMvGCrIQqMlmw1ggHS1HMjgRC83QrAzo09urHdmzJ7I/duFMpNBcIrOwTzBGnmTkBwiw5QSAC9ij0RFmVQ5E6eJV4VkOW0IvnpbIwNg7zKRl3LAIcwxApURqMQegcFygHEJ5ObPiSVTenGGQU2KScTq2yQpAEeBVAl9uofG0WqMA6uUd/DBCEMyF5wSmSu5VYS03EbDpinFHZ4N0GuF1dQSMfgnmG6@JoOd7N5iFpMJxwUz1xLX0l4OMseAGb8Mhe9aiI7ZI1B/6pBZR3BCl2wVuc8pZY1S7QqEMPVTyS2BEkoei4HlolcGWkFCgLGxCowhFquREJKz3x52JbZUkHfocgwAB9IhJ9pUlzf6sqXuqorXK8TDfYkgAm6QY@lyB6BbHtN2NK@Rn9ocLYgULIvOOqYACpA9@JqsWNxTcOLqxVno19pDDLLnuUAIOVeeZr6FQcos@hJDFJWQdADCwe5GPZyMRTmQoHw/qlMKBhdfxRGtYfVG0MrQ3uOh8ob8oygDVqJtOQpth73eFzxbooiyljENupMeakwCiaoJcENomJQ6R/45u@M0KtAt35fY53HS9Qrg@B2zuQ7ZfJ9GXgZXGWkpg6CfjKvIDh/IGkvLQQcuTUlqVbmD4vE4MJ6oc5LIT4QQi8zkPmeFwNXAA0SXh58pdXBVZZfEFoufOUDewrwCgQk6Lx/ZZsUFzrL4brjSQ7Xx6Xd81AVMoCGTiXUJCsUvGvIA2vXRrTwoiw/WBXg17ZAGZFGpOubTRfgYPwqlHGccGKTzyueYFKTziSexjzJDfnhYK7HfAdqJvPKgVwHec0YhU4AgdRU7VsZqk32REqRsIp/rCdHBwcJDuoGNjpmsZ0/80TQik/T7HACTQd74scZNMxY8TiFhhkqytqmNEXNqolcJ13Y5BVRSu28GoFY5TiORjC2/JDymu9mkcTB8/JMmsbaoTRVnmd942uFdGdEavdd1BqWg8LrX16M3vV@UFRd9GHqDZKiunV40pcOZ2R7dzWIX/AAhCldNExnGzQWOmh@EMTTChoKmswQKC7umtKQdwAFvJqmAgp9pgTBG4qrjOHOmF5bmv5/6byt5w/0gBtiaTwNnSeev/Aj9mXohnH8oB7YnOmpZ/xQMG3S0BY4RXenTe60/z/2ujuerh0v1@F02vm2goOS6piOZ1GqhZJq6mfgTccJpn68vM457WLUXnJxiDlzVUf5H5RUp42yfEKYldevvLAbfyLLneuoJX0QVVc9S/wgfHF7x5WClRu9e4XlD@oBfYEt4PEruO9zGO4QP4Q@VXFVN98CHfvYd7Hs6woeuhDe0GgWPlu/Qah8CuNXUyCmc@d8/QZJcfeB83JmqNY/wU/wR4@GLpy17qQySucsvycMPQYp2jvO6aAU0ue9p6jU9BFBFbJDnZN9JB0V5gzYO55n4qUgCeizEw6Kzp@ndDeMUi2UVeWkSpLXzoOrfswtqlIsUCt2DPJhZlPqcKr0bswzpHfQkLT3HGLBcHpDLwflezzkD5CNe8MAB8UAp06Gm3SG@3Ln5Pxyp7TEbm@WoT@GGxeyKHtk@ry4SZ0XN62@Ey@vY@XNSTcGGiVVO9/0J6NSUg3dtkPDpLx3a6MDhz6dO9pc8xw0dCHUPWm8XdXmDXoNsYpvzDMLvYcDK7rFdFonB1fqNzPdSTMhM/ag6ULfo64Le6r0Ba9UaU7mTp5HQilXmOkx34GuxzqK@GGvEPSmRbVEM6PkdupmrwZR8ZbG71hGLxKCtl8BoyJOEw5qZtMrD/43SG6mDjQoJUDvMzFseBYyauQ6yCum7Hc7W08OPvNlzBNdxjw5N3T3lskf6AFz2fUVFYKzenCi5f7UbvjBWLTdhQ3RdC800PXGBcD3IODVxkWWX4R0i5nj2qNCiAauDZhu@CPnnhvmnC@HnfZXViKdzUh6W4Fw98uBtoQVgFZwS1iRpY2002jHMbjKwGVD99oW4BHImrzI0oLDz3UB4Gwk4GyWwVm6tCQBCMRSGBYNWpp7LAB8sDj3WGTpw55um6M80iD4stNwcQEQ2I5DxkWGwGi145dqseOXtNbxS17q@OWO69CK7BGIudAiynhwXCmanoe1G/KMIH9U8rT0msYpRutPdjM9KMb6X9PohVAtgQgqB4JjbG9S4qV@aj3fa97UJRTyFi7xs7kJgU9IeNVnIWQkX1IF4i29rpZWGVcCdhICOwVIO@lQh7S5WiyGeU0799Mm6ufihHl4sbFCp4rqoPK18HYu2rs1D5hYM9/mPQ@QejNd7j0PSh1/jimlVDIjtVfyknsD84DdgSKLpJvpau2Zjy@f8Wrtmc4ynwc1EFQQKqkTTApCpVvn3dz0m3mnOL9zlN8xxlj3z2bAuacCwEIkYCLLaOOVbbwqG69kgxLe0Clxs8Ez4dKMACVsIqzCbZbOREI6o15thG8QFWVOgOptPu5COOQVJbA9be/TRdrFX708QajKIwPRzqnkbgaZolNYbJjOmniFbpqA0g7u7TEDD9ChPGDoMYjcSn3RmYcmZz0qGdGFVoc2hJkqMcxWhUDGWrEjO9OI5KwGI2dzo5d9ozcGp7FnUSTf1OmuN4iKL8axWkKkxI3RglDJyL9HEGTyTGJV5zzJpZpRanm0hYIBeDiIqoJREXiNBbVsesBnPiXkNbt1EKrt0kuZVZGFDpIRvFwDLSQRjBVpWldA8O2VVulUAnk4IcjCBcgcTAun5onezXrBMwsKgTzxeaebjAvCvBLoDoFMMKhwVXP/DZLi7pTa7kjpptLnptPnxulzU@lzo1Mm9LXg9VLwER8Cb/JKPmmEl/bNeWnfCE@QBXVTdWWopmc5K0M1WtRdAKSNxWXeRZYpYy/DqrYQHxSDo77cTIsAZ7vy2yoEPVrpbRUAPjlTP6xPeZJVi1X@squxTcwqCaHS7tm33ZMnKv8V4jUJhDCOJUcqIIO6c0h3ZfZOVu9s4zHMnG0SgqD3EzXFMoCAIoGAsiwD2ufYCcCAMsKAlkm1oQpTaurgkYOS6kaucz93pn7uzP3ceV@5kZgIBkMbiGa1gW6mDXQzb6Cb97edo/6GXeIlb6QZpJyWcz@fWAZ1l3hDTiPPSFZEjThFpD8XWA1dZDQrV0MXUT7/paEL9woiJcuDgJWh2quhb21G9FVdBu70ZYKW4qd35WsRDoqqK5W4ROC1Lmnj50x7lwT0isKeJsFksLT@swCPAN@mo5zk6MjhSjAuDo8crgBiF9@fU7E7oFeUYncw6Vtwk9qic1CMxoNWGmeCKu8Uz3eO5TvGEfuyixmgy1Zkj0DmcYMniER5pedXfn7F51d6HquWAiAG@WYoB49wHMJGTgQomGn29yb3OTVCAR0QIjCmMfNZWstgAhcOJuMmO7hRitU3/GrlTpXFzLH48daFg2KizXRWSiaostBASCaosg7UCq4Ikm7VV4w0iNYc1Sj5UP3BdSE/SbKjLMFH0i0Gt7wWGd4HnVFSANrAE0qKDDY4Z8ZG@6ja8k@MkcA8O43jrCrwArkKn0ZastGIHDx5Mo8QlmE0gJ6o6x8W2ceNQsunzaqxsEJ4mXiPbyWQvBPt8K1AJvCEwyZF9gzeAMjOaxE9yW9SfiU/51d2c35FL@dXcnI16n1U5IlR2lci/UsL6KlEFAZ5Jzb0VJOgMFLjt7Cql7DSO1j5FfiT@toWBt/XiEw6rJB8qhS98jRP0Ehqrzjf5TA3Wzme7yKgHC7JWM5BNPAMjLGctK4YTk0RTIxvJZoHrs8qrQrm5FKLuSukxdyRGs4Q3lB28CoDes5r0QU1PntQssa5xqtc4ynXUFt@sXq0rjIIysZ@FLmUESqN@vtSGKlx0lveF9WIV4gJvCxL26Ya8EwkwLXPi4UFzovVE/uVoZV5VpGaZ@XwPLPH88z@rLpFWRir@aBeSYGkyDr0s924oVIYq@Xx50Wj0EGyMXRANhcDWDDUQDtnnww@WgdFp2OrYHdI4jdE5oY1Vs@qO/7EFONwVekSESpZOh9iKSfdyTRxnULhdKFwmx5cPCiphp7J0LEZVKbk@wQWPt9wUccbLnS64cKHGy6WThctAG3gyaJFBhv7PJKRTNBKRGgmA7STPp3wzMpplZeR4COYcHu4clfxYJ4hdhQPJO3d0KMb@XMDb2A@Zdnp1vgCHAOvQEACL33HE1qL7FkWqbrTNSkJoIVZjbRWhobnMNEmnIO5HvMdqJlaBS14J3xMi4pcB3WelGhZKNBlYQUugBlh@Gv0ctMl@snRJi0iKgDfNi4iKjK8Tc82vLLhyYZXNgLbCMpGIBvU@NjTwjJMnkw8EUyvDESKPPSH8KE@gw@1RqchzwhCe/AaneXRmQVqUCqufB7nSsdvrgMdybAOeAbDyqc9req0p5VOe1r5tKe1v5hx7S5lXDsHPK36OKeVDgZa8dSfKKrfUSHVjnz4boNakV2vkBRfodbPQNSqKx/RuaoTOlc6oHPl8zlX/CKs9DFYYclull7s7jS5Wjv2qddY9nEOSFd9PPlDM1IzFDTZb1tZq7y7cmQ5xrvRgMNr9Qfcy/KEAZqAsXKjjRWZwEuFD@uK39QVVx5nsSU3oZbeHew7HHqwB@VreJ4/PDqQFQ07wIHgFuK1DMIo4InIDF7HZARYVQJnEq6E1FNwK9VqX2iEMhN4yE7YhiwACpedoA1ZZFm47PqS5hrhRFkBPVM8Y1Uw6deq9/Q3iBFg/5X75D07H7g2SwSD4O9PJZ6I/PpUAFYsbdbNCPqsa5qA5UgnBJb2k5yHLuIJZDktXeSTBCMnbCIYhOoUN@QZQax37hSv6ToVSuCMUMl5peQ8K6VBO7kAqxGPCBZJNQB26NO847pU@5L3qcmKs6KgiaxDEsMqtJKggKju8@nvAz4V4z2QA1PYKaNWJtPIvnxpTpxbG5Qvyr7EzwBvDWsQLXq9NaxBUjROr/x8YlA@nfaNZz8bVIoYm0KcJl4hJpACBTgFPBMBRi45mYAK3bmTZVkfRUADiY14RDC22AAEBN5P2Cm3MyxstrNcxmyXdVKNgwMGZpSnGxOBbZt1QR1I8cSQQm40DruCBaESOZJl3HdT2azJJEenGvQKBdNBY4d1HoVjWQRUqtqgMdhQKZTQhRLogqmDyZ9F2GZU0ayAHAdsjA3XhEEyaqSfq6nCjBWVsWeSCIgkz@@9UaoUCEmjZgcsTwzYPZyokkoErOyBC2kkWCJ3GjmrAM1iGS0yBKMOVnkyzxBf@oHA3h26Mg1g7O/ce2gMLWEzvREzaoZ5t0Lp/o0/XTf6bt0MXvNTgSci67AbVxkR5CMC6PUfGPJAam3iAeoF4SmHmeVDYrTRg/suV6E1jB7jFt5GyCTsn20A7dCsdkY0p23fY/tZ30FaMV05uQ0ninMlThFPRMa8AsfACxAfxHBmjybm4CjcTORXNSMMJwPxRdwGuvqvAo8EjWRZOrt6ivDqMTY0Yp0Azr40EjQRrfjMcJqlodBBcpIlQfbJKaccqmwqCwnGipSxBIRA3JDWAnD/SnB0IfWO5Nd8SwryG7ap@byNZ/MioDsoK/FEMIc57BVvPBu/8dq3jebmN1r7tvHJ3glMp85eY/kDW0DZ84NeKTilQV7xPuNKME/RTuMKIMPyCWHqM9Y5HUx/1iLRA7INkuPYCOWvoT5STH0cE/Ael1o1NoHlzsrArbcyMEJ@JbijdzMDp3chkN4JQXoXINPbxAwy6axzYAxURtBML4Nsx9DcWBb557S8kJAn@T55tnK37hURNAuwF7dRqkyOvHLsVgTqCeeZMGAXMoFMSV8ASuBYI6GIj75bM8e@tYPq16y83L0gfEk0w5AAKlhWsKTg1CFilWkwKqIMyabQlhcD0jEHFXbIqJFXiN6EU8erFYalOpbMjS@8aJAS45VyFE@tbbQ/f@P9@RFss3lTZaxSCs53ZmaeWCtzY@qAXsMJ31dl0qK62rQhzwhtBacsBUo33ra9GRwdK7JMt3ShCm1eqAyCuk6z9XajerVRVLXBpt3xEMMDui70PdqBkCAHcz3mO5BYbwZc/oCWH36yl5V2Wj0xWJefpMm0SrzJJ4MS/dhq8CfxKLb6W5BafR8EKoQJQ3AgoDOOvGkVt5Q9AZIpaFFpHwieACEMIMFjWF9XeuGGVSJodObrTxvyjDChZroEdZvwOIsiewTw5vE4i23iAzYzQZVAnnLsaINyAVDkJ9ycXGRZ5FMNN6IoPXjDOL6RA28QQxi@iUVp8Lq/0iipvphpWAFMZljhOUgKGp@hBSm4uIQWkeD6kU1tV9v0frWNN6xtasfa1lmjuOk1imlJ34mVphOpcIMhEVIJxl2w6/lkSpG6mk@IgTy4f9tQ6CBZ8A7oiVG3t7HQY9DyOih4mDbjTSKItPVO5k@VbpRqtNQjAVRI4xdi4DMDeCCNZ8jx4kzAQu8YrP6Jw5sNL3yeUWWQfa06z6MgspXGWXVD5slJXenx@p1NbWjdLHWK6rHInQjLX3qPfNUDWn3Cbl4BnoishoosbZihju/JUt4oFGtn9ELzCrl57Ize9dcgBT/hc/QE1jRZhkUOBzIK4qKKwqBL5AyuDtnSRme9a/aJyfOF0ywBo8mokVeoQ67ThpDextJOfgcwKuKZaFCDakxPRzY4oX2f7h9Qr7lQSi1ugTvdBHfcBneqEe4MjiRXQGnMpzseyCuG/bXCSEuOSlcZU4EOajyIZwQNvoKkDp1FlgAmx3R6nZXK68zJmJh@kBIS3yS@LKV6lDok6iFYOFaQbNC646PV5EUVtmnhgpYPJO9UigcndatMWqdUtDXe8vQVx9f3D6@P9DRPN61bKKmO04X1IiKlszrTtkFW7Jx6/cSPDgw9NivNSZViq46dPVjoIHj3Nu1OUO@mUgpm04fJHlSpOuoJNOYVwzxfEVq7GpWQiWk1rwK90j19lXGgV7y8r91uMDhMf30TQoPW9dgEg5kSz4/eD13D/M0p3NEnV13H0K5dGNwD40UXNDRmXQdNsi8v6fzo8J5R@owV7LDm4vshIgnyCsYqwyN430oFmCJv/Kawu@d2Pm29ooCERv8LESXLP06dmYRGIcidZgGTDJ@JHecAkyhrfb7oeqOLrtMVGjQ4V4hTxBOBElGAY4ABBWUkkArt5k0EtutGQC2HHeebt51OcUgAHHtcaEQrAulFZ1a@IddBXjOFZEo14jTxChEJ2nYgJXXx1cFcj/kO1Iz854uvnshrxih0AuBI0HxmJZ4IeYVTmp93k9aHyUcyGBVZO1qyQCfEIpuBK1Mr6OhAK7Uyz8Qx8By6NiO/DRngGvKMWN4RcJIbTnFDCW44vXdYoJIALk/5HGUv6sUqjwxWrSMqz0RIIhPyTuUqaw10NSNPwJHsKVhlQnzhsgx7JzIhcQeZJoUqwbc/4bRQBeCZpbntRjyiCRPV0vyzo6OpHJ5L5eik2jLQGwBIR8uwbxDyONnLMA9vFErDGNi0UmjTysFNK4Y3rRQgjUIV4BHIHF5k6QXvsavEE0EjC1aCbtgoKjQdFAFGBOcP0imV7IUzFCZ/aR0P0brBb2obZYOoGFSk@WtSiSeCLtEnowIMqDNJ2T8J3w00DOEGHHJwZeECjGa5slBBDnslFPQhCE8MgWbKfcODkiou6ynAMfAKBCQTOjtSHEcOFLO80clpVFKaYaOJh4IoaGp2ZSLbXc687I7MvOwOrcQ6Ygssaw2PAFcNFKTkkYFTwGsiexoVspas5V3qQW7wjjLAbJaRJ0LLEwrTYFTEaeI7CHp8lSo9aDgkRIsaDkRP4jqHg0BSdU46EdR3KOWNBsEqTatnQs9ZPoS0MrIUtHOqIqvIM6IQuS6rRAY3ppNbtGMNk/K@jjzMflBUPUeTBrNkQtjQSt@DVYWdGVq7qKOFKiO1zkLA7pUj0dbpKqXzdMJl9ok9pHRZUYKUTpfIQVwjgNCWl7TxSpNRowWzcKXaGgWYbulc1G4B8QOFVamyks7DUIxcTwCsQYDraXCr3Owg2NiBFFyjdu1TSIl1NJDBJ3ov69mclKmzlWsrDjJqxO/iSb3GGnHMlJwnA72ObP3BdOHYo2wanfHGBQXIkA@xHalJT0sFFvh1@zB07AedoB53vDSkQtgd7OUrO34uTiddOpTSmdBjX6lMnlbKPgRnx519KGzsQd@BfZvarwOjkRsn300V7Iw4mMwojMp0AEx8UEAF6cN0GTpB@KDe@G26pAtFTBeCXe93w7JS8AQo6vFdUliFjBp5hXq2MI6dm24axG8xt1xnOEauyJ4Ay9gMm1W3YT6ahZJQW6p7HcET41eSGtezPI2uiKRNIjR/Z@7TzEfbTwBM83Qsver0FIiBqXN1C0L/8yGoqGO4d5NPO6WHMKh8MiE8kw8ilCp6Qrsznx1RZ3ekoL5HYYdkwmojoYC@AzEDqy4VrbqswDMhgPHCBZpV9gRAToeNWX7PlZKq44JQCEbCUd4rQPqYhhYX@UwGHslkFngkytIXZ/dAjdyEuJHr02ZlGL1tLBDC@ZiGZP3pN3NSFU6B@A78lk576xV18QsmbSCzAS0GLmCqSd65xa/BuYP0s/pBM2rkOqhjSyOqCoPjCFJ6qGsGG5s1UQ@qp1RY2PevRNtRBHPcvqr8sK@cG25mmiEePEqSZH5zvNJFL3TprHPpLHNRq1wSmDnzJITpf8NdRRXQQ3K5WZXBxmRmihWOBiWR3jGtuFELbvR6G73chlfbRNnOe3cM7/kDus5bjJ1RO4Xdddg87cOrDGxdoYt2hfllN71YPuykMTjgJLp3uoIoe81P@ADxspII/ieAeSURD/Kz70xo7LAFpsQO3LHIwaoOtPqFA8QutODPPrSEHIejF30gDFb2oxUce5QDxa50B2OyHJ3pJ@FwRHdaQAvbzA40dph6P9SlJt5hKpIaULda/WL6dOxiZZ58an1rJGzs6F0T6urpIIPKBz4MvUBCJ4U9NyYr08E8e9lPCN1siY9@toJfrc4eY1db8GdfW8GxS32PfoXdjnvY4X7@cFOpedM1gexzE@SAZK8bqUI@aKIDhp43/qBzgux7a4q2W@8bgFbxTDgdnj1wQmOHec269ii@l4mPwq4MvoIZhY4atoMnOgu0AHwbeBZokeU4SWre0nc@Iwzo1q4EOlTanUBFId04RlYyAiuWtswUAO5a3DBTZOmuta8UjH1VIdtXDtm@kryQJ3lPXkCCnuTtedITPgUzEwzGUyieA/EYhqcg9tiIku3KBGQrUvXqdJ/O3mmaNAP04o6zoFkGP9T9XU7d3@V2Wt2w4@qGnQ7fKAD82PHwjSJLP3ghmqOFaI4PtnXqYFtHB9s6PtjWD2c6ezETGRc/pEXBEFBDMqjCZGCNQHDzgL3VSjwR2UuqQHrE/fZCwBvqsxcAnszsyMx@zOTGTF4ESpU5cJrMAVNk5uRf1bziwbxi6M7Ks4YZ7So5CyTFkVxfR3Z9HdH1dSTXN07yjVI45EskIGoFeUYYsUKku/uJ3N1P7O5@Qnd3XC/kT7QeKQEI5DTQ1SaVQDCnAS83qQADcnzGd2UUnOPQnArMUVhOBcWZJyNITj74rgJPJOWlU4/hwvHjON0OApNU/IrsERxhEoK13seRvJpIc3kdlHQgL3xChY1SvCCMi8tHWzt6kNLdqZNlDsbW6HSZA5G9@6rM3Vdt7b6ysfvKtozRvhVG1hIkcwWhvf18ZnMR0YPqOPTKMM/vsY6l6qkwUqM5g0o8EczmOy4882bAVk8C4HTasThybVkhWjqlvpNSzJAU1Rr1ylCNTvj26oRvTyd8ez7hmw5zKyIEscwcxjKrQJaZQlnoe00LQ4oM0ZsuhkT8eTXS2roO8KtzKHsxHpbERdYPSbax07totF2JpW0QJzEe/KQYvQN6TR@EFljTKxg@GyhKYcAUuRkSR5JJfaI38A4p@i4LQRIdiuDbO2aa6V1eaF9l@YDeBVsZ5ufuhMYTK2W9CvKJSZlP3qooIKGPTSEBAEeDjlfgA5npNGZvuEoyVP/kkwxDAFfTCscQpGN5kALDKUiedV4YBl9IkNn8jQr4GxfvNyzcb1S03/SOkAYh7OuQLtiWQRUCgSUEwRUgA7zSEtYCyMpIRka2cbmoZy4XVnrlgF7VQ68U0Cvb4Bd1pXMGI9joXuqGKKgN76FuBILDzBXFV/jx9UqiRxnFmWzNo1EEa5UrncicwYRV/ZXSg5d/Z4IpBCUkSq9SO4pXlj0Bkmc01@IlAFRwVzxDOsv4nbySv3SXeyb47mgnQQH4wnEnQZHhZduRS4IdVVGwI5UFO3JhsNgIuFr6Wl/tncO5q2DuFMqdA7nTIXoH8sTgnKaDyPR1NV@3h5KMWTMTp4lnRPnXtUJwgJrbWshRhMySgVPAE8EEdi1LNnlXI4ENQsbSu/O92orvJ3MxKEkLZpWvIIrrIH91DkQvbwFO8gKduwSOlhSx7cpQtKUYY5QMtqYIP5gd7SkF6fGAcasNqibfDEojiqgL73My75io75AZk@xIRs/eMRdGsDujADyTTo2lxnthVHbTzei89KZBzFvqfvqGnEaeEdTQE99P34gMjq639ep6W0/X23q@3tanNQ9kQxWPeSYbXFqWSS8qPyi6vHTuXTuoVuXU1Afj9A7D7hyEfSCnEQS6zyHdcyv2ozfYNqm3MNYL5Z31whln7S23f2IM2ntS8x4V3tjOG7dWI@FHsKX6iun5Khc90JxOFj3KKHKj45UbHa9Gjc1UBBksM3gzlchM9gpv8xVWAuBUU5Y8iCDRfEAl6NGEMwIVSH9mM7yjnULATkJgpwC0Yza2YzZlx2xkx2xsRx6/X0RPMqvLnvaMh@4X2TMICqAKjfNkgDGZcOQnyxAPy2ODhaAVSyODBYAdnrOpBO3QPE4F0s5iuIYsBOwshurIAsCOpeKVAVqxmI@zDDb28UJGMkErEaGZDKSdVY2/rjzUuhruuRUCQSWknqKguN27qnZvJHwLTWbUY1ipebxy89jSdtwCICiLG3KLDDZe6ByVROB0Em9PdFp8IVgVZgRmTniifAFQM2UiAzrDdW5JlqPolm5XLQCji/etFhmiS9fnVgBNr4KwdVUYTEYU5BUhHfQny7JeLwQ@qwXJWYhCPAPQMMuq3kmBmObzxBeLH8wrNqGrvHrC21WdYlUZqlnq2lqLPVvraEIqA3y1zvEj9God5R7HjjnMTo6cvMFRGb7sgBRb/A7iNYJsnBecyjWOB/IdhqXmJg@I8FtqmcmSV4BHEusNeCTKwsWNTpPKC8P16FujkCYbnjrVWWjekOsgr5lCum18YB0yZMdKnCb6MSA8A7LpKZCN50A2NQmycTJgJOgcvQTQIMYFXZxe@WH@EEVC5ugztE3r6NhKQZ4ZWSpE@mNXqnkLQY/sinVvAeCTXVVXozDqaZTTT50iFCAem1ABBEj7jROgHsvmUrOQGjwHxAALxTAbw2AnlWAFsT1OskKkrc/7wM26isBWZmCrErSl2jgVkS1u5VQibYVyb4e0VRHYCuUiD0cPKltOmXLakmNDju0ENQKeGanxAReVOEXQEh1pUYFjQEHN4apMz@Gqjc/hytbmcFX2FmVt0bYWtrSwHaitwsTLAzOiZ6COCiqLB87NYXJnmrjKCBORlypmgnYsdwIKQX8tdQIKgAjYlc2syspKRla2QUMAPCIWZX5DmVAwjt5QBhBQWvl6obAyw@D0GTcH84phyqtjbBK6q5N1Dkqqqi6pCGPquC6pBOOaMhOdIXFQCnbaONRpU4FOG4U5Ubcn7FwF7FwD7Ny8z4QApuhO9cFOzfYMQOblLYVgbHjBSwEYm1nngszIv80orc0oJbUiukFy3qkkc6rSjIicd1xHPhZot2d5RCDb7VkUDu8vZf4bp@oPGhSkCfsDBmATveyMJl6R0CikTIFEVDO8MFKLjY7Aaomh2lmfq3vA0GOz0sQTdA8WOkj2RPcpdLaKPzH6ycP1uxqu32m4fufh@p2Xyu60MnZfFvVSloXfSG75gplMPBG0nAFYoQ@IWljtaWG154XVPpY3d553lYANY4B8ulUlThOvEBOM24b7sRvwTBB0tmQ/MSo7lZEdZ2N3rj3uQ54MJKa78ARnRmSFm3z52FVIc5e3ug5Y7F3eBjpQteFPZgu9FUXyF3DgPiz0SSoEfEoI0rsA6eV9cNxUrIgsOWooVgK2zEAdqELQkhmwA1UA2jE4qJKArIzvalLormeFHsvC@8Irg4R8LOk@QlZLjNWudI9IZVItDNSuLEAmQCIy/kUW0Q/DNNP6g4xgrUEkdfHvIU7wwAzXEBXZI5ikufkV40EVYOC9AoH2CgTaKxDS3auOHlnpOK0wbIaP06oM1Wgpmuq66Z5boCM3uCOn@nFhoL0lBaBN3FtSZLCxB3VIdYMYozeK0Bs984bOv9HTli8ZqwzUzOm6di5VEVyp2xPfP/XEWllFtVFUHUfSGkdUgLIcRfq@JYLpDHnbTC@pdQ9kBAkqBnrLNA5PJ6pwyqUd1fThbxCjpC6BKYiU1B0ilaFa7KX10rphUqaSUQA@iCWhyGiD2vUNsRloxDdClvjT3SAphkmla2aoxmXUqDJqqIwaLqNGnZPUkGeEsfOBYxfJQh@FBkHxCkcsHd/b40eHuuKuLbpnS92xxfdrhSuutg58pGsBcrqoEE8AJqIK8VdN8NDsSDsVSIWUIjpDF8ZqTik5Usn7YFAn74RBJbkEI@TbRVf5iDxP6mjpPH@EAkT3l/HdZfreMnVnWbjCIq5Ah@wWWcy0FeBRhkozA39VAA7UjtBxCaqIIuCoFFUCWXGiqa5KwpUQvokMgnTUupVcygQ9iggdygD8cbyWtSG05GiBayNoyw7Klh20LTuwLUut2TDhmE@WHcme5QAA6qEJhjYC9vmLKEM38u/jQ9mAtAtWYb4YDxXDFzothlurCWFrlZYQB15BnEZxZ1a5zB0l9DIDiO5KCvyzckR7wibYxhZwFXIm1MawdFZ1ApBsln@nnzEEZX6auW9TGVrRp4MHfTR4RJd0EcHpasQC4kKpKVUYZJuE0rBOe7hpWupWVgJpnRAkdgEyte2mPxSFYRQ4MSgh9hN7s5@UN/uJvNlP7A1t2K/AE5GFrsjCF5eyxsoyKuDHqQAP5ELHBRZEAX1pTiplGiXV1dMR4IKxIp2xLaAnSuOjjYUOkoOFB2R7OIjaUNBEjB4ejKKRln5zq@/JVfJssXnKjfUnJ/WbocmuylDNDGl4CtUyY7WglNgSlNLU1lnhVqxAnQIVKu2OrwSKR0JQPAqQxcNNLztvG20QHZ54nMSpycCMMECeHcRj85J0xPsg8Dz6oCqWjEjppletHBRV@erzTFBlV9lip0yxL9SvjwAU7ryfrhJodt1pN10Fstn12LgXVIgnAilcgJdAV88PXT0/3LBSPykjqbRTC2Dn7/@OX/@dvv37OpxOdslrlUS0nljGJNGrOiIyUz5pcV9f8um1ZarhIbXbD2jjoB1dM3aY6zGvIfTJMsy@Hm493e3GoUCtCclSkesgr5hso0Q2WztS2meGCc@XXmSCKqfY9U9HqUCOeWLINWvvGoWDot2RL77IiC6RSMzVu1Dw3CrxC72KwpMhOGRa/IBJFfEs2xGNeEaToacw7pHcccV5YbSGPEK9Z6ZBTKL4/cFSWAiUw4SgJBYAZfGcx78guHMe/5KBnen6gkj4XMaI8uH6VDc8KXpW8YTjEgd/IEsHDWKd8oQYm0qhN31gWaSuvOa7IfTzSgvBG4FQr3odzxOSPbWS58nQJp80cSBMnCudNnEQjO0jzcPIoY7M0pGFJ6GWbkUOKvtViqForTMlAH2k9lWbwHTAT9bOC5Z3Wqwc5VTZaa1CUbVz6nqD6NQ8vRqVWzOkFzTv1DRqiB7dsXHUCNhahk6pLxC9U2eWF0RKdtTG7Mi29InjlaFabDerr0VmpGacqrMTU5V25w7KBtFi78bHg7IqLM5OQC6U3lenPyiu80FxnW@/09/ezvlRDaJfveOL9rVzwFCEOLnSAJRi3onZCNYIelt9YrQlPaLOhsKDUjT0wu4GSZHXYxSESgE/qIEe4OLM43CVYCmjwbYKoIwF@EQH8glri8CFLFARu9V190JUv@PrvLWF@YfsVJJmRgHV1fuHSpTx1d7KyQGMIA3vZuAYJYRBlQYKo3mEzFVaLOjBPeUtmU/vVtVSd8u11EMd9RAZn5Owb2c8MyICOGth98Z9RVvi@cuDaa@R8PxBRCWolR4FyexyG048h1gQKs1GKc2Glfibd@PL1G/0IrN8waNRb9SzzzJs0Sqko/QAIF9YFi9wa8QNBwuyKPd0FaBVHkL2aYxrIU8KhAfNBTuvCaDCJH@EJJJllUoql1MspTc5/nfDm6JudGLUDcYGb1Bl3ch1eY6@PkWfz9DnE/TV@fkJnNO9Vq7HSBFKXAWkslkY@TsQqYE4W96pUxm@JK7zKnGaeIWYQO40dEd3A54JgqDMssMre7dSMF5HwJMv02lSBbswCGxSg8AFoZKRf49SkAWcPhPqI0GfiBsMZN/oGPcbnulxw0HuG8YVnb2DAGMddGcC3ZjA9yUk@ZnJCaEaFOgio8KRwZGgkpS4nZQJpn7vnLGDYqJ4faVDg6gYVHHJCAO@KZ0bq@DG/CjDG7On4WXno24PCh7t80Ud39AgKa7GdZYCyx/kA3dej3en1Xf3vDCOl8tJ6hHnT5FcOiehDHie6fjVglCJFq3d6bjTKDs@lasytHOjSN7Y7g0jfcNg9DjDvTPKcFdjDHc9wqCahAU4Bl4BDAkaCUV2JHuWpRe03fKudlveabPlnfdaRvA6k6PmdcZw5WEQWXpx0ygONeKbU7IsK5I7HiBBo3mq7VwA@l2I56cm0eCshMMNUIUVNMvW6xMpYwmuHd204sJ1YU9Vu8RaEO4MGYu6owU4AvB5utMBCHe5EisJI0qGfqVUdiMmixs5RdxoQZQ/zvOLwfhHgj3xhNQYQ4U0ypBo4KKXEBakOagh4wppzPh@NQbGqDOQFR8tqrrzoqr7Na@uGImAP9eJzrvJBMoYHpiSxWchExASIwF883TOioqu6oBWArVIRV49OMnOYEUq@IBt4sJm6F0@mTYoSxzwo8hp2lXueKb0MHTRM77TiE@RHcqQrfGAkftEvrqRRPW7ofR2IyXOs9wJZFGGn2d6rTO/U5gVyKIs@RNNlxeAFnCyvMhogyblKyErOIVdAdhhK8oGWeDnA@fxoHI4bnkvsrRhX14oRQsBKwmBmQLAjp3ZjqV9B5mgGYs7D@6WdggWgL7g/sAigyfulVa1HcgTg5VuBwF/qFq2ar7lzkeRVOCZEIC61PL8zJ1OL6myJwAytwML8ZoEQhQQbp9p4JnCD/yYP/hjrofxHvTtfkC19KBqSQ35PbAaepSFFiIWj7LSQri4b3DAfpE9AvFBLOIziPeB1ha@D7iU8N0uLzKAInsEIoAiHgF8/PjxO36LPZ4vPv7v9eOn/yxXpn94n6eXb70M3vzx97/2kx8n6TujSSsgXKwjvyg/fOflT36Q4Gi@ePl4@sZvfvgv//blr/7n@N2vP/7t0y9/8Plft08/2P/9x7vbv/7zxy//6U//8Fe/@a37m38Yfv3tv/7mr/5x/OmP/vaPfvmb755/@yff/dM//NGnL3/4@NUPf/Ffxl//6@fvfs//w/bL9/0bn@2Pfr3/5V/96c8ff3v76//4t98M//5/v/37v//X5neff/jyP/7j0z9971/@5fT1P/i7n/7NL35ivvcD/zfr9//q8gefv3G9fHI/fP2vf/mvX/z7t7/307/@2V/87Nth/OWv/@OXv/3@t3/6h9///vd@@ufffPud@e0w/uDtZ3/@m5//8/oHf/FHv/qHz39vf/792/TD9ac///c//vPl23/n/@Z33/yH8Z9ef7H@27@6b/z9T/7ynx5/@4Nv/Le/@NmP/v6Pf3H7jx/9v3/58nfbN@1f/fc//t2f/uC353/8xcdPn75TE@TjHs7f/pOPn2rafvra5cfzsLyMw4fpz6b/9Wff/T8//vFHM3207sP0nXR/7HCKz0TwrY8fP03rxzG@4KuL//2Ha/zTrR9CFEOSQwK39cPdfXhx@/phts7MH9Lthh/SBq72Nj9F08P6@OL@Ibaupg/nKOY/f/Lpa@enKx9NDDMrWBeDP/7@YrUh@WOOH6eq@GlYxy@m76Rv1Vv2@NN/O6So/mk6J1gCjaofEiySiZkx62Qzv758IWIe6beysfivZUH/8F9Lbk/p8bQj4hRznf@zr/3e8K2XDz@O6VazbcrJHz997fem8wcf3BfnL4ZPnz58/ccfXqLq76VjSaLOP6cS87MhDa/@2cdvDVH79/Iq5q8lp6JeVfvJPOeQ/Idt8N6MX492//P/Aw)

Ungolfed

```python
l = 'eigh ceiv eing eism eign einv reins reim feit veil seiz neit einf odu eird istic rna igl tera seil eiss reini heists tm rpr isu eip heik dece ceil feint herein fy ido eish nceit ucl rlo olt noe eio dri caf trad rote icat hein iress heife mr ji oly mad iru ifo eia egr cys alb uein reic onot nthe ndee kein isin isan inon iger code cave beig weirs veins veine seine reine deity deists atheist'.split()

def f(i):
  if 'eei' in i or 'eii' in i: return True
  if 'eie' in i or 'iei' in i: return False
  if 'ie' in i and 'ei' in i: return i.index('ei')<i.index('ie')
  # there now can't be 'ei' and 'ie' in i
  if 'ei' in i:
    return goodei(i)
  return not goodei(j)

def goodei(i):
  if i[:2] == 'ei': return True
  if i in 'brunei lorelei nuclei taipei deist heir heirs heist rein their theirs theist vein weir'.split(): return True
  for w in l:
    if w in i: return True
  return False
```

The basic idea is that most of the time, if 'ie' is in the word, then it's a real word. So the code first gets rid of cases where there are both ei and ie in the word, and then checks if the word (with ie's replaced with ei's) is a real word.

The way it checks if a word with ei is a real word, is it uses a big list of strings that are present in only real words.

Comment: Wow, very cool!

Comment: [614 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY/LjoMwDEX3fIV3TiSUxbxUVc2iCxZ8A2KkAKFYCiFKwlSdn2fCY1rJi3vs65d7xGGy78tCo5t8hF9DTd6ooL8@skKiJsxKiaQxu8q1JjrdTqPzOgS220Rz@lyTnWYNCiGQc3EwzifkIjhDkfHsJo0am04BnQspqTq/1ZMHEl47o1rNihyRk8UuRBh8igBDkt5CTBhXjmvix8LdQ@NnC2by2oCdWwNRkcP/XWmusg92B7JA0Cfc5JVn/esI1Om7zTD59OhTswT6WaDDxC8VK7d5/PvGXleXecF5TqIn27GCXw5V8roq9vXKdrB31svyBw) (I had to remove testcases and the compressed string to fit the link in a comment.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), <s>12,707</s> 12,219 bytes

(Thanks to ovs and caird coinheringaahing)

```
import zlib,base64
print(input()in str(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(b'Gar>nl]U9ZcgCa<oj+@,\'?AS1nH1b=o[Rk#ee2NMWifr*#`LJC+U"3NCT@F/s/+P^XUT5B[lgj.<d`u6:Hb_TF^sV:L\'l=S/;0*L>"WSdNO[-TSF4jrG//I)2&?mN5GuDk*e_R=A\\%t.fC[LC&pH#7g?%!p7&73\\!d/)tIu4%`Y7HlX^It/F:BMTia&e3ae-Y3celTM.]6\\TLJbPK,^(?D(X.bh5A<^KUa(%76YA)Ge/]f)J@<GsX^IT5JFBJrdM/`>?O\\s@r8]YHpbSR2r>cm]VXSSgK/Zfd@X&nGlV?=Za;Fbe`25!/?3&=j]p1R+)V1n;)E*3JF.qr[=S\'&8gq^@"Q@[FOkho\\c:Y["8!Bd3WhGrrf_@ljZA!urR#*n-Dk_NrTdje9\'sib*]PU(e+(4#jV""]]ETlM=WW*"Ch.CMkGjTT4/2.`W->F_\'mT%bif6o!R#Z3Uf&:B+Y)3]/1_;qR`U:C4X\\6a`F!SH0([s@:sK(F:WqD9-WH<X4BNZ:n_oZ8kVDYQF4/KO8`M-hXcF`91sguVcqPu6Y?"tmtm[0,s4iCjSct]$aAIm..-:5Ua7\\ic5P(@nFSX><:2WMT`H$0W\\Q:c7]jt_cku>!$?Npb^9)Z0;e.piJ.O),rKUfX2>`inD&g`+N4DYAKZdgXmm(7V2Z4m.D0Lp@!dD^7E4I3J0#9_=3%+okq^L.MmZ_P:r_DeM[(%<0O\\*)t%7h=3/Hr[&0NKe%]cI84G&\'t?f!^7:C*5(mc-j:.\\hntL!3F)\\Of$j@i&,V\'_J8RT!t#(LA]1@*iC!tUreuWF_(g.u#&Ick$-Q^^XH;`i7.n?jb@R)Z&(HNg\'nR=^K-B7m^:`!D3k;\'f#="T<ji_"Gj(o&>#c6>OYX;as*mHGT!bosZIKjC.:VKFk*]eo`ho@cp*B@%kZ6%6e3s@^iD&"WJ0iZ.Nh1\'`:[],ioN\'$U[pA6\'H>)"Ur.fq2OC.A_0#1HIS(Es<>pKWg1Q%he91<)E[j;WCqT?*qkkd210Dg@\\`K$n<c@d$.62f&kmPF6LknL+j+Tu0\\ME8aHfUCrC,R5LKpQjG68b%pZ4h]@0>I1rVoR9#QYpm>KgU<=5k[u7(a-sVPr8FtuUPj+OI?`$ST4@:`fhAe#&G6&0@;b[@)XAu`\\6K"7;o!ShB"P,L=\\eGCOZ7[,/#`YD4r]qM@lT3I/@I\']SFh@G`"_8phAlR>=0:%HK``NMT+!aeCWLt:m0VSGuO9-4Z:n"H+O;66\'ONYX^IA+Vd6*l@n8f.oVmA`t#.e))J$n>a8)?PmQT4mb]Nq3c7\\h"c$lZtN(=:G%[9\\7aRC(u\'9&1oRP:V&iG\'Qi^Ii\'%lYO?eC"aIURS5k`UVO[$o!U/*o6J3nFOc=%bplJD\'BD=NE+@bS1j,KMFW%b\'B"VF*iX:r<:YP/RTsddE&QjCN5&6/P+4fHB*C)`"Z+a?*VIP3W0fIKgq<.`R%EAGoUSM5X_DI(D-aW()Ed\'*eS:(DE%?6Sf;/ADCianA>;WpGlZl!jYlC3()Th(t)4d"d]&9nG/]MT.&KbQdQDM0]Y6l<.\\8)am\\g87cG%QW2T,sH4Reifs#"<I>+R0-Pku_&(&uKo30PBM*/777Uj*WqKdE]4`dbsQ-XM>Sk>6O:tY6_lbFIG1=fN[dB\'_nj#[6%(K1X%AT\'85*L@AiJM>:OhL5!,P(uX%&r.6h)k&dK1U!4jCM!UMSY\\)PbWKb?6A1dn^>n;a\\E*Ud\\gh^GZaA_&J8aMi,MB/>HDm_$Aab9YD;MEN^S:nlYd\'$Gq@GZF*C<Ta$M0k`1_ZjfK-Q4LR5Pj+\\dGY%F``4i(5&nN>R/)D3\\`/k8o<h]&@\\>?p60(CFYHfYCc>6-5\\gbc_?M6nCS*oIB+CZVFEZ!oQ$Q1h^18/h()NRG_#bj\']jl?=nQ1CHeaG_;`?;@dq5XIV-rXauWBqqsQRr,/4AVi2?@>=,=&,tl[7R7XW=-2C?).&"[Af?Am:R3J.C$=sM"GF[)3PAQof&3pWnEJ!^=(DEK#AMV7dMc:Fn*`p04Q94O:`7o,J"Y`ZZDc;KS[a9K2[fE=nb*$8R)5[::<tLJNNsgE)fPBkXDN[_TU\\*05f-M3C3DlP$WFGe3Fb&V;c8=R$\\C(JCRPWkSE\\?"BnUOH90Ye72($T&_VNRkDqKQ&dM8ZqP@_k0T\\:=Et@D.VLM;SKmBlp,boCO-opkB4\\q)1KqHbDZS(AQYEaSTH%h,VXr+.\\Q*u3)FC@LcTI`X*A07N\'\'^CcF`Y?B03B2%+1_Ea&+1^_F^%G5!O>*bQGA=bacuoSXk\\(bi[];g]<lo)i!?Z$o2KR*l>N]_V#S&LJO?R,s1TQ\'6!-NafDE@*f]kQ]m,S)aV9mCLtb:u`bOrg&+ejKM(GNu6"3SgUR6O34K^*s`fOkmpq[11JQ6RN1H.DQq%":?kIH-dF^U1%56nF.(TI$!ND`#TG_4rlS;\'_^]S-n[(PT6sBhN[Be9F*_0)mg*"s!I\'p4NUZ:8k-I68#Z,\'<1X<^VR\'COr;`r2lF4F"Rn[qT^#\'fU6^H!<ZfR]b:hN\\Lo=<l^%NCm%cVmbd49[AVpjTZi5#+<h\'1U!Mt;U(S1B[m0=dEpHT^*&X>U,7)PZ!4g*PWE97^jg.7(4M)Im/kQ4:T=aN^lt5#^P31HRTc#;!@#4,"9kpJ[iTI=:+mE<SU"KNIT;(R??MsaU^"DC+TE2]]Rl$R#ci:%iI3+%";0`ElEFYq.X#9ST^e&hH;`[H,g$p##O3fqV)GC#qQ2(],FY28Z8SHZ,%TDAPS2u4\\#K1hB_1YV^Qhj:(W=tR8X:l?lW\'`(I)`Hc$#/Gi7I#B6V8eQ2\'][Pf*:Zlq>dG6Uas1\\t-fsUY]!\'l`kdKd-\'<"C/BiWB/7#qYZ[C;ab?W>l8B\'VJ7Y<dB)o8H^=jaW#f2;97m`^RK[J?`MTG2RY\\.?;H\'Ag(j0#:qDmE\'m.R[6-grZ/l]-`7u(5KdE+?9Wo$tTQn[FK\\XoS?r=M,@6Kk!pNGVSo"1(\\L;l4IX]86od5S7WpHf]NNiZ1I+]hs;RAi0i*#1^%Hlj3XkKbkk:G>Mi"ruj5;sZNA^>kTX$8Ic!\\J<Ed$*gf)Acmlf-0^O/Emn;0#X4q0(qgQ(LP5A`\\-br8KI5<\'BqG[s">sl]bX$Y<*e[5E=2Hia[*Fu(#1AqMLGnYe`l.BY/^/S0(Kj&UAdUrHN-J(OPt(*P\\liQ08k2D=$2hlUYV8W!)C_LuPBin*\'f0$#9:B"i7[M\\8nNtOm,?q&4BlCTIkDi?Dkqku6)q,M$I7pN5rC5nLO-2cR.s[]5^!a(L;gsU0a.:Xu/6?EJO&iQY%9]:Z<ZTZi-?O)EHt)tPob\\D5TR)f^Y3MfM`^;jol?M#XiXfclGJT(9got=_dcYp?@71Z,j0++8HDaHAPFSYV*i6s5Bhn\'EQ[@s(oMU$Dcf4CVanX%oqj[HMHm^IWm?RSCPclqR\'W7tHT8qY++^P@ma7Di\\;Dr\'IC:6Kpr^u!89k..b&AuISoK\'^W?k2K(WJ`mK$@%Bt%kUU#k8V8n^d3R6H0r=M4Hb`3IV+0E+Q>FqMI;j$KOn=`Ku3DJqHep7#0DTXqFJ2e?FV@6l\\X^g?mSY-q\'`6Y*Xr,qN^a?P9TR]DoLHc-m(r+i><($**i;Kms#KNK&E/2#/Jb,^,lgC3q(QSdps.u6J<@hXQTA^][a@U@6gY!QA,?/*@9A=&6,\'"4>R7Dl=,c_\\K#ON,aIp`\'Z?`Z4*Z-OP1aNN[9bk`j4JH6qRVYP+-EBq$D%CB9%QloHSO_m*O);K(Sh1M@5Co2[,A4<=D(/rC&GpZ*>Wt%OTWB*C0E_K\'b,gIt!0a1C*2rHk`UuL"Es1V9H1;f[%00NhT4n-?\\s*:iOl<&)Lu$nm<PV,Mc\'J12:dqj5i:;CU0H,o^d5Nii@fTQ8g^RZ,2:,A$E=5#!kRf5]#co\'.fUR6N?85CW`B4%;/!Xi1!*;Q1.+F1tZKs<TO9aB%O2B%[?s*St!S5&HNo(SGL9*U!pA"[)c3iS4\\#V[I]^>hC,OI-O4S&I4SFB$0r^n70?qD;$7uW7U&A`9ok_q)#ZLp^TV$-qlQ/e@!$r[g:0InNIJb$l#.;2`qaC2rJ1Mr"&JW)%80%D-1KtRYP;+RGR[O3)g#-\\LbbZX.e=igK-$.Tcu"(]e]/NIc1N_C6ZVIaf2[Un/>=(<#:HE$ZjP:lt"%ZT6\'nW5\'*^R",q5@#dH->lC,Wq7&7lZ6O6)9?2-NeD;(@W`P\'B#u?e42GAeRJ46<jm[@*N9uIWlKQK5U=l\'`MXeo]h9G3-3r:DTJ[9a]C0BLgZ`I_JVs,$1-><f[#uD)9HM[?.^gHY].@9W9SfsHDW-E4?)gHJ]KA9;%%5XdY5T##_]NhjS/f@uY$TqscN*\\-;@p+D56]6_+0485:>e<(YmBd[_p<59X_^)5di=5qm8Top/%K$6s`>:#;#"pqW&\\;YNdOk7E!I7qF!dRfqc"*]^1V\'2hfZTM>.7=^C\\L_Vr[K,B(1)2hmg#RFh@D;jL)$9hGMJPA784QUpCa(Y$iG1FT\'5Ap,R(pBZC=(Z0c9>NC$5TRh]-_;4)?EP"Jgpl`.HkIJA5$.p9]d",mrI)$=9?#=-MunVg9K!aZ,ENZE]&6R&,P9a44l8`MVt?0$o`#l(u(\\TfR/FoVBXDaiJ\'$aQLA7R@NHEiHBA<UTJ4\\)Go$6o4R(2_jJq/VX+oej=**:KgRXeoZeM.EK*b0>7cq^L5%pK_$me\\eK0AJiq$`Tc7B@";C,(h_63=.rOY^@/Hnk3Bj$Kje#SVflm?uNq%kWP,VSX;n=a^<T>9OTX*$!NE"F.AoZj_HfW8hM\\@!^`Wp\\bAsFL-gK3\'E]H[9s+.W<W*u\'9MT^BU,Q\\G"4U6FKB98OkPOHSf\\7/)q2uLqDk/mrf48>K2*<c7AtRL4BIK-U.\\X-p!=P@X6_2S/YDP$HKIr&<;5UJ)"T>\\%%@9<p-b=>EEl<J)X8ergVu#c:0<1hXiRL<P"fTK[\'?!5G/fXBbUoF?kfraa<ksFAoAWDKqa@Q4gqE"*,"+jqF#;[7oOsa^!4\')pOp8]c/Jg?ART(:1`tQ<RpA?Ifc@`pH0+_<E;jN6dd[aN"UFh\\[<=<\\:Xg;e(>-PeR`-!1(2raU!;E=OoW.\'bRJI,@\\fAM%N3rqufB\'Xn=h3>7G)c#cgGhO"[j2U.pr\\eY\',&RM<>fKdlQ2WZA>OX34;\\bhW:l;UCnY>t<Eq4)D(<L4J_2_9:`YV?<1*@!^Nq#)p:p\\mOJl75tHgmu5+O]&qfE&BLW:e)e*rk8@Uo_BCBI#ebQZA)&UQ:Bh\\o5b.3WDJH,Ar.L^hDVi5CH9g2[;XQ+N*oG&/PlUaP-++nikEmO_S6V5AW0L)V&i:=?9==Ktf1(lS2S`KN`M>\\PkD#.Q@X0XRXJ!7#\\\'inP!DMki3[/^BQqHLVZNQ1q^l$Mbin`_a<\\9h(65\\F\\#feI;"s)Dm*KRl;\':EUO%@=FHGmZo"*E*2*NRJ)FOt-W4Q>7OO0^(]EcLtS4I#*R)E>jLbT5g&X:>;Hh9&K/ILL6UNHR4<:$0rdG/.J?t?K1\\qAJ,&F7qe68tOEPj)ru09!8CIA9d+<oP+@88:lJ2gGkaA@4TI]!9*%FFBi&J,IYm$)B$L9N\\bc0UAl1iE#q*_,KJ,O.Q8@`>b0H:OjJ@58d>jaE1fFfA+]Qr4+NG3:M0+q0t`Qs)Y`nm%G_8o#_i-:q/`R-loWFeao3C.%M-c?N.:BpUau3df6[@!U55dNf7NZO>5kMMqW2>+krku0&`;@`VB_QqMfAagVcpome@%8m%>;FN](d%D,Uk[gD%*2D0cYPr\'_t-Am:^ORW\\\\^%p=9XK"Y?#gj:/%5M^ku\'9Z>Pq7A6`W`^tUk!7W+!T0X-)q"@1+(To0j4=9jI4SJU&:,K1$oAnNO0-_I>Oq/:$T4,j(oXn9Q:aF9"#HWq/(Xao4?Hi\\q2*a`;O@EMb+JV-,he&K<n\'1qH37SQ5L:p3m$1U8j&k)a[E6c)pF.OR[eg4#PGOc&N!WjRkH!eAK(Z4W3,POKcNMN"^S<B)"_Pq[90\'3bo.kPYDH+q@;<.1c7kQ<!?Otq.3TT3G+U/GjMh4$j*Ei$(Z0u(KGkPUYi\'-SE@V&8p\':>8&hpGC<LGa#18@$3*Z<[^)4)Ft%fDrAG0?08_rN48=+T.N298=k)fP8JpA,Jo;CCh?G:\\X*$Z(:4p`rJ!p0*ergAO=G\\mqU;\'Yb3$C\'>dp]kK+G>fX_+S*;$U+j:I!dbL@-)`a.0k)pg6Y_,.G8aa/o$e\\D4*6&&I8"!hVf,HAu#FOa!jH@-9iJbk$$fRd+hJ9IfZ:Y]=mgs_9,:DO!F3fgiGYU/bHX#H:d#RZG[9D4rbmW7;;l#:]c\\NSoZA;]%9G?\\]nG=7PW4.3\\i-i6L\\$]mM\\omt*"9(:HJ&#=KpCfe<8cT:(`Xl,I:YdX1;?$(8G_q0$<CRf`LSCHI,iJJM78/l3@?aM78T\\VXg&3B_=3V\\g+k4Zf[h!W3o4B9%L#fiaHYE^DGpY0a2^\\<-=+mM5:r=d3X&YRQLO#H&LY!$tLauhnUHJ:dWk^=Trel,*nbU8mT?lj>!gdZ*S3%.QHD<ra4>2O*,Z9=U-cal^f+\'uCGI23BoNDV96KoJ*/nM74a?ubdHcdt(-B*_0q6beER]qG)[W"IZ+?7tK+m=)lsb!@2,.*MY-`p8(j0qI[rL,!q3OnR"LbD8Y3_f.^oJ4d<]ameZiF$V[+i.\\.@e]qo?Ymk%%Yr`3=bW`^7HpZ^92"!&%+5BjU-J6?KRUhI5aWB?nr\\9dL%i@VZ"OI[p]b`&`/DYgBq]4I!3+@6nn0O"sHC/r-c`D"e?Xt0jlhNhdT=$I="2Tf3%%5aR^(+lO3DKg%Wd33XD[%`6i@XI_@lo(f$t-.]I3IDb5;IZ\'%Qc.G#cn7$d62^Z_PE61WB)e57RF\\F*gp@SaE\\ZcS3n#.A9-L#$hEeiJ;5e<.u#\'2iuSFDeKOT&YSC5]M4EhtB5e4G*l18@>m.?RK"r;-@/9LDh>&DnVK_<uCeDXg?\\n6F<PI@oE)\\a4dlT$"ok6cMh`J#($:s5O:V1(Db+#Mtnh(Rp)bLY[J"AFHKs`QMR:eIo"X,-Co^ss.er^Ep,U/NL:l\\l3JHld._AnAfl3Yrb<*R(8J>Q3=G\'Asl;T;ZUZ4OtN\\M.=lG[qXD48+K>GASPbqMsu66D\\%*!jCZ(a8fTWT&+XP%GPQFW3*Z5IaL^O()eANW@?q9l!`C*6P!sZ:-^+%<O>aoDQP&0O>`2AK&6W[,rdAP*h82rgAnW\'.M8rikj0T9#`C1p_8cRAS`H!BU[B`f#eh*?c7<Eob,33$`af4[!t*M-F8!N5H@\\o:.c$g>c!mnhpZA0*pH>$RHN#q@1ioON%s)7l92a@/a*<I_]`gLu1-t0%A.Sj347\'i8X;\',SXnL8.]94Nn8S;.g":`C\\KrW%<kp2`t&/Gq>)hcLRaIbql;tj4q\'Ki#RQ7Hkm3q[k1O(3@-HkB_+,Y%IgI""K<?0HHL.jFe5S$^(#_6STe0!YI-_Y74_jfX[P]d?gV/,gX$\'kZV]N<#6"J6<_pp9RZ>s/To[p.$D\'c2A@(\\Lq^3lUKbD6K>YRc9l)\\=6!Ooic/?J6,2TAcp[kZ@NRJ(!DKnFgF^P>VPfEH/Q+T^??h3mi9YW=F3sqeM8\'_//a\'78htROe&g$_&d=o)ifIA-p9<t1(>no&?k^[<KC4n\\XOY`GXceNEFYR78Xc_1+tG;8BWB4cq=QIM#L5FYV=Y<F3GqECNte0M2(\'5CX_$.Y"JVd9tc/M*gr?6b;YeC!&[(EAMsj9a4VM,Un#j#il/m&$WRduo*U!C/CYqZGEbhRX^H(D^Td5MI"H#G<In6g\'?X?g@]=]PGlSXoB7/kWLE<[cE0]Yi[\\`EkaLCKtM?_=afT-Z4K3/_a]JkpT\'LMJS6;%6=sMD7Nq?UpL&rsTt8%t5LY%r2.W:tA)R?`SL49gq]q<ILs:eVMqgK@j!u8lNRJ%Q,W8U*qQU\\6O2^<[/oKSJC6d;pI@+"fW"p3I`(kUakrp\\r&P",Y@N,o\\3J,USGu`2d=a]]\\Zn0\'L^d3RV&]P$&i%j:h-u^Gd:\'+t=6rjX)r:],Bc@-r"GTGsd)(1FE>!Of`[/h+hOgFr<3%>&r\\TBQC$3kn.Boq<8!3-*^kE2GO&W(%LH+76X`i#N-@$ZX04Aj"%Y^6`n*XXR5"&lVE#?X&;]1aU#@JVNR8JGY2-rW:Ho[,f/JP%\'\'%Q[AD3KK@"9rs3Wk?]Mr>SQeLRL\'<e7+o2Kre)!;7HtIPDnRIe@]H.ma3PN/i)Lo`J;%X`9:SF(E>G+D%a[7ZM*pR)+&WnG%5FMK%(=0,ni/%5MRW[bqMLWDFD(__#BPUKHe:$J(;6jZM]r%t7n>4?J,S5s/[FYk>0mec(I,?gK*?tlECubA.6*A5iNAMqV#ejDhGGF=LD7s%muZ6"C3AGg,EP\'>RLhQsB.NNeT$;8IMVhDf&G&FI\'9`1dL\\0RIF7LugZ4`0f\\p*[72D$iF4Q(Ja:=at;E"o/Oe"5i$0Q>H!21LaN*-o_jWc^_g.SIZrJ7&5G7>q#CD&O(siQZV\'PIN!TMOS^F*S4K;n1)#M;c<K:r\\p9A";s3Yd4_ZDfnoN_W[%14]&>A06iIg=p$+-UE9(F11B9/*%Tlq*4X8@fQYB-#>Hc0#]\',`5qPHAlX]GkV=d=g)CFO:C3"NNBr$@Ep$r.,/3tLU^8R&EAs!;Pi/_C[f]SiH$70Fp>s"+,s!JPNkYc-0Dl34&16l+$\'.AQ/[GVFIR<#mF#;9TYTg]CG!#K(*i65@4j,>52gp`@639"l4a=Z]W8VXE*NBKag-lEd(nT/\'G]6VK!4W!"hD3O\'$tbB/<,""#\\:6+0,pq`:HnYG=@@N]%[5jlRB[B47snO9O_1VCuhA[EYq_M3Z?cgnIbG(^/$\'3\\-.fjlqEnHHT`g0!_Y<?C>;&-P&<3ZVErdH+o1t\'\'Zj7XBKLh);aa]ibl5go2!<aI]L?\'-RI\'0Pg!DB??0"YJsTN3GC^T=oACo\',q`USh*muAd.V_,WPmbm6@Cua1?qpYe`hXm9%@-t]QFn!JDI=b#;T.7;b&IK;/2k&6Z-*jlj0.-E!<s"F.=SUELNOq-_D%GC(-GDeEOOh`<@!chP\'iS^rA&>@LID;l5d?-3++R98W.u2eSRGKe?Q49@W,n0QGca5J.mtoES*Q3m@SqIJST!,_+puQ4%9A!O=K>j?+jTbW3""`;DkVCWk<eUWY\'p9A5p5bWHBDNI$L1<2)a3&2tt[1p5MC#gQLGo,sg)\\W8VXEW\'IOeh?U.]qG-6`eXZY$M;3]_"8O+sIAo(80(tbGbQnSC7,q"m?ZYlAYdeQSWp+:1Y&6gUFct<j^ugH0,K-La4bVB[hK/dZG1`lCrh;=NZ7c1NF`Mp$i%pHd4L#04!#A?P$2e5u:U#l#mtA._TaR[h#JlU4"n7U*b-/&$@#M71]S<\'2&i5&Mo42n:A-k:$i2+LN?S\'OnAiO]Pi6B>e`4]Su%VQB8ZMlQM_AOgDKc\'A]ke&Fcs4U1]\\8g:*Mb1rD=]gQ:G%f`"(O.5/1IA>EJ[R)H^86ife1YRO:5Z8tBEE.PWSp`RH)@FXR?m<bLjY!Dr^H>ph,HH\'K*f!@,i\'hP(C_q]0s1uO$?se,rbVbAQMk<WZNP)+5:He(5V),\\QNV7"j6@EjKLgW-&\'.Xb#nC6+@&B.3F9^3;\'KrN#&S\'jZ)M($l%gLTEcsQZ)rjm*\\"Z#53=SIiG#p3R\\cFRs"&!/N,Qo#:6Z3#;nIWK^91#eu$B:*BQ39pe?@F\\j:[_:kF/(:0150O>,o)=.XLDO`\\2[t:c)Md/L*8@:QYQf,S5NO"Ur%_#Tj*1O+RPP/$$u\\$/?C$1P((.ehC^pJ9[_LS?N-P$6Fb]rHVs8FI>>LW9TnVAo4pha$"uo.5jICMh8b7UD*d?5c\'=-p7ffpX*i6JBR-CJjL*0AA+U\\Dinmb9uZ6-G92D;Aln5sT+CbY)2.VjF*^GlrX=/JHL`c$*MfLLcb0Q=..gBGrIJ5U?u:H,;<j,PGNOQaZQ.jma7,nS2nm\\>hiE%L-juGYoB@-cL!I2uj=2<n!P!&6\\"t\\l)iWcn1l@_1.5_[\'mJMPn4fB2t/;>;J\'KqDATA>@VoE;FG:c32f*KKLqp-ZloJ(#Yp9sV7\'7iM_.U5PB;$Z_DQ_!hg(RG,@ZBD"TEq<>?+77^"<,V=N$iGUce$Z^*REkIr`DIG+"O;fZ%@;hHT_>D20(Pa\'ND6(C93l(<(;.L=(G\')0i7,57fs3T!\'Lq0*,n\\G^#J=@)OJ2GZF0:WlDsZ$NX+5%H\\*n0O<o3KL&D"ug%7l@!]0X+q<l`(n0:DSitn1!5I#jq-?KV#RT5hX\\n2=4ea6#l&DQpPd#t*b)]+/_.+*q-7&Qgq\\^>L4K0gXn)BB&e3"@kFV\'9ea2;Q-:&NUs,gbi4L*Q&YsdJ_Wp-R0jBJ]Dj(c0cg\\#EIDEqfrIafXTK\'>O.Xqh^%_k\\fpNHK]KG81u353kO?Gh]QadY)Bf:KW8%6sG/Ia)mbMsA^@0aqI_C9*8tQ""Wo??UX&hPbes^q]2uHKYj6hj.S_tH:!3aB1h`9+XWec%\\C\\V>-nMb;!j3\'GtQ84d/U4upYE4J4>G+O;Vfalg%6`#J?@:a*Rao:+<#W?5A0\'er9b_[b)](>2ESQ@^?)Y3e9Z@W[Y@%@`7R$P!geM9K]X;a6:)tqAV0=ljO^Ec)XV9Z_N#KWL%qp230gWS3>K%E-g@=nVX3PU>6J?p".=p=oiQdc@b<,R9s"J[YL&@V]*i#W$_eLJ@8YOjioD:q7j&ghgn3U9ZH#8^tu+FCr1hC_tkm#$6_KYd_QWd1?8cU5N5Y=51a9!o-%NtT4`emN;-7)/-_jq8cWReGoTpNBLFohY7;lWPntZAVFNch%W1F/`^M4j30dkP)JIj#_Q+i]N^u5(&@H_^)<d$5($_,oD!,fCAP2.RFX"QSRsJ5,mQ4p%t0[#7m3\\\\k,j%l,%Zc_sPUu_$aq,]Ro-(6@mpI\'Nk4f>6BR)A\\;Y+BWIu>Z@pSg$s.q#!`?>:"[l+*?bplD(Cj]j(FTDePa0c[h?J?J_oBlB%#=8(TPGC<Z\\R"88jj!_0pCqe>:.tL>sAL:GK9"d4?SQ>?3B$sf279`?A;K==EUfW1p77?l\'TPmXIGCV%os%2qP*=;6M]*:*AcP9L3]<eYQ-FbM2deiZCe#eY]EX4QiA21JeCk,Vl9g[`H$R<\\5r0EN[k$]+m_8K#(;?Nr(j*R*)5>Zm!)6K.O)&FXtP3WLXZ\\8Z#K4r0"OBa_Pc#5_#,UZ3emN&oh,!&0Wtl87+;<R_67\'l@:pO\'0#,gM5ASq&$)hsqUOaW25ri7Aq@_UKhJeIB`X_/+=kFNaDD0\'UqX+<2`8a#pGF;p$8\\mdgl-"kpiU?(4X>AT_U&i*=J8OlS]Xq(H>P21;<VIe\\#EbLW?MQe_N6CP@QE[7"oX>CSYjcp:7=Ug#9jN.B9I`er^:Dc;T[;p"`_Aj>hEUZ#K@tSgb+b$5GsV1o^]!Y^Mn7fQGJ(iK+m<QkQs&/p\\<V2;RqZ]oFZ4dGn8juc?0\\!?Hm)o-!P9Qg0X>EleK"HLN#hWqrDlD7X5@&:;I>R(\'8#\\`H)`VE8>KD:1?5WNN[L,QHYDKKi>4Khp;\'\\,`\\4"a\\kt\\d!89R2VOme\\4,[]<0U9A#XEejmIIe<=3sMK>XGLkc<I+2;b\'SgTjT$j16pT$C.i9s-^#Q9&GNM[6!]cIr,lhX.19:ur>cdigjUUL;W0\\J;m$m]8J.Qe;p?egMoI1lcW=NdEO4YORd)S")Q+d)jW"8hSIj_2g^Nm<37m3*(rssg.bO,'))).split('\\r\\n'))
```

Searches for the input in a compressed string. Definitely could use some improvement.

Comment: If you're willing to switch to Python 3 the `base64` module has the functions `a85encode` and `a85decode` which should encode the compressed string a little shorter.

Comment: Ooh, will definitely take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the space after `input()` and you can get rid of `a` entirely by moving the compressed string into the `base64.a85decode(...)`

Comment: You are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>439</s> 418 bytes

```
“£ɦ^“PȮ’ḶḤ‘2¦×3‘FḃØ⁵ịØJ⁾“»jⱮVŒl;“þðxiṄḂÞẹṅŻÞÑɗðṁṙGm³L⁽ẉṇ/yƥɠỵỊ£nżsCµ®ỵ⁾ọȧƇẏƑtNgŻỊ⁺ẈɓỤɼʂrƓėɓẓøb6^ḍḃ"vṂỴ÷ƭVṖẇƥƑ¤æⱮẆẓ\6SNḌ|¢YỤṘ⁽r&AµwƓTṃṭṚHẇ¶(ȮçðṁÑLẉṃı-ÆẸbCṄ¢ɲʂ§ȦS³ịẆu⁽ạİ*ṁ©ß¬ḌZɗẒ¦ṫṃÑ+ṬẠ½ṠȷḂðȧç⁾xḥẹ)ẒɗJĿḍʋƲṚɠ_yỴ\9j6ḥḍƘḥÇ2Hƙṃ⁸Ụ°ṭ¹Ḍṭñ9Ẏ²ẈḍyẇƇ[ṃİḅ⁾µỌø§}UḳỤḷCs4ṗȤ7ȦĠƲżḤ,:ṡÑjb`AOẓḷỴƲY½;ẹ5£ẈṂQ:Ṁ¹ḋ4q+£Ø³ĖĊȷ#4&¶C⁾ÞẒƲṾı0"ɲFɠðƁḊḅ8yṪÐnŒN§i²ȧ2ẆƈUỌỤḟ¥$²Ɓj³ḥ-ƤṢṆƑġ⁽ṫƥG_BẈṇØ_¬ñẹ)¤rŀḍƑʂỴḞ`⁷¹ḤdƘbọzi³©E»Ḳ¤ḟ“ßGW€)Ɗ6ɱ8ʂṖṗ¥ṙ®×ɓƲ⁹»Ḳ¤;;€”s$$e@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVPrThNBFP7PUxAkRESiQUSwiRGJQAhBDYJBCRC0MW2QIHihRpNuEYpc1LYJLUahQC9BoGm3Qmd2AZMz28kub3H2ReqZxl9nZ/ac8132W793aipQqbjBn7DnZMaoPrRzbnAT2QmylBtMtEBGxG/QQzeyBZFwtWM0V0Wiz9XO1ZDpdwu54XJ0ykMncS7y8z7kn5GFxBYaHPli2RRbIuLERR65hnyz5xUU@13tDI0vyMPXAjLtJNGkpSuwN10@neuCY8jRBe1Hc93OyjAa32TkzcDLsklNrmagsezE0Ew5pxehWRmz4nQyYoJNto0hWyeWde@Qh9D8I0ryaBj5BhphmZYRSIkMkUVjidpH2wYHkK19hN0RWoWchJ3NNnTC8XsZe4x8AfkR8h@9NAonl@2cyFb5i0h/lfeCVWgWtIZNdpFa2HX0ixBk7cwgFMkdQnhbVbhj5a/QFOyLbTgktKdOHI0oZJAf0A4RaUJ@iEYSzpAn7ZIyLW9nRZakzyNLk3@N1O7E@6y/JOxiVepEyUmOB0jbaIe/TfWwdZmgKsItvXKTlroaIz1AZI@AEyRVUehA4yvo5Bu1B5Qb4WdKQx7ZImEBmb8mGGQ/DSErKjdYqWuuFXncTt2yM1ZS6uVTCsPV28h3RMQ/OdH5gBykLuIh9RE48xDVm7CnAHjoEbUFFfZq6@sm2BMJKFob1opdutTaACddBKiiEVVizq3C9TpH73aSIi81ZCtEqD2A/Lf4Pl2ODkDWB7qdbSE/5fIQkaxy24Z0PehS85PXLN0s6ePtIl@SEWtHmc4PZLpn/F6VS1gkxuFQFJSTkJotB5VdkQuVDWRbE65WUjxTL2RikrL2wQdF2L8PJjIdFJBK9HbPEzd02ChX2pxCO01Smngc0hRkyAlKntRdjf8f8Xio1Q3@mquv996tqB@itvlOLV14RLhG5TFM70cqlRmfd/a5t2bG66PyDw)

A monadic link taking a string as input and outputting `0` for incorrect and `1` for correct.

Takes advantage of the dictionary in Jelly, but has to add some additional non-dictionary words as remove a few that are in the dictionary.

Slow when used repeatedly because the dictionary is generated each time. Now generates the dictionary purely using Jelly (rather than calling Python code directly)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3384 bytes

```python
import re,zlib,base64
G,H=["".join(map(chr,zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(x)))).split()for x in[b'Gar?3CQa?!%"PP@eS)db*<_:.:\\C<.o7j7C6bYeu*^[Y=?7CpeN&,$aRJ0:HPcnf*]g<auqG$d6NX]:OM9:<gI?X".<gEtbcgB8TRe!nBg,QG?+FR.jgR`H-nMCOR(e>rR["sGCjjaHAkSMe#S]7`d73cUEKGOh0hl2pKYh+5uL\\N-U_#nCoV!Dn]i(Q,eK,+?HhOW>JC)p>Tijak_Zn+`5f=$0;nGHbL_f=\'$`a:$T7_OX<Shd8l!7b%tP0%Ca%EsK[K.D6*G9+4ok-($\'"@GfPTLm1qq/`Ng/`he.\\W#pb1=;,UbtsJ!mMu"_#,8u-#u9"8:V\\Qg+BRUsi\\I@q0M]HZPpiFCGJ\\8FW6X:[`_+F4d&@J>(lq.H\\=*5;,hgaR[k]T2]1Rp\\a-,#+!D(]`V6ngIXVEo[b1EAp/oa9W01K?jh[PutO\\,u7I(Lf<eUumH](R80*0g:F0SJgfbLoJ&),suqDE[@b9]9JK?C2Z%JR0O&\'b_\'a*O\'`T)R$D+YcR5#ajGD90U[SdCR9ZQE=$.(<.c9J5+dXM$m$7O%JL1tbd/&L#7o27Y$(YOfMf0AXVu#dP^2D4>nb/VI8O3Yk5(bO->Cn[lmE@8qBRa?Q_/fgN=GT)VcCR>K7*]gh^!b:\\&rB7,?"A4TbEKfNI4D$a3Q$4Uj;90/;t%J)prQ8.\'`JrngCEmQ#_Kc/EpPL3QC\'<)<M94XZ!jQ-Ba-7YZ5!i/mn#1PKno<nW*lQV=ej4=-#8deA%3T3b^#8itGakSRs9Zh\\oft&1CD_8!^sl]aZE@0l67;)</Z*:T!E1618bG(=\'--qUSQ9&=qU<qRoP=0o!9qXl)Zu95g#FPcp(`ObVg%fj&aD)(!W>_e;3X:NlKP=]$J]SaM2YQp_T6D3?>i]jSEW0\\n>u".42mgD$]bl/=YZ:Fc>:l$WA!cKq!H]B.m%\\JN6X_XF!A`JGDf$<*GF)W8IY,noam.PulpDVb0+g*Hc(F+CiWcM-tJEDb6AZr[3A4Mi!M03m*(eg\'R"MFi:nPN#!"ldT=B\'5[k)7h,]H^A"98l&QHYc!2PCUcodJ&F]\'c-EX]D4D^FQi^BDp^&e`!oBCWt4(#Md5)5.G!I+-;q1"CXPA1kSoG/O,.3)Cm(?MaGN:3b`Ir$#Fhb]9ocE+b&e\'SGUK875er=4`9$t$88IcGKKf@:T/"*fu#Y5e_H\'!@)f$H7k[\\D#(Bn-1D5""[UKP>=Pp2+t*f%p:H\'mu[<\'8Jss=&\\ruZ+A!B?8o2;)5>n(&Zk>gAShfpM%R8H%\'MdR15ij\\V\'pQ6hY;e,!\'^!EU]nLjp2279lb+!=&N+mAQr.Z*[51.mGC"H8Nd\'q/2p&36W5?%F3LA\\EG"G-uL2A_)W+"<LW$11\')W]`nF3j4RAp1[4\\<T-!@Y7O/%[0IqGWhGi;&\\md!P)eU_0@qG8YF[!<jk6R+92]\\!*NJiXOR\\3/1=O(SFFo4Lo8.?Y8mU.+^\\UuBD470#QK,2:O&@=TkaX@u?ThROp^b8oPYum?;&T?RIc^2##=h)G=T',b'Gar?3D3D9-%YhI0enDmc1C=o6T\'Bt]-f6WNro(SC+[AH2pk"[T&6X$/kR+0#Pp"$:<UpE8*$p5Qfd=]0r0dfJ($g\\-DoqHX"Dmq[<;qqFU@ngBcNda:nENe$3GbrY%W)2:T9=!BBIN+!"T]%-MA7_:,K=CuO+acF<*M:"ZRX6raW>liX.3aKVg7EY^"t8&`$]m?*_<=V?[(fJB>X0[XQ[:gm``qReR:<]Ngog&d^$?2L$afoV>6t#`I4Z[NP@q,Mg?&iT6!oT!,AK^Z=u)X#3J7i_+a:-,ZS6kpH2\'Kb[2gL\'jk70pQfK9ifD2P^$of:Ks52p-+W?q^_secPW0X`$HN2mF\\!rWld2OE45/#a7;7p%<Ut!u<^e]eH7"l:754g<@*"bj]Cm@>Od5bgGD#C^[GFL5LalMbmh16n3IYec$e\'`\'3>.01"[?[W[!.f^FjN56.R;-2V#T_1__\\*V)d<Eqg)a:Tep1Al=m0\\hEf_b\'@0HP=O*4D<>`hOgjq+/RH;6B3eUgV<_@F+MmC+jup-IB3qboF[<IZP2\'*bT4M-Bk7kE?_CC@##6S?\'Oe\'FPa[e_\\RsU_S*V>7Ni-P]*3P9:oRa,R$e*:2+XrOHsl7k;g#,;V/Tm[4kFJg#Bit21)0KW\'aL0H\\*5-+?B*d?q="@,/0Jp?u\'sm%Ep["rNEk*J\\D-7A:Pn(qTZ8YO/n8G:BJS_,c\\dFl!%L3+#Jq6>Pgj9Ef[.`=oGLddQ*<B!#%[kCZ6ft1O?I_o[\'!s:2W=qS2i3/mHKgpL@=Af"k08p\\UiG/04ESla]b5mPd]V=?_<<i.\'eP]B,a6B6g^!m3+-Mh$=F:9I=*]\\n^*N"3oNd$GV:,`&.j8h.8NK0mR[<5B>u[G)X_e.rplB3-3G,m)hfLG_[Z1ImZIr-cjI[(4jR2QpVn;6.YLPeaurGG77eTC\'Y9l1h9Mm8B9N?i3m);oe^F(N8j58&A\\HQY(OC?aHV:lhD?lGURWUg=j@&3X\'QlKp\\f=-ef*`B^Ss1R.FABA(]f!TZGpaEsc71Z*>415C_V-::HZO_K`Qn4.L!sLEF0f\'KC[h[Gb*:_FFhW"ES%IZ\'\\E-:rU<Rga0[5G4!nU:g6\\7<8XiQ!NZs)$[JjSnC5ooJd36t03XZ%;e-DiWI-_^j(TsoD1J\'=JP+7DCKNh6\\3q6BL?*bnJc=j58tH7Yq4=q+Sm^MRS12oYT&e+i]i@^P:Ag/`JW1kO]E+n3*na/(3nce,/.n[bcH21sWa4PA475XC0Y3RP9%Bd,O>^,-&lk4=XuLC/j3nGO1s>V[T)ZBRqVMm2)\'MG$QsTIN+7Soa,o*Id2sK9J65&PsLF=@##-D]);C-&&o"^VE0"E^<.U*K&J!L]t980_G&tpej$2_PLJ@DniaRN`P$JIE>"!C^g-s0a3.9\\ns&.!O$"AY7fQ?nl35I5BS"f:[QW!`iJ)Wj\\UaWs4Z"j?.I?X`//sE5-iYYDnn#<_0\\IXpm?Lf+*)mPq<B9b0;S""IZ3P0C(5#"$Dfh84Y:oa.p;bc5EUOFh#\\q71Dt=\\<qq]h)XF.9g1iVX2s<h*Za("A-g@ZZlNT#b/F\\.MQl9c']]
f=lambda s:s in G or(s not in H and re.search("seil|ie(?!ng|sm)|eing|eism",s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dL3LkuM8k6a5z6so@1dVZjOzmd2YVS/7CmY3K4YISczg6QNAKRR98T3wEwh/wd8sM@B45DgSBHHG/snPbf2///d7/u9//etfw9cU0p/yd56ySHP42sYpjEVct7gM9YcUplkN/pWFqMK0PlQS1TWHMKWF5COO6sVtGMMi0i2ktEWVt2UfVg6yysyPONxEfE7hRVFTsZqjCUsJsZXNEUVQhYpM4DjfpnG6S9j/HCWwWzilBq4t56BEFj/y9LIk5qPmGMmSxJKfh/xVy08xKEr2O8nq6n6fVhOnMJc4PAKHwkZikzL2UeLEWo9H1Kwwaf4UeZNcfMQgzqeo3qmQSJoof8hIJUnzV5jIeEycWfMUVvk75FCFsUrJJPZexU2dmF79jbTn8NBnXsT4UIkznwyy5SHuU6DMrmLBSyml/ARYyGw@Ds2l8rhNWks6RNpnfaoqxVM6fy7SOszbQ6W8SeEsIaUcVXxuL5UkZDEph0Winx6Sj2xSRq7TstnjXKe05bjtYlmn5qmvqyVh3eg9Y6m8nDVGeeJXUcR9yE@T/7GCxbJ58jOFRiox3INo7dNgAmftXoPYt/wMN/t1n0PRYIHzjs2oZlGIt2d5spJJcUp5u9kLGhUu2yF@xRxMYC9SCsuX@JI@yxI0f3OQEEosuFCzmc2cbqdUSsjHbOQwbjdNN@Xuk@OrUmHHqAVGBUIlr4IaZE2JrWSQteR7VA@PvH1N2yMO5lmT0CLv6uKn1Hqac69hmps69KX8S2rXr/JiUirFLMn7Gr6DKsw3eU@LtIgOmayzWkVSRK6QxYxqis53PPZ8U608LO8wPZ70Syz/zHks0SDDgopRvGGTQIr0HO6nRDBni2TOc5DKo5Hph7fG563xCYMANgWsFHQYUp6NZHkzTUokHfkU7FcRYyM2GiQG/ZlM9vpe4ruOVQinSNWQyeR0elCspr/C61/@KR7k13yXxFN2yN9RjLsa@psaL3n8n2qbwykaNWRevTj6s36dVDJBIjVrEGtJ5M2KVYhqlpLICWFzVIEdTuVlO4sw1ZrrNMxVYFQCn1b10ilrEf@aypc7qFGs83D7rmHPQ9qfUheUoPLvd8El3HmTxoMK0YRUhSxSqcxiylXDrPLze4ziyRHOAI/y6j//fG1f8lJpOOr5Zq@WVGxf21KKt0SASr0arLBykWSD7Zv6t30zJ4OsVDFENVnvoAo/mqBo1PzbtF4pQnyEbUrs15v/fqxcmlTU4jBJtKK8zCQkKeKRKstILkkqjKW3qb813nH4VfKr7kJQwgLrhLe@w5ELLv29DSmckv5EOclmVJNdF4ELkwqqS8U5ygug9UecHvrim0Rwe3NGi0ngWMNERq4V2/H1xfW/ChToMUp2HOODXLNB1oea87c4IJP1pQEhJiksuyiQyQqrBH/EUndYPV5sj1kf3SFl7TCbxihahOx7/XWkp/xEJv@UxGVSrFr2Y1b8sUJ6UJV653iWpjC9W2KMahKWYlw@d8MimVTEm9SJRaLmk5n807GsIi1DLK1r@Vlf6psWrWJuXMeJwN6LIL/t4vkqjZTbsJ@fMrLcqjjNs/kciw6VyOnPraIo/sjX5WZfFxHIlOxTk0FpK6vf@aY/ssBRzNZavJXv6yy/ilBKoIn8a0kcGRpP6o2MTzMVUOrFJFD6ONG0S1tE3hFq10fJJ5aksdTIonKocgyLfE@LmMvbnE3Wh6VSYc9Bag4VKHFFGqXpc4qiKQ2jIsXbkeV5Pu1LTtLMJIRvccwC@xhCNBQNac4/izVo879YLDef4X2a7IAqCf5LOfzkd5wNSt8pMZzVj0neOxPYl7XUfxr16fXi3HhuWxIH2743AjsoDRNrkd6exypJ0yRPLzOsSFIZlCxWiZlU1yqQryyZnoixEdMpk6jdkdvMrXwxSjFRiX7YspRQFRgdo6Jj1ECPRePBAqFtmDXnTSpOt5skkk3Wun1zrVKksZTBQKbGXgT@RYvkFu7UGuCYnjJpzFw8Nn04YorbWYuYCB8VGGgxLkLSLlDphYdRBepN6yteLJv25VmuLVSyHWuVtQfPUunDTKfWXl426baSZQ4/5y@zJHbZNVoL1WfUPlnIVtrwUzaTFVmyn2rzq1rp2VW58gqrF69Q/eBXf@N39cGK43H27Is13aRTcYotpi7j7bt0mQ2VzvCRvE0ictpLf1U0QnyV7me0gErVXLNpTfukXy2y5KF86oaqmad8NKpH6TVXWw7LvpX2RdCMUbu5pX776bTYjprS0pHiEQmxvUoH2xJucvNDbkROoLSgbvpd2eR1Z0MpGXG1t0Ilhlv9whTZPmNac2z2QqWl1halxLbvAvcyogmsrHUotc9KFSiFqMocv9PG8atWKQ7VWn@L4bXNBw11WPy07ceCIamMxRSQQ7Lfsv2Y7ddcHeTqhFtzpcVyz41AiSrP1JrFJK8qmP6vaoVBKhkRFC2GFkX8kCRw9XFKu1qT1tBxM6@26pXWGlGfjpgMDnVuCdh@9ZfDGjLxsGokHmE2aZHGoEkcSmlrPxWu1jKI2rRSgVBpNYpbERjJp5wanfctLkXigqCf72LYEM1Nm3w3a/IVIdqLcWir5ojmLicFWR7npxRBqrBHbcKNwzSruXI0VSgejzLURmYSUxqvozbURqo352Lw2IQYhZbeNEdQBfIoUNFTgzSkfa8m@Rhq630Mt@F@p5o0B2chLa5Vxbgf8ylxxSQ2NV/BzNGEaIKpaHDnl7dYdPiRJCMS5bDflcj7exOslk8VM0uqyGHeVbM8VXmCY@n9rkEryTE8j0UGdUm5mDcZl2SZ/ZnUh@n@kb8SQxqBGrl9PErjeAzmP9Wg1Eq7WRgzpV/EpY4OjWGVAFYJe@VyzyYbybzbaXTCUrxTQdzUs/1QlfglZinh4lw7/@NUWk76mR4naU4W86yOqFvBfYryp7QXq8m/zOFGn6lGZCx/qOix0aoVK/@a@c9QWg5kiveZUklGFt1MQxTrKYlDzlwyc/0x1x/pL1Xgh9QC4/RY9SmRlC1JD21c0EDO0wTOZDY5D2KJtGbjRBXrqGZU0zgrp7OPQxYbJS@yDvKYROW@imMjx1ZOp6X1hiwz5VhyX1i2W/kpculf6Fe72MKiQxtFfkrs0/YVdEDztHAqKL2tJK/1adPIVCu9BmYVzd06FySXImo5nv6hiQx9FNWiv0hxEEGDYPkYOYaphJTMqVnYaZqWaW5CzBPNBIglK@SWh7o2uXLTmWqB@P2VTPqVz9643Y6zyTpuoxQTbe2O0hoZuerQwqIjPWoSkGFNMdnLt2pKUPZFLsJjW6U/X2QdbS/S8XiagojkiX17x/rtJSkaioo43UolOuqr/c69XTWJU1NdExs3TZ4IrL@9k6K3tJ/GOkFVmrfyLh3LwsGySfbSBr@ZTuIv/6jf3FHrp4@8Lh8ZNR0/6yAzL2GQj6mYJbhgEzqhTucEHukSgzRk7IZKt4kF3rjjbdEI5f2ROi/cShOYv4tBhk6CfHaDPOigvaagnSbuDP/RvrH1jK3JyK9ctXz@nE3JKs1CubUZppE8ob@lSKwsUc1Ho8nrvbRP@P1ytiTWRC9mIyouHfEjNCLjZ5a/IaxVyE8R71tpMbOkYDI35eVTtEtOkqi/lSSUokKtlCJE@q1YxvG@kV/5SWma6fFZXs/09dH2pX4KJE/nIPmwfGnTpNZVKjCJ2zTKqxAW6klpNi9UFcQqWr@qfD7tkS97Fr92LmpiJjNJ4Zi1NrBpKPrsS5xWbQuEtTYLwloqJQmx5OAw7yrarznSFISKYvJgBRvFtk/7U3qy5Rv9w@Y/9eUJNu8WEvdzSgR1Ui7kT@2ghMOEFw0dVcc/t1AqPs2Zn1CnK0@Z@FQz72cvj2E4Lfo1qOKnivmURDWeqiKOjdyo0PtslkxzBeGnZJBlpbzvxZCX@V4aPJqWImpNWiT9jN@1oXsvDVxpGhVJK3WT4imdP6ukniwyw9bYWKBsGNWMZtoP1cxFkKHIuw1FFiHJd/4@1EHoImbRylLM7oGmGaPOpJXG8mOVvxQomewBCYmMNctf@ZV71SLQr7UevQfpSNz1vaIRdnsF7tTeoD/jtpgplP@WV57/BjOjmfozhyhdaDbeW/w@JVMXmVXWUf7SfIoJpaK7y9wEPRF6xGwILgL3CESMalJeTVKzimlAHfHfUt@pQc7vmuC7VFh3HT0spoyuqcAerfaATSK9GO7qIj2lkrlrM0lMdilNgrs1Ce7z8MXTXSoI@jZBnYvASMvIHOyncP70c45n3Wf5VaI2K5IBQBXYzUbtBjNJR4dAVaiElY@7vBsiCPpWYlHWTqkK5P5jpXWTRoaYpLzJ3PPdJsju2hK6bxt1YIsZpYSLyaoqJRPl2RfZ3p5NRlLUpKhsdchExWTCETmQhz6tZklRkRuTisNmo@d3mlpTBz8S/x@Jfizda3EVy4c0ajPwXtrvNMl913b8PWp@iEk@qhRPKZnIwvo7iRoLVIRF5B//sUE26bPqhJ4YM@dOFdfGyjE3saGcEJE5IBFbl0YNlAK4N6LgKIb8/Q1qsHW2sOcanDTkVBD02uxRxE0GK0wwlLS@byz8UzJtHYEpkr7BIjDiL2Q0gVBp3mmLwVpItTCYPapNYsuzd2YmM8kn1dMq/rAqXl4JUkiT5IEK9Ju09MVkHa0pDq0pHgMvnHkM88Df@wd9v7Rx8BikqzJWiVj9Ubx@2PTDYzhuXEGRJN2IBzX0IhnpOahRXJaa1dYgySiGZghbbIzqQWMI9NfaYo@w2SKaIuqIcmmz/nk8Bx0FNYmCfm4V1rHRxzRyP0dMBjx98Jhk@v8xxVkL@ikKJi3@sEczEwmaB3UOpki/Sn5VZ9sWISywziaZqnOabN4ruSuztiOL6kMNRYb6SpVV2pV/HpsspXrIvP5jk9ew9NRKJ9BJ9KO0Wov5UEdbqksOePoxikHhxEEaWCYkkmQaXwXR0jL8kKFZMxlo3GPNoWjLYUxitaxtyyK@qqlEe08qsB8hjIrCWJGOr7PIsQjrYGqrTtI/eNjwIbP5vHiQFr@dkkIlHEsZ@lDTfleTnwIJNPFhQqnKiqgPu1Q@8gxEECTtLxUE/f6aGksMt5u@dNG@ZUWi1Xmkx4POZpLOIZ98FVhZlwaoQKi02AdeqUoRP/jDEk3g3@Vb@TjkO/3QTvDDxp0fR5aH8ZFX5knvwjoORZC1lU9bXEmCVKVPXcX1tFVcJJSWmcy@thbyj6pBNcgqDQcx2WlUv6L5FXVW@qnz8U9tBD@tEfwcJBFispt807bUsw5dPM@RiyLOimb14SNl6ymv91NnHJ66/Otpy79I0ESXOk6@DybJz9IAMIHRS7Ve@sur/mCNnEYmDRmMeYbpXg3Cqsqf@rUKlCMq0kM32RywuVLxLSb7FumjrGYQiequKgjivxxNHjgu2Um9bTGGe@aIRZn/edKw6Ua1Ow0qU57QusoqlCr8FEsvrLXMpz77pLLSrE5LVfbZn43oOI34njaSpalQ5@@fk9RWpZVBr5QYZE3azXvqCqynLCp5bjNl2RpIYp@2WX5W/7TB@SwfLP190R@0R1eEMz@22nd@blG/BCYRS@JF4v4FfczCrLGiwUSpJJ9btqCyLq14lmeqXYfnofE/lkGbj82MwSkSLo3QMFqxa238o6z7VYFSpA1zNelxaQv9qcNoYpqdnchIyvPzoFXTatITU0GeulhI3yRysm80R0fOJ/4W63TANEpjoMSkirER0ymbmFW0vC9ZsN1MSJ/1FmXMrRSScwKdxm4f1lyZlq9QxwQmWjWQqmxLA1jcmjmeiRcI8PiEifmUZlbgFtmk6wPUnI2Qnzs1BL7OoPdIC/JvQwO2r8EpbHvUtdKnjb08dLShvLWng7XZilAsI40CmYWXvdNiA@qkmv6NutTSCCiWaZdkrbgegsi5WqG1fcT20Iaz2JpVAWyv0/LONnqr16X3tbFnZ@FQx7DoBIzKGv45BVPkQ5fHlx5LO5LaWD@NJbcyB9IMo7GlinUMS@Ro6WsHr6a1GVYplokm46qFPktkricqHc54ysZLK8iCMpHwWReJWls3FdtZZZQQzoj/PTQEfsnZoPewjj9OazrdpXA7i1na5lfNPlrccRaOdLS5WW3ZWTg/6QNmD83kZHI2OdKaHsuKYi0f1vcpqWORQys36py4Kjc/SMFSC/NpsXeERvFNflHlaaY4IpGLvwhjleIpmdPZnKz6LSry1L78uiphinFoO5fFHh5HnXgia462TLu1ldzUlYiTLUSkUY2gq2ZkMVrpNrPtr2wmiCYU5b@D9CjFJECdO1kZ@jfIbP9fXdT9N0QuLmKyrkyB/d2E6zIuMen3Y6xrwP8eUuWLyT9K6/avNW7/chdaDXKg7pJ@GkxKf76H8gUfSydy20NrKV@h2i795k5iMcKr/NGhDRVKYN/rJq14FQjRgnAaMZj/zMPXFm19k/YbZ1kAO@uqiXlQo/hYxW9R1NdJupVq0O9WG86DDRbNw@sM5ldcy3OYw8BfQTEFfCtQ74MMTtI37WaClh@a@LChiZI9@@/0IDPR2JaaowmlDKn0Ls1akvOylZw@pVTF1ykRXB/SRjaJY7VKDTBrjT3XynoOPFvBRnE9nXXHPH2FaJIWXeqzc/GjPxQG7e6SjVmz/n7wn5KrAwdocm5E0iutH20RNTL98C2NLhUo8pN6vfLoXxH@OWQtR4mozKwUoW54mmmwUKWX@fWqfr1k9KWuvJi5HTqqyXZbGDFv9fM/b9I/EJM82h7n8qlZG6dzab9KgCKwXnmWYSJTVW1DjL7QpGLRFCFVgX57609vAx9d7TwfsvpTTPqp9DNlq9BcWp9Wzki08Z9Z3@7Z3u75WLWUap90tj7pfPzIq77Q@sk4FNPWVJgUq0RaD2rmi0HWv7qHrki2I2oZvoM@8mXQ15NGcR@rTrmUr6IkcqHu9Cx9vkYmDWkaL7oavJgyuK4Cu6VVyua2yqRbqmfr9Cyl8zmL8Cvu5QVfArXF1EhkrmJd1cq5JKaoZ043ffpfpZ9lwsQ/Vpmc0koxMamLVXoxvC1Qg5llBGkJi9Q7peE7SGnnVQhaCheeQhmiyWpGiZMOWS5BhofEZFBejtFejyVIEkpNPNfHMY3S5jFBFOr80EJv@TJpp14F8nni912MpOYPmd@iqNsrFmq6aQCr7fsq4qQtQCqiVkh0udtiq92WKdmmABIDDaWKYpJviglUvGJqrfSZVyuPJTVyqfjIdq4xW3hxjXZJFll4zi4s3kXR6u5lShpHfVmWrVaay3bTXXnLNtbnZquwVYhVqL@RwN2H0nG1BgbPaau7eTattZbhbeXyrbIa265lqoi6H7KKuRGpDFYLq5fSckQWch0xLrb8VP9031UpoWe64l7r3WLJzQ/ZYq6l0cZZy2dqFqADyMt2zKMQFgTxNsvF1sQWIT/1na4i4Rdr8adrOWQlh5hRTePk6yGTWMsxW8W90EzzuUzFrOyLirERGw0SZZ0Lm5LW0kMt/bSaCYe0zMTkCCQFqYKsQAvSwev0RhOKJ5/6iD/W5jKJ2PndW3V8eJVhvT@rjtCtNkK3usbseg7NrTJKVgwxKW91oFxkdRFu3/RUVh0oXm2ceOXmOP@ljWun9CxlxtvSaaW3s1p02uq0f05ZcVCv1B2vOFlLid1sQf1pyVyky8OQ3vnKBWeVMrNK7WUmgTW0Qi5J2XQdyspb8KKalNRtrQv3Gpk01zoCsm7qyNzoMrJ10weoApNNRg1W@uSL6@NGDQYxbsXURc7rYbWBScTWVUrHWvLJpCzL@UxgxEXhXABYV/@ZUDK8iFMa5NfJlqFsX3/DTaO9fdGpBRIbkq3/WeRm58F2ux22EJFldipCrEL9rQijpnCbdI@LCYzY1SR1xUYVxJ9tKV8OfehVLj/ue6l2bJRoi@XTNYv0EEO0ZBEjddlUnKtAlaXJ5oCWXDWrIqt4/k7LtRrZfqjKtF6slFmxiMQfZJ4b3OwDVKo1WdNcBM2FQ2pKNfkXG906Rcb8Ha@C@Pa2l8XkovnSh/rirDFTwLlSk3dtyHSGbOCoC4ucVZxx/98EQdqq2H7LO1EnomkHIPuhQjQhFWFO8suco/zCQnng@yAzt2qS7prEzapfN5PyKZXXhmTTiyLsNWaNTD9EXhSkLymtZA1UKOqS1iLIZLMKTKICc5Np8XHjQs1UTVXUcYG97lCkAxmsCq/DmPaYzyHM@rRJ0J29e9ui3WXh0Z89DBqECBREKHGrS6D20oKcTVrF3NSMdRxR5VMYq1QVqYCQqEOTNLi26xTQrqMSu41KFOHcqFUs6fwSiU0LR5WJ2zS1Scyy@KvjAzvNVUkfZn9O85b07Iadlrfr5qFTjq3cKqncfPX356e0@B66XpQa@eX/11DeS2mH8F@1UHfhj7ZJ2HiXBqRKtIqKJM6sSVxE/iOeRPWFV0SpmVRQU52yQEVhUg3@k4c/Mrhd/v5udc39Pj207E2zzo2bRIwHdcQgqw5L75OMHIhJuTtlcale/bArrrjK0xxSfbnmUD4ew/pHGk/aWJJ20m4d1b32VPezjUut1ZsKWgq3OdOCz0kUTeYfPvbOm5gbkVJdLaS@7GGaiqneSrNo3xKNTK0kqL0Z@tu3/KUDbEXUkSGWaDFj1dEm2b7pO6dzBac3fvKgWCd@YaOuaNxp9bYdKVMsZ9ejWGp/eKdTNGpPfqdllKK@8HZ@E8YqVaVToAU/Ra4f4p3mD23XSLHo6xTr@xQD1@hqigsdtK1SMpFLpojEZDCRzO@5ldhfCV2Crag0blM6pfojtxxFpBLPAv@2WGbwlMiZwdMWT0FZO19TbLfZlkruVI8/VLrbmDrJ5zTEafuccm5EjtdGHSQLetvrSDlbZPtIFYU@w@0Ukyk8ZVbXZpFog0w7v2TyFhuRVtc62/xp7K0jLQVijZLjNl1VJF7TrSb/JC94PHTmRKWS@PS5nR@rQ77Mh6xY2XV1A01@SaUtQjRBfsoqyIhBEaS06aEI@@fB1e3ZFjEpntL5s0pZJZuurGJsxEbDRHMnH3MViAQFweyyNMhO9qrnejWnep1nesm@Fv6rKrRyQM2TmIe8bECEqGZS51WlPFg2uY/EkhoHm/KpVYEdb9J8MCH9iTIwGGXUXKr7/IdWIG11mZqtQqqLkKJuLIx6rha1k@4CFsnHOOziQr5JcYhBFfRJxyHt1tmui5RUiH/qYiU/zxJ1LXUM9Xw2Es91fWLTlznyOpFRzaimcUpGqB4HO5SKtspwyYtBT@6ItPdwz2aeJIkgzaKomxijbWKMtonRhHRK9NZF29sY697GImmLqUr88zkY1Vj4F2nGkKCD1rH2yUyKVaJf261hxUYHzEitFulwFmna06NaTeVhQ3FuhiuWDuiT/tbdj5F3O8pa36ir2aOtZo@ymr0YC513Ek5pPMVFEq62U1s9oO38S@1WNUD9UFvVpoGmKmuQJLA2e7Dehsi7Vht5bCzq3Gzb6m0cw3UMnMOTpne9h1tVvW/UlKvSeIqW1tOWTuspWgyqyW2NdEZGQXCWsbWZU/G0dA9yFVQxlT7NfEotrY6zZVPKQ@MunwnRfUcmVpdH5IGDyFsYHvGMOo2/l8ZFK3c/akhqMz9z@Ugf5qfIY2tJjcW7Of2vVlF@WTJetUCxaM5ZVrcqnw5NSrkK1YvS@HwMjdOUa469pgfNWgZnYXcpHcHMCpIKGqUczK1I4ymmKra6EodzfpaakGcrKIbZYLj/sUPaosw6Rd2oGm2XarSjxGLdkkqSHRtYWpj66SxSGBuBftP1303Ts4jnOEpjSY1Fom91tPTE1EwqsHludi6WqNHeo8WbPo6LmaQTtyNrrcfruKWwikjPKZU@smVY2mksvMmzLDzH00x/2rl/k@dTqgr11@pWvhbZ1r6aWCWJ5rFafF6BlkixMGvQXLWbyUC@ZWRojLT1XhvvZ9v9bLpbyx3PoojBxpHic9iTDHrEJ1eo09dmQ5OxtKF18kJEyS/dIlB3CMTy7dSI08qHOPwpLfMvjbkeYRPtCJu4bd/2k5wAEnWxd7S13nHTwWk9NCLqOGt5xrSr@8/5rHULbrQtuLFOnsZD2kO6MSDahoCoDVE7HKKeDZGGuzTFE53DwOXSJP6VDxwZTSA1LWUisMqsGrMqZPFlthBW@6hXMYl4mJ@y5jfZmt807Oq37ZQ@t0mn4biJ8iGNvXSTNmAxZYpNBfkp6hRIuslmYjH1N42VDrnWU2ua/QKnyN2QOgr/pxmPTzduJ4q5SyDR1iCTqGNjVVQsZ9aZJDCEqiuiYN32RJLOn6TbYdsskh3DkewcjqSbqRN1wHX7c6LDJnKVrcuSdNIj2aSHDpCKwb8vsyosWij4QI/yt3yd2Vgoo8ikUxKXU9yfKlPPilbrnjbxplrSafuoyAePtTLr/Ab5O4oRxZCfJNrTLy07UZN@qAMNKbTVX5I@7avadIhSpcyCujNDcpmHhHMmVf6Y8m8iZUrxj2TXj2bWT@3KpafutFOBfn5K415MAbp8v0jf@tO3gdX82WVlhUn8a5i@5e9TjSQmG1ow@CRY@jubUe2cfU@ZnmBTnv9T3ck6kSKsp8nBbqOmYBstCbL0uZhv/eVtP7xlkLFK5HWJ2bcaHBkWYhVMRbwkiclhVW2qYzFy3if/JRzWdSAjRjZoq2XSrZaJP2BJvl5JvlJJP1GJh8/1LaBFHPpBTvXwDZNilehXWRuQbG1A0pXjyVaOu8MdZLLh1lrU6zp81sxHFJGPruJ1ltQm1sitTZ8mTbLwK00/@TSpQH7T96381SLwHaw@Uoni9s2BSwq@uVEiK7HLX/mSqEC6c5C1JSoICruisBuiqRsxkpqG6X2nEUB2oZtfku37THW7Z5r1q6UCoSVotorASBYEisngkNMOVCC0Ws286sI2Ffi37a2zciTKj1ZiNxkIEJPBlwwvJVoATtMpInBesUQ/0btSDJmWT7YfJ22yHkBNynCR@GGKSN8YkZIJTOpa4yLbkexVJFoXmqRtkzd1k/UzYnLwUaIVVe8VpL9bpQZyMqia@5N2OXZJzaJDTcpape0y7KftzFtDJY4qxVM6f2ZJPz97/f7sMtoq5wbwEVv091vZtymtcgxIlUhrk1NvVGC9ba3vza6LMFXgn3XMoAhULKVkVVk0JvM02mE6dN6LFkyVBFrRUolglmmsWCWF0Vg0lK0ezzruo0I0QX/TjUJVVLwY1LcpTzeLAudgtmTkKcouXTqgXOKb9RgYFdiRHAsspgCpPTKdHyG/RAuKem0P@bWOhVVR6NsGy1K2g9dMEi/O0/bIsqvCpG9dPjRLDs2RQ18RFtjUFlK2jeFFmmtcjj1UydrzRY7mW7T8/Sz0irBRtI8v@dhzu6BaMsuTrRZXi0r2PhxfedZqoVmo3ixTd4vUS7@4Wdye9BjfZMf4Jj3GNx3LYoGuchhOssW9SZv8yZr8qSQ63ufD/NQRQhViFepvIpw9UFqkq25lQ3s6bJ96ssPgisDduEGyKN3C3mzhSO9BFmaqQA7eQ9QSrBJDXYCogqDA1dW7fu7Og/GLaOf9k/iUmbA8SHkWs/iRh0kXWxZpD1MxKEPVIAeSrVm7LqWm0IHDXJpVOnCYdSzAXtr6zmZdh5RtHVKm4@91EiHT0PMoBtvsgJ5cWvXrOYPG1npCmtjMCz26RzdgZt6oSsE051TKamSVbPaL9jJMjTca76A7HFngt8EkZfrYM03qmPeaxGBJDDb@YpIq6Tq9zPsCs@z50zlNnc@sc5k2j1nMM@HPureKxKgC96tEojZM5nWRWa44yTqCLmb5Sma9vSTb5SUipGcVeJrhPFm9OVSdRHkeImRytMVV1FhgrajNYJMEboPBTUtvnri@YiOKkdSgHwP9/6Lq708WPdbiNoEML0lkpkUPlKHaexYlFtiXVYFZzW5gz9IOz5tMHORNDaXTrK9TPqcoivigSSE@OlltEsVNTzBQgULY6k0ZVnS246ZKx82UZPBCzaIjB9eayeAhg2tF@ltPqSuWNekcRCPrD1Inm5hPqVSmVVZd6otqUSXrPtjxlcX60uXc9C1KRzTRmIxLqECpidPXoZ1oPtBWfrZvrYyk8eo0vk9AVv1kU7fMouGimuF2KUfWIZk/Wddf5rd2LlWgMvnZ9e0TIZFQn8HHdtIfUlYOLSm0Fv68RIhs9b6gY/XXM5x29@N8/sI@1KWCR7NS0GQqXEW2qw6KKBNRx9oeBV5s57xQ@YbZvBOJsb21qAHisyx/q0ISSVdAHet5RuKx6mEAKnBW2PlIRdJpniKdx5E0FlFvDx@pVsoO221uEqufG7lPWX7QIZoqiR@2nfVYm12px9qaUU0KftKsaw77O9ZzTPxYz80lRdblKSYxPHc7kGxxquu4j7WOah9rXR9WxLpY6ljPOWyWz1jLBPGxxvNZxrPMnGN5x9oMsBWLfN9M4IypQxNFPDvHxVI7FsdqjSJaSj1KQq2GlVXW/Fd@54zKmlpqsKhR7RKDF1/QRWa0UN5hiCbpWTlFpNhRPN@bZeHHhlCOXVY5HqW16EvPCYrTuhv7Ndz0E/4a7Myzly3deEngbDx4fkFXOr5sNZ8IJ/oUM1ElynXIK8jFEJxkTbAlVxLL5yW@ZAJQzkx8hdkuD6r5oEKsQv1NBNNeVUePMHuVBq6lZLKKnZa289asl4zQvERTfnn/qUP9OtCvw/w2yE/mneYtYyMK5kSJKWDf6PixKgmkv1qe3OZIstg8wWuyFXqvUlWrwGMer@12njD@OuaHDb@86FTgeLbh39oYfXNbUxuerYVUbF/TW8ekixl1jO8tJz289YCHd61Y3me1YmXzrQdlvvXA47edl/nW3vXbOtdF4LGyP7Kwlv9@xWl8hD82M1KX1@raWq1Ya@l/B9svY1KyX@m0JpXMfeaHISKfBHWKVbkeC6XWiU@EaC3tT6fXRtkfdhBH@RvUplGLo4QVRwsmjhsbZJlnueKIpFp1kSVr5tJSPcuF0iyij89bW6RvOQ5iJEEGzLhqkL/BzCgmByIDTW9Z/v3W5d/vSRoaYgqQtoMKjBSYVQYz3nYszHvT22JUYKR7ZFUo4W7S5RWTVeK3NDGrxFqS9M0@VW8dTFLTVNjUYilCJcVvrhLlb1CTsuAjWfCRZk5R4wVWaqQ/v4O0X383us1OjfSvf/3r/0rlO5C5Mv3P//qT//t//fw/NCH5n5//um/xP37@j89/TOv/9yta//mv//g//8d//It/@S2cr3Is3Q6i/3OYU/jDLx5Z/994BL3hERXkVW6U@PLHMI2tll0I2ajZxZDgX3NfZKNMl0KC1Xkm90gCKPkIxHup90siKyEvbYxKo2hGexg7EpFo8C1yKZVLLSH59abLM1Z846VXs0swGyW5DBPU6g2ZrSI3cv3zqTD10D21827NltHBFuhWD7to1J66jKpVI9aDsSPUyL2EqaOxJ71SR/zDqm3/NvrURkP7iMAiiiwhjB3oVBC48sx3jsJT1DHvRukfuvDs5nJY0XjB1ktNn/MCIbt0/aMLWFZJ9mi90nOZVm9FbRjPQUIZs3nJVu3oq5TzOlWvGHs1/6qUSuxoFMiawP7T2qdwNI5piau3/jRWucLTx@C8zRUUMUXnVa@nYikLc/tM5QpY765eC9s4o@/MaeVBRLAmZ2/rSxqM9iHo8HSj8oj4RhuaPx7C@3ReRNuw0hhuCx7bkweu8n5sUKnJlbaNjzK34QAEMhUSwZ6yA5j5SpJHPqvtCt2WTG21IG2Y085X67bW0khuAqATtMBa@kI9GXuUOuTfb2Ub@t/51TtzXj@oMenA5Ko9WivjbZoCB8aOJCTuidZbhT1Cfzo3ra9867AvSfUmYqfmKmSygxPezoIIPHFVODdJGyvdaBwmV1FXlhBSSxXccuP1ZAs1651vTLIDk6@05QJlZ6eLlH3CztuVG8XQVUl28XKjRBcwg5Leydwo0WiHz2xF8QKlnnXIZbotL@hJ6lBD@CJo77fdDd0q5W1BJRmJaJRu8BAEuCpTUPKE5gunnoHnz@2FWnJHdavkH7LdWY2kdfKAmpKBqyrluDvnxFdyeu01xK7ehd0qyp3YqFlvym5U7cZs0G0u0m6Vu6Jsd2w3SnTXNijp9duNkmztBLW637NVnLjH5PX03m6ntsvl1V5PJ/mc4j9d8@a88RsUu9TW68AbxZ/QqRFyxVGvDm9d0VDbacd6aw8QR7n9pHEwYSr0FvJWxVVxe5/je5ffdmE56tVrzBvVHap0BhFBAlBSimQKzldX3cgUM9ibWOid6T6c8yL1RtEuVAfV5p71Rhk9BL/oHnbUkKvZG6Xsc4OubAc3OaATl1a51N27qRe9N2oyrw16dbL7VKQbN12U5PTORuHpG7Ey04r26dYTWtyKtA35CY1PGeHpgHgNyPx2uE2rXFbv018vsG8iwdsJXZFVlBC5ImgzbCc5RmwZKEkOQdtAQesPDam0TlZIBU89OH0fj1IanHuyJw@ce17h19hpahpzTiEobnaFOSpvzd3mzkH/rh0Xb1phe@rUdojnD99UAmoCneJrmOarobiTe/XO0xf4@AWjfl9@2O@rdMXcKyWgLdlfvBw3Oifuu/5FxzNBIN8BYkHHwoIOIVBaIC4EfFzmxcdlXiAuazdIoMwHtfpRTAERgQ97daOcYo9g93H5jseebxgboRCfPCwyxI5wCgrNffwaYpdEgd7P@NW@XGRv3qVi7Z5IxAcSI2QKA@8m@kyQ4fEGJD4m7966UZSQTeEODmkXU4Ny7kpazljUcp4DdNobmDrquu4Na/18Y@l4d6XjDaXhDaUhDOAHA@eHLHd0TtCP1T1SPr2u/TnlufNT73No1TJ0sAwlRK7AK0ktOTK6OnKn0ocmLF6xdAF7BhETFC9Q6lmLAkaDgM/AAD7z/aJtdt55H2nrREi4YG4UxWDyiGbInfcEQo/aUQ1jbdqmR1s2pr9ev7M5p7x8p42WEBdTn3FTPNpMmX1BnaEEQJXQ1Qdhhqc@n5d497ideKis0@uUwtiR2JMuGqEj8FTne8TY330lRTWbt43eegcruAVrmzOOzqFHqIUqGJWXK/0zzGcoQeBL19w9TUjDyme@D5hthr1yRLUICsmKvikwGJHAU@NtM60vZB8BuHRNpSNz0ahsuIuX@W9a4a@PgR@b/oLx7y9dU9f6d76TRqKzHG1FRrvAIJ4rZO11aq6Sgo1eJl4ljq4KYHvyoH0J2Nq4n4fbd/@sjYJqKpFeUJOhV5zy7zdt72j1mJVn06htMMmtJHYk9SQDcq@2gIggdSB7Iit1@xgY70Kti3yv/EH/32PE5L55cX2jdISLh3GE/lnQHOKztZefn40j2iHsfJHjmU8XmPeYz5ClkH8wRFTs2J/ZsP/ih5C@tqW0YuFpC3PZSa1np7JiOCvoQ6irb8uxHTxwrbttRR82zMkNcnL79kGQ3Tv4diHw/rHGTt1xl0bun2dPfCrlMNgG0KpX7wkT78vBFzh6V50/I9ZfwnyUcQjia4NBBzp49BG2KfmsUeiy4@1V3u7HT9fsM5SA@fackSZGdC6PzyM9sadVWeE1iNLfbFUSNJ/5UpboVUgneJ1EnaoOtYnVi8kceXdRfmMB1h3e3pV/rHH4RW9@u1T8gie/kKoQ0BMmPi4FeW8YuLj4NilZbyVPL1AC5toWDCICiEzph7iPvRL02DViI7SRsS9OhzvAG8LIlxLXtiSbpdETcNLWuGyPYHcZOYW7aygpAD/blmj0bVwYRIjTA3vPhhIy/5CVtH5tb1/xCkhAXPFne@vHoV5U6@SKyZH7USiFzp/j68uPaCtxheWQZY3elS@5xwiVg5yM3So8XJrZ7h082hTLtuHG/kD9ByjM35AQAj4dvKfPOYFUwBy7gOSB@/Yf0I846GBIFwsCPha8H885gVisUBpkO2GjEMNwdIPDJ0Zln6SIrh7zcMnAG59u/BVLUewKUYQyFLEIdZOognxACVID7YMDOgUHNhcOOo8hIkAVH9P0hJgmnxcJ1CHG6DhjBDK4/3QtTmHeXxp3vGPxFNgq3obRdYPEPiJIHjSvolhHsLcBQPv2Nvjm7W2YhwUqI2Xen/kG43SCfOB064lLzgxrZ5i4@M9@JU0Bx7Kim4K80jLQ9jgITKHzHnu1twF6tTdsOt2g5VTsmxsOE@DyUIB34/vrQvyTEOKDpmUNY0dQx@f66lc93Ib9YpKoUlS9XSjeOjXaw4w5KdAr0hYPavq5B8OQDnJoFcEz9CdCPsBkw62bbBACwGeUn4244WyEgNYO9ZGC5In3k@3Oj2OYMYeZ@aDoFlUfFhNfYuRkEu8KXufcrVdT5oOjzVQ@OCFtk9JYAuSjIKBprRlywekSRbPqcr/qaVcGYX3vjRb1j0@0g0L7koq9VZjDF86MGfRB8XFKoMfMq620KMEFSQSWujQwddStYGkYhAI1SUEHRo@Qj10MC8zgKQM13nGKerYN1Sli/a8oIXLvnJLGp@cAXX4lrqQ/B9/lV9CWdLrrGFZ8nCx1EH0T5OMFq0wEQeTj7cjw4THYfnie3SysIPRtRp9m50sI35BCJj6vCvKpY@DyKoTY@RN7fyL6E9Gftg/MVldhPH0flO1Uli6QV8Oq@wkDhwXQfTgwcWvUzdEW2FVujCBtb1R5d/nxRieQG21nmW1tLfh0fVa2WlZ44pRmjPkEvRwjGZCP6uS7PgZc5OlyGyzJCl0ZnF4v/@ITcS/5k@6999HetuRjtO07quw7pkOOuPKuINpxW7uVfpX6NB8rvjx8m2XjP@3VGpvhZwUJiKt@9eS3lsCLDm/59IKfX/Bz31YT5tSopQUVsKKEyD0bJc4nGLhV4h6F3JMZvSv/KOR8AoySsHjF0gXsGcReULxAqWct8suoxR7aqWBBLgK4SP@Ga/Rvs1sbLdbQzKMKaR3wVWsuP4QkQD6RApw/x4j@HCM@te0YwZ9jhKd2LPj0mXh/CvL@MGj92YYZa2NDCZivno00aaO781yUGLgYyVlczgnE5/ad/NSkIPf0qOu@htZO20FaJ7i1TkkC4gqp3uTXAmwFFuIbexvfaQ1l9ISpo77cnawNdvatiQ0/JgIgNTO2l4R8kIBK@4nY4PMjdp8lMzS3BHwAOAVsv@pNMU4l4ZYKg15xCdDJ3@TA6laFj5/H3FGKqhvu3zXYKfYrDk@Mysd6oXqsnSJu2O235raXxfeq5xFkzgHdSXHrtEOGnX0EZ3hJln3uHPK1T9e0886/T8sORWGRw5CGuCClHV5KLQzuXjwCovbtYbsLkkkC0C2cqbit8Svr9DqlLshX6MJ0XcqNu0GPACT7xPGVIx1KSPoVUpXP4Qr2mr1aH7BbAaXIN6G2lY/n73r9J/ePnw@3Wn2FaixdQj5zyo0x6G952o70bzCk9/yBjsWAn/zi9xOlK9bExv1UI9NTX5hOblGpv@gNjJiRzc2MTr18VfuX3DAq8wVhna5dG@ZUsxz70innehyMV5/ycRUP5ajOp/v22oJBWc//WwO8uMZtZ1L1xg4MRO@bgwSdP3IUZ6ddT@gE5aMv5UJRNcr9i6grGJRfpdnSvREG0wXNVwwK/Etuiw8QUF@uBeYL5IotrCe5wQKSG451b9BDZHsC4O3@u@E7j3LZn7e31rh2DVhFCRg0YJU4v7Z@fFwhBLqtF3o4J4Hd6Q0b6NC73rBxLmfFQzh6nLwPKF82RBXDU@b14z5euKKcEcQNVpjfNhxA22DwrFumI4RPWQUtZq4QnNQ9/Ir997XiXhc@sxX6L96JY7rk8OmrvNdur@O4Sj5c1@Ej3IELL9AVjAkK8I78iKDYvR@58yT3vuSAFRszjE/G0DIGl/tI54to5y7iuYv6L3jkFgDd4nCHlAlxhZ1Q58oX9vLF6ZZGGnTJp9MpO60VVH4xSr9djDAZvxCfMEBnW4j3Rc6g9q46f5bOn6X3Z0F/FvTHfQMi@ulzxNX3/hFDbk4JviZCfPSmtIMfCcYb49Zl19Zn14bZtXXZhZ1Z2E1V7AnDgQV7twi1vtidHwcmejsghVjsBfhgftEJBHN0awEY@YdzdF3keGAHufyZO6Uwo9IC66AM@YdwLH4llBH3GI4V51kVgV8rzLQq8X4lrCGO1NUQsILkZjcLneQYR0ieEOcPIeePAOePn408YNqQFqXdt7g0GqUEGjEl/2HGecbDfaZhyrFYuwMcDIIipjd2yY2Q2oiJxQUCR@ziGrtmujCIjK9UjoipyglDygm9zQk8yf7b9qGC0Y48fqgUtEOPI670GWEpzzhMMyhMMyisvkAqaXN2lJnd6F25vB0HGCMc5UCiViGhQvIKsFZvhLNtRlx0M8Kim5H6b7P7Xc/i05/91nCxJw@aoirWxvswwDunxGUVIZdVAtqsCoN7YcSePGjjEXzLbQywrFhB28RU5JqRxNrJR7W3ORy6dbZjuA33@3k4VAdHoOcpTBbqSV0E3eiaWO/H3BM3eCEU7K@A9hFBRIBeQJpdM17sGjlAfpRHMIJX6MDYkdiRzht4mldzaWO4mBAb6ZayACmM6A4PMhPkIxHRW18uw35Hbwl5RxjhO7xSdwhUOpq3a/rpWQY0QeVd4adD2REfa/9O38FHurclYxQZesVHoAONMTFKverzWOTMRpc7Sn1sXGXic7fextuqQ9omSM10/3ibLzrTc4g@DAIuQeWjc6PxyyvmFcEWZrSHK6@SOxt1dCe0jG6Z5ejXWI5a6VSHdHu6B/7dpBEBsGeITKb9pOsFSsB8Jmd4nSe6Y7zzJ/f@gLV9VnN52Fi4mPmw5@kVYqf2CvA6L/15JQa94gqFboVCu/rOAgNv9wVy9cV7dT0Jtjtr6l69NWF273KVC@jt9YKXVlVu60HVeodPq3pgyPsBAccv0IhfXoFukQKVJBeQnEq4jXmEDczjBGvhCnhuOMtpEFz6xsl0uxhLqtQ7Da08thao5Ces1amVcYMzIgl@wOrfkSlY1WPh1JrHQFNbAHJq3tI2Etl65Y3VOdW@uJj53PdLtEdtTphTq3Sq3WdexrzK7etA1uyjdtZAniSP2lqc7LlzlDtH3uYeD431HjNGVqnPYrofA0qEXpnhlXJX7gR2vuULNa@0@kOIBPiHtD6e4M36eKIvrirSy@oaEPluHfAm2oU7rWKGDIAxUAGpA9kTn2V@7FPsCe1tdNPFIv9KvdvUHXarDJqJU8KjNwy5dm9l4xWMlzBd0Okq8BffcYLcdXaUtH2FisYLFq9Y6iFkUIVz@4an61m99gfI/NvWfaIVomIMO05znhiUw4Jb4Q36cgVbGAj4gpa2r4AHvp00d9BPEZ7QlU16j9AtI@g6nhgLQ@X@u6K886SPgF05f0XhSTe30PfY@7B367oNwvMp7ZHUVYFKQVVuDMJnaTRdUHjEBsFX30BWgvnM8BgDQP@ZEwC5xkxdGpNbjDApRtMFhaTUi8wdtKuBOy@aO4NbB5nWSHeZL9SrZvQzg19yWw@kyGDqoU@Psc7HfOUYg576r@Nr6j6Pv7/whv/@4sfm99e/879@UmjcbsfF6rcTuwC3Eb7Hcj1qowDLBUdY2jfCRP/oJ@5H7mzjl1ih9wcWMitInni/k58zGTc4vE2Ay77NH94mdpd9b4zsGyIKj8jPsIzdXOOIE4sFPLYVdpQadEHF7nBdQaB00G1FEKQwl3SBEJNDrzVqGE4Gjv1k4IiTgWM3GUgkdv7E3p@I/kT0x72vnZ@@jGB2YXjulYagfWGCXIZITW4XnNqdvt8Xp8DFjdat4muq0Ie94UsmxKdsgzdPgIv09k7ozzt1/rwT@PP2K1LG/naOsbubYzxu0IqXWzIbhWXxT5ZB8sA9LrlFqbHLtfLgqN413ygmP@9LwKURZ/9GmOkbcUABhhM@vkH@8YfsjR9om3/gwK/xsw5wWr6gNpAwwFSbgPbhhcFPtYm9eXShu3Yg9JcOBLxyIHQXDoQhQVQSxiT5iPgiFOTAB9dONZYB@Taqocavm2ysxJLQcJeNN7qeGDT1xuJGKeUhgRIhpwT7@wNM@gW/nT/4KcAAX97gP7wBNy8E3LsQYOtCgJ0LwS/Mwl2D3Z7B4NZtwf5B3D1oC818B6fST8/yBZpRDycFKvx0KPdk9lqPLm5uvVzJ3TaBZCvf@tWRdkCHDhZc78d6c10LR5PHfNP9BQK11zAf4QI5tea0YLmdMKwdyE@P7luz1JEJKEwYBt2868nu3z6@i9Bbm0wvX8DcfhbtACq1JLrm@761caLrrk/rTFVe9x4bdbGdeQgX1glU6lV50BDeJoXuBZoDFJkCnE/LF85NCwIl6MsrSUBc0AucOlJA3KYRWn@VelXaVIBvokKvSF0y9JFZp9at56/Uq25dlb1sWD8ve4b82P3XVkDqQPbEZ9juPtBiT2hvY3HM2M1T5tzhBQ14OQNNCT5Qw@8rDCtOOjLxKv3MpDKvVvrl8MAYeaX8HOYdtJiBWhdgxuD4PnBU0jvCvRrqeAW/yZjtTt9tOWZr43qf9idsilLm1bYf0Nl@nMI/fTtVGaj1SqCS/OL2kNxa9VLM8J4WQc6P/OmXcRt0ikendaDKi86I6BNXsVP@udGhvFg/GPWqob@R6YSphy4bKmt9nPqqSZhX20t1PHSKSlEVRzgr@/QsXyAIA0ZBK/p0KPfExyxexEzYeAXTBXRjekazO6KbaR9pQeMFSz1r@ysGc3vmcPgpb3lXRyl0T8R3fooVuxgfOB0lQH/oPty62Q9lbUAF4UiSIFDCyS9BXmlCfybwZZ5hil0QKOFooqF4gVLPOtS@T0ZiT1KHgOTeb8iABRYgMpm6cdkTd849oHfXZQQcDKMgIelB9sRniT9JRu0JQGfPDYCzp@7d2VN3OFrqjkdLFZD8DBwTLNP9wZDKfARzhvjkjJmQs49P9k2be6BbjCLcKWIULhW5uylBso3b0oHkibc@1iaQYmsfENldzhBIrbXdpMXW0IHYgQTEVZK4zYvtdMX3Ber8FuhdryNYp/ZYayNt5/UOhwHf7ctjqXZTT2yHXGq/JFRbtBWo2CG8QvwiR2ERQfIPH0p/wGtQiUwYlLeWPizaXTT6QTllruAHWPR9x87cPfjV3Hfo19FBtF03xaBTbCecyaIlvrV7bWd7NKO4bHUFloAvjUSSsze98LvcEA/2iPbkgSsrfrsiW62we4LeNkXd4Dp6W3ueu4FmVOXuT7O@T@5W6fs5w9oAzBzX/KKPWdMwEKsPsCnnDYpgb6vDyQ9diR0VIBBn0wLeWNvg71DiGOSnJ7783f3Ayh3PgbrDEU/FDgfNKHFvKiGf0Dk/IaVr9x02lJB5r9bu01pqijtGm5CPeMJ4py7ahcCbzgj98fFJmDKYKb13M6V3mCm940zpfR6@/NU2SpwvhJw3Arw/352jb1TBjBECriDVApw/0PCYsdkxQyjwpOEBzqGLVuijFTBaoY/Wz8X5JCd2z3b2nvlSNoMqHHCkxMdv8gccKXDx22jWtnXDIAFpxr/V3sYFTz1TknqSAfnYyTloHWije9yhEyHEe3zcfe9AgPfnG73pSurxDZ5gycXdWUoSEPepnmHn1X3@YPO0EGyabjDxLCCBiovuBrPO9w1uObx3t4LcN3/L4R1vCbnjmoc7rHm4b1t2W5YYtIWHuqltM1nsLlAlCZH/2BWGfQ1G8NZvfju92tsnsnX75RUlBEd0CfFb5xW4r/zWb41XljpytDdSFPbATwEjn9kR2mACXEvXUOoYtJG3uPTdMoUQaqeEn/ktdk78Z37rzlkV5F4VutkE84CQ9/oHCvUPlukfX6R/fImOw4SDIoxcIHHIIeIqpUq9agjuxkkG7QsAS1Rh/9EdV6sScLWD2Nt8UhJ7khB5sELAK@wWrCxdsdzDlK7YesV9T0rZpWan16mUb@5@xUAxgh2svwHtXmH9xSfFBOK3/qLH6@/knxaDtpUtyD2bf7pzgwx6Re81fjYEuCpJUbxAqWNAVh/W@cQBrRfYvYSGLrTcuynMZZWgqxBQCxWslADyatFbve03gNX9POPL051gywgyYu7SDCtylIA/fpWOAu/Pa@uqc4U@XRtspzaSAPkABYA/fPaEG59paOqxG/tuofM3dfHD8wcYQfzg/IFCsOMoBPyBjqMA5w9Pijl/ZJosA/L@yMRZ488xzzgdrsy907p@ov80Nz@452k8XqtHUIbCBkcH3/kiGK@wosdw49Wd74rxfkCgK2QFxhUiiQPTRzcwLe3u7ImPBA5VSzu8jUWa4A1WkgB5fwW0HsNyXQE@cn65rthdXLAPf3R9@AP68Af04R9DcIcgPgbbDqU/z4OfJWbSZvyD5nVwRtsgKgbfjjGUELWF20jrUx9eFxjk76M71vkBpzo/8FDnx0BrMN0iMEVNS62QEf2FY4YftCQpttb0HMDaxDysYcApbIMuicFdziWbrbECqBRdxu54kkpBtU0sr1TwTXJl7omFbQn4hIR5vzc9VvLebj1mzCOf92b12OM54IlrhlzmPwc4c81I@0CeW@/XduHX1vnVHeD2mEa/Zl6A82ca3Zp5sTs/wiM4L4KWkNbeZubkTzd@TO4M4scEV84ScDk/RXAfZ2zqnywhdG28E3n/2/jwXHCbQAHJE5dHYk8twDe6P6n9gSe1P7qT2gv5RW9@u7j8gie/EJdtW8ATJj4u27Z4bxi4uGxQH@IVUQ@@EWp0LtyDJPu98wPmxgV1/tzBp25xm7JODZPeP4YNH8PWPQZ/QtNjhiOaHtReaMKlxkAbtW3wPU4CLqJw4@vDX/j62KAXS8BFeVvHDVUUJWS9Q19e8ALkB1xlXOwPTE4hoJL6e4Ur9aoR4g3NHr4AqY2xb@M85IDp1oGS5JFb0WMgtQQua1WSMiAXGwE@PthQFeQSLUcGepW1c@S@Znim4CN2dUzs65iIdUzs6pg44MCVoYTIvZVKXIwyLq9TBmov1HmhQu/NC33BbQlKfPJha4ICl/wQRvQnjJ0/YQR/wtj5A4@0AFgCIczNETNyz9mt2XjA5bBkfw1u2VlFqIY6YUQQO9D5gcCN/DJxx3IbaYeQCluHLo9XvOZVGOTyCte8PtzpWQ9/vSxZa@Z4Akqg4Yq133iudnQPdvd1INAeD26gGc4pCL/AhUCBmhJU6ULAVfIVugDvD6w6UgL@@HVHCrw/v79dhBiBT4WBV0ycX9sNu1KM/BvezeYwQp@2F0SqEB8@H67pNI4dA6fTNr0TH5cDZo@V@NgdfvZYgYsuXmWrBPzxl9kqaP05hvI9yH7c3SC0TQ6eDYgdcUEePD/QBCnABQkTZQ@4pfdxwAQpAa@QMCKpi0eCaCSMRYZa/8i@hv9gd@LjuxNPas2vY9NjeVLrXYmqwMopAW1En7yGNDonLqIEYOSQkRsf5NvsfEDriAGtow9oHSGgdfwOEW54a2m6wG0t2sI2n2ggzTn1p8ITmFxavn0@wwy6AJ82P1sudpe2iPkTu/yJkD8R8yfifYqCfGRh3vuJS0ef3dLRJ9xS@oSlpE9cSvocoPwL8Knx5V/sLjX5hitqlPn0dNvEnxe7xJ/dJvFnv0e8oBl9mjErjhl8mSHpH2gKEXENoSd0dZ94QvbTd3SfcD72M0AbQ4DzIfj2hdjBD3xpCfmXNgy4YMsQBAZLtoz4AGHq2UgG5J6uAufPC2P0Qn9fnbcviN4LQnl1geDKjoYlgDBz10AXLThAgYCPVemJoLUNCqLDs8RrB9r3VFH76TSGHjv72jbqrABUy1Aq0DYZQuAZCGwHEE/WbvpoaduUNo4oo5ftZKLagyc0wNMBr1J69Z8dEiUMgzOarjBAF4YrXu6USK7lVrDScRvRsQQ5HP3dBFwvrk6BjsG9u@niJx3utvEQdTOdUKk/c42@ks4x25MDvuDLXPTak7ZDZsz1rwx2vnuwui6Y1TmnzYqmJEtBM1x9omZLUAubnkvFbSYrA60MQbgxMQUBkJVKT0DpLJfV77ZYdjBdUM98ACmD1f0Mk@L9ra54qWt3hetzgsEeAj5Dd9djEXvyoG17Tb6l/SzxgcFZQU5p@/KjjgS8gutePDffsXjS8OK6NWejP2EMku0J7dkBKr3taepPP0DJ1gTW3Nq7IMDBgkEuAWO5BAhzgUBw/xQTCKavP4RB7bH1G0OVef8iDpUbSohcG1RJ61OC1Ca/x@Pp76YQa5uK0kadoSwJg2BytyTYoFfMXf5nvPmbkY9Vhlu/n6XOwyXqylxwBxbyAwr5sQy4DE4ZqHUHQZ8sddBFvqLWP1oIOGJrqqW9Mn5YWuyisD6g8yIkZUA@lgzaco@LgRW4BgkuD37C6mC1t18QWC78xAN7BKQOZE985NM3@glpgbMcnoc/yeH5edg9D6rAwDV0lECTTKiLnaHkmF0bYeEVe/vBUuC/tgLbhBhpo75vdAGOT5/CNo2Tn9jE84onN6kJZxJPI09yu/JQWbxi6QL2rC0rFcULlHqGKF8EkEGtq32VebVpu4FSIaiSPustwsFBDXfqwW10ZKudP3Mi14qnaXZ3As0FTsDrGTTIULGeQoPMK7a1jTRFw9qTdp20sCl1pFOy82oahCr1OJqGoc@f1r7y3Swtic59eyaNMTuURu3z3N/4qhDujKB236Nbw1Kpe/zLV@h3vVfqVZf@MHWDoNjdOjz1lw4z2q7uamh@8QcgTHTRMJxtYCxfoPkD0J9WYCj3ZHaB@sVdEw15Z6fgr6ZRAKHPkCH@hmK1@3Bnn187Tf9/XTyt8wdwEIfyNt6GCxfnL@hk@xouw6g/dA72GK7UGX86SJs0eh8wR4/Ye3nA/v/S676I6XoRy3W43Q68raBSUB3peJZOVSioUj/D33RMkPrx7XXOtIuxjyW@DqVkrt1R/pWC6rRDkSfki/L6by/s9j@BzxfXUbf0A7S76rnFH8CPeFxERXAXjat7hdsfOgf9BbYOj/@Gp2vuhjuaH/I17dLa3Xzr6HiN0yVu@7oNz5fQPaExLHi2vkFX@QjDRyPQ5/PF@foGQfFIGcsyM692fYJfwz9XNF/CudeduoJycZbfCfMVczl6dZxTpRDSP8eVYqfWHxGkECN0cbJPS8cOYwG8Op5nwqUgBPqzEyr1kb9PdDdMpyoUVdtJFbKvFw7X3llcukpRYK944SEeZjZRh7PLb2MJITwDQ61/5xCLD@dq6KVSvMej/cEV46thgEp9gNNFgZv6Avf3wOz8e0Be@m4v211/zG9cYGvbI@vPi5u68@KmNV2kK/WpSuHWNwaMguo2v/pPhlJQzZdtB8OgfFzWRhXnazpfaGPNU2m@hK7uofH2rjY3mHroq3hjCVm@cpxRMS7honVSeaf@CtMbNAmF8QqGS5iuaLyEV6rwBVfaaU7hDTEvBHJOWLhi6QLGK3ah6D/sCp3etHQtUWaQ3bG72cugV3zR@B3afSwIubafgLEjsScY1Ixerzj4bxCiSR1op0QAnicx3/AUMvYoXqDUsc7/y87WyV2c8TLmCS5jnmIcLveWtT@Ag/A4@isqGo7qOTYt91Pb8Adx03Zv/Gia7kIzXG8swH0Psr/aWOztF4FuMYtYeyh0yfBrA6aX/xFLz8uXnL/DAfsrlbSRZdTGVkET3b8DbAkT4H3xW8LE3vpBO40OPwanzEU5wL22ApIHbU0u9taH6D/XAlxkC3GRZbuLLFxaQsAFskEYm/dwg7lHAS4Om597FHsbh4Num4MyYtDF5YDhYgEusMMPGYvdBQarHf92ix3/wlrHv7jU8e/h16GJPXnQzIWKtU0HphWSmXBY21BC5MqHktOnbxqnGLd02/ZwBZux/m8avWhUJZCGtgPBJbWv1oZL/br1fN@8qatR4C1czc/h1VjwhITv/iwERu1DUtA8pe91g1XGSpw/hJw/Alp/6FAH2lzdLIb5pp37tIn6XJwwD19bqdChoqq0fSy4nQv2bs2Dz6wZb/OeB5d7M1zuPQ@duv@55FSnwgzUviGW2BuYB98dEHuTdTNcrT3j8eWzv1p7hrPM56EbCBLklboTTAR5pdfFs3n1T@YX0vyLSf71KfZ1/xwGP/ckwPlQiPOC7d6Pb/Tju/PjG/yAjA9wStwc/JlwNCMAGUsEVbDNcjGRQGfUdxvhDXrFtiS46m2udyFU@@ptzu9p/50erb/@19SeIKT2EUHTzlHyDkObo1Netjzde5I69OqJUzpc9I5SgAfXoawwXzGXuBX6ojMOTc79qGRBD1gdasgXKmK@WAlxBWv1HdkZRiTnbjByDi942C94Yu40drY22TdddNcNesWvEFGNEChhY1SQVwqtPDpLmz1Ts6pzntqlmsVmZdRC8QEkdxCVgrEj7jEKsmJa4VlOAaWevS6QVzvaWLZF1bN8gdoEPp4ZFpI0DBVhWreBLm7fsEpHiSvDhFwRFtCWYFg4NU/wbNaHP7NAiCsT/xxwk7EgX1Yy3CHAxAeVn93cv0FQPGKndkRQenX58@rz54X58@ry5wWnTPTXguul4KN35GLDK/laT3Bp38xL@0bnAnzobqpW5tX6WU5lXg0WdQtwebP5Zd5ib3Nmewxrt4W4Uh8c9OVmWAQ4bys@LSE@Ris8LQEuTjHoh/W0T23VsnXxxaiWNjGqEPJKR8K4HQli0pU/IaknGZBPo5TIDrRBvTGkd@ftG3x9ox@fYcZiQ8gFfdygKcbABVSIC4jtbUDHXDoBPiBGPqBl6tpQwjq17uCRSkF1h6hjP3eGfu6M/dz5WLGRSMQHAxuI5m4D3Qwb6GbcQDcfPwcm/cd3iRfeSDO0dlrOfbpYhu4ucUOxRwlRWxEZiR1p4/Nwq6HF7r1tV0OLtXX/N8CFe4JAacNBQGVe7TvAt5YRfFWXATt9TLxP5dO74rUIlXrVFd44Iu6xLrTxc4a9Sw1MHXV7mhrWBgvrPwUkD/zTjFCSIhw5rMSnJfojhxW41JXnF7vUVZg6CqmrrI1bjlO3RadSn4wPrDRm4lV@IZ2/mMpfn0bfl13C4LpsYk8etGU8@BNEin0F9yu6X737Fdz7qkWASwHfDBWdE0xD3iES2b2YNPv7avc5GYGAKnQJGGnMfG59YzC5KFTWpq3t4BZbqb7dr1u7U2UJc3n9cOtCpT7TZjgrhYlXWWAghIlXWQdoBStyWbf2V4wY9L5FqFH4UP0hXkJ0CfYIRQKPpFuC3/Iqdvc84IwSAd4Pf0KJ2J0fWDJLo33s2vIn9onwZXYax7mrwAViFT6NsGTDSDt4crLkoVuGYcDHpLv@YWn7uMVi5dR8DZtbIbxMuMdXicveCXb4KmgzePLDJmJPCH4caDuvYk1g/2nt3xDP@RujOX/7WM7fEMk1dM9DUQIGea@kjR8toIc3QpgrO6Wh1zUJhIEaPoW1ewgrPIMVH0G6dV9bYe77WlCgwwohTkp9rBLMExih9kpMl9zNzSr357s0sB0uYdzOQRg4A0PcTlordqemNKwZ3yLKA9f3Lq8EY3Z1i7kVwmLuQgMWiBSgOKSuACYsayUK3fhspeAblprUlZoEpQba8svWj9Ypc0FtpR8FUWLklcb@@yIM1DDrN9wXZSR1CIl7WBtsmzKQkLTAr31eNrfAedn6iX1l3pd57hI1z12E5xljPM8Yn7VvUQpDtZS7RyIQFFEHft52bKgIQzUef156lC9Q2xiqEL0rASw@1Aw7Z0/mPlqV@kiXVsERPSnfkLY0rKV67rrjJ4YU52eXLwV5pQ3Oh1jkpLs2T@LFSxH7lyLu/eBipaCar7zMF37mrlDifQILnm@4dMcbLnC64YKHGy4bnC4qwPvhTxYVu/PjmEfwhIn3pSDvDQPvD306nZsV84qXkXgnPuOO/MSuYmUJoe8oVtT69/IxekF8Xi42bj5lOeDWeAERQepA9sQ99MOf0Cr2hPYmVw@4JoWA92HuRlqVeY/nPMEmnMriFUsXsGfdKuiGX4Tv80JRvEAXLlu0LBDosqACvoCMfPhrieXev9En937CIiIB/mn7RURid08zoR@p8yOBH6nzI6MfufMjgx/Q@DhoYZnPHiYJiM8vBk2OfPoP4af7DH66NTqGEiIX2gfX6Cyfi1kgg63iiudxrnD85jrAkQzr4M9gWPG0p7U77WmF055WPO1pvV7MuF4uZVwvDnha@@OcVjgYaPWn/hRr97tXoNoRD9812Cti1BWC4rer9Rk0teqKR3Su3QmdKxzQueL5nKv/IqzwMVjdkl22fW1H7Mlz28Zrmnrc9nEqhKs@Tv7pGagFCBr8t62saj@iHFnu0200@@E1/cHvZTlhdk3AUrnBxgom7qG6D@vqv6mrX3nMVstuQJbfFzhdcNeDrRSv4Tl/@FxAVAwYAQzEbyFeZRCmAwlIW8B1TKYBa5fBTPITUOfK3Uq1bl8wQsnEOdom34YU4F6ubXJtSLG3L9e2ftFcoztRtoEJqT9jtWFtvNZ@T79BnwCMfxd9iD1GPmNtRsQHgd8fJQlI@/VR4HzZYLMuI9dnXWkCFhNNyPl03Np5aLHenL2dlhb7rQUjZiwRH0TXKTaUELlUH9gpXuk6FchgRl4ppk4pJlSiQbt2AZaR5JFbJGXA@QOf5sOvS92@eJ9aW3Eqyj1p6xBivgpVkjvQVPd8@vvgXZV0DxCBKR9QUJW1ebR9/Q03LK0G2we1fZXPAG4NM@h9TP3WMIOgGGK/8vPETvl2O3ac/TTYKfrUCIk9SR1C4nJAQOxAQtKAEd8cJk4F7txhe1sfFQADiUaSR25s0YALyMV@8p3ybXYLm7e5Xca8LevUNQ4qzMigTBtrAtv3LebuQIoTuxyKY4i@KyjIK0FE2O733SibezK1o1MGU4dyuEDjBbtw6o5laWCn2nsYgm@oCAX0gAx6@Nzx2c9Wt81I0dyBdhzQGHqsGePJ2KPeneYKMlTsPDuzpIGe8PzeD@SKQJc13ezAhhMD25FvUEkRcb4cGV/SQvwbecDImQLvrX9Hxe6C6Q5WOVlC6B96Rc6/t@vKGPCpf2PvwZj3yTfTjYSxZ77sKmyj/8JP1wu@W6/gr/lRkIC0ddgLq4wC@IgAePwVuzJArU1/gLogf8ohMz4kpve08nTJu9AM@xj7LbxGwEu3f9aA9wdmtRnBnPb2W9rP/R2kiuHKyX24QZqVxI4kIG3KFUQEqQHFoQ9nTt6LOUcIl0n7VWXkw2HQfBH3Aa7@U5A88Z6wvY3smiDBa/KpgRFrAn72xUjuSdOKZ@anWQzlC9ROshDEOMUuUtGr7F0RahgqQsFqoAskDrQWAPtXDfdRoN5R@zXfSaH9hu3dfN6Os3kFwB2UShIQX8Ki7xXvOBu/49q3Hebmd1j7tuPJ3gSm28Ve4/YH9MHbEzpMnULsNCBWuM9YiS9TsNNYgSuweEJY9xm7OB2s/6wV0g/IGoSI@0Yofg37I8W6jyOBlPxSK2OT8/liZeB@tTKwQHwkfkfvHgbMbyEuvwm5/BbQ5ncoBWTqi07FPtA2gWH6Gtp2DMyNsRV/puWFgBLY31NCX95b/PbINQt8L26HXJkixCpitAroXMSEBAFGgYkrlPAFgAwuNZK3eqe/W5hL3zq66jesuNxdkH9IMMNAwCtsqLCBQuwOEVPWg7EjnUdtU2jnxYBwzIHCCzL2KHUInkTsjlcT5t/q8mbueOGFQciMbyhROLW2w/78HffnF7DP4ad7x5RCcOliZubEvTI2pipMPZz881LW@thdbWooIfJ@5dj5lCHfcNv2HvzomNjbfKMLVWDzgjIX1HOat7TtUK8a9apb3mh3vEthhfESpit6AV2GVBavWLqAwK5mwNsfvM@fNG2PFXZandj53n6SpmCVuNlvwdvgR6vBT5K81ervhmj1XYmrECYfQnQWH5kIsbGKu7UnAGCHoJtKuyLnwlny4GzOma@vlT6wYUXEezrj9aeGEiKfUTNcgrpP/jgLsScP3JP3x1nsEx6wycSrZIgppg42KAtwr/zkNyeLvX3lqYYbvbWNwY9P4w9E4Mel0A3flFdpSH1/xSiofoVpWB2YwrA6dy4rYHwGFqT4xSWwiMSvH9m77Wp7v19txw1re7djbb9Yo7j3axRpSd8NlaYbqGCDgQio5BAfvut5sk4Rupon9IF8sH9rKF@g9sWrMAGDbq@xfMVcy6tSF0PajDc1QdDWu7Z8dvkGuQZLPQh4BRq/aAY@GTgHNJ7RjhczcT5cHYN1feLwvuUvPM9ImSu@W3eehyDwi8ZZ@4bMyUG908P1O3u3oXXfoFOkxyJfJLj95crJv3PQq0@@mycgAWmrIbG3foRBx/fat9yoe61j6BeaK8TmcQz9rj@DEPzk3YELX9Ow3S1yqCh00C@qEOa6RDH41SE7bXTud82eGGK@YJ4RCD0Ze5Q6dEGe0@4hPI3FTn53YOxIQtIDDcpYPx1pcPL@J7p/oHvMQiG3sAUe@yZ4xDZ47BrhMfiRZAWQx3i6Y0WpY76/Jgy02lFptftcgIMaK0mIXINPUKsDZ5ER8Nkx3b7nTuV7xmwk1juEjPRP0j@sTrW@dZ50jtzCMUFtgzbWj5bZl@5lmxZ80fhA8otKsXJQ3zovt9ip9L7hlqd/c3z99eH1hd7m6dXrCgXVcXqgXkGgdO/OtDWIihenXp/4cwHzFZs7zal7i7fu2NnK8gVyz36j3Qnds1EKwez9YbKVdqoRegLGUsd8mVfkfXuGLiOJ9WqpC/QJ9/Qpw0Cf/vI@u91giD7/@5sQDG7xik1uMLPF8@fqh0uP8ZsjPMInt7uOwa5dGOLHpwsuaDC2xQs0tX35ls6fC37lKXzGBEdfc@H9EIXk9gpGtTsn/r4VBT5HfvBJ@e5ePPC0dUXZExj9F9K8Welzu5hJMOqCPGAWkOzuM3H4OUCytrU@XnS9w0XXdIUGDM4JiR1JQNwbISAi8AHlzpMMKrCbl4jbrlsAtBwOP9@8H3CKAwEXsc8DRrQKaGNxMStvKF6g1LMOtTllJPYkdQhI7v3OoNRdfFVZvGLpAvYM4o8XX50o9QxRvggAEwHzmUoSEIiVn9L85wi0Pqx1wmDsyHqh1b7QhNCK3rgrUxVc6LhWqrKEJCJIGHrvTfttYODXkDNC@@EBZnnAHA@Q4QHz@3ALVAj45Sn/FHtq6kW1jwjWXqepPImADbxo71RWe6/ho8ooAYhgTxBs50XzhWO72zvBBKyHs8OkkBL/9Cc/LaTAxWyDuW0jyaPJZ@oG888RjqaK/lyqCCfVykBvdqCNqAz75sY@TttjmIcfCMWwD2xaIbRpxeCm1Yc3rRAgjEIJSB60JVzsbSxwj52SBMR7svhKMA47JAWmgwrwCfHzB3RKJcYiBggTv7QRh2jjkPZuG6VBr5i7ROPXREkC4qMEnwwFPqCLScrrk/DjAMMQcfBDDlEWLrjRrCgLFdphL0K5PwThxC5Qptg3rBRU/bIeARFB6kD2ZPKRHSGNIwbqi3zoszN0WRmGHSYeBEHQ0Oxi0ra7Yvg6InjzdUTvS6kj9oz2XiN54FcNCOrsI4LYgdSTtqehELXaWj5SD3J3z4iBL2aMEhBYniCsB2NHYk/SBXI9PqWdnms4EIJFDRWBS7/OoRKXVRcnnTQ0XVAoGwadrzCtzgTcbXgIqTLwKfeR6yoyRQkRhIh1mZI2uJFObukjZhiUj3XEYfZKveq9eBl8kSTkG1r0PVi7sJl53x7d0ULKQO1iIeDllSPFr9uztd2nm19mT@zT2h6rt7mcpkvkXFoLcKEtX7TxqidjjxZfhJX2vkGAdEvn0u0WaH6AsJR2vtB5GB2DqBNwvrkA19sQ13azQ8PGCwjBGd3Wa@pyYh2DK@ATPJf1Hm6dV/etXVtRydgjfBYnTT3uEaass/NkYOoTqz@ESzheUfTaRyaFmDsAHqVc2pE9udLqAsv4uFMeLvzPfYYmv@PFUBfCEd1ePtnx84h91tGhlDHkK/ZvlSGmSjEOOW7jgXEQNl7BdAGv/ezjVbH35IXZ9@pebEYYDDMIQ1kfAJKUO9AFmfL0GC6CSLl74q/pQReKhEvo/E3pCGjvFBIASHp5lhCWkLFHqUNXfvk0Xtx0Y9B/i7HlOrtj5MSeAKDdN8Pmrtsw12ZhS6AtdXkdwYn9VxIa13N7Gp1YQRusrvk7Y59mrm2/Bvg8p2Ppu06PQB9Yd66uIB9/PgTV6wTs3fBpp@DIB8UnEzo3fBBhq9JPaF/MZxd0sTuyoemKuh2ShLuNhA1MF9AX4K5LBasuFSQkAHy6/AJNtScAzk6HjW34nJWCasQXQYhPRISyJ6CNIw0tLq0bBsmTKSzOSbG3cYnbkaGRSwgbuYk2K7vRW2MZkJ@PMdTWn2kPt67CEeifQdrptLerV735xWdtBm@z9zHjC9Y1yS9u8TM4X6Debe8wjD2KF@jCrx5BVZgjJhDyo7tm0Njck85h56oLy/f9lfT@dMSXuGPtysOxYml4hWl26cBRErLjk8OVLv1Cl4t1LhfLXLpVLgRmLDyEfP6//K4iBeCoXW6mdufHFGZIlR8NIis8Y1hx0y246dfb9MttcLVNsW/zcTmGd/7go45bjGPodgrH57An2IenzPn1dF20p5tfjtPXhoedGHMHnJTo3Z7O2vaaT/hx1scKVhd/Ar6sEEnOfvadAY0XbHFTYhVf@IjBdh3o7hcM0HehG372oVuIaai96Ip8sG0/uoPjFcVAfVf6AvtsqZ3pk2A4TXe6gZvbZlbReMG65wNdauAXrEtkD6Bb3f0Srul4iTvvIU7Wt/YEPau9a0CXen2QuSsHKQ9XgeSLHE7YmFTWB3P2sk/outktrv3sDv57dYyx72o3/Oxrd3C8pOmK/ht/L6LnO9znD68uN199TdD2uQFiQG2v29MOpdyTPmDX8/Y/9CWh7Xv31PttvW8HepWEBPPh7IEDGi9Y6tmlf5Dex4RHYStzX0FG@ULNt4MnOAtUgH8a/ixQsbfjJNS8he88Ix/Qy64Eqip2J5Ao0I1j4Asj58sGW2YEuOhufsOM2Nvobts3BLN9dyFv3xjy9g32BWLCe/KyJz4mvD2vjQmegsnEB5MglISBJB9GgiCO0ohq25UE2lZk16vr@3TbG6ZJGfhYvP0sKNtdPLr7u2J3f1c8YHXD4Vc3HHD4hgAXj8MfviH2Nh64EC3CQrSIB9vG7mDbCAfbRjzYNg13OHuRSZuWNNCiYBeQoTYoYW1gRlxw8@B7q0oSkLaXpKCNEfbbhbjYQJ9dgIvJjBGZMR4zRGOGWGTIlTljnszZ58iM2b9284qVpY756Kw4a8jo6LJTICiOEPV1xKivo4/6OkLUd8zyHXI48yUSLmmCEiKfMCFtdI8bRPe4YXSPm4/u4dcLpRusRyLgArkNcLWJEhfMbfCXmyj4/@s6767Uma2B/32fTyFFpEtvgihVsYCIDYIYSCCBNFLkeNZzP/t908DsPbxnrbOW@8fOnpLpmdkDA1Kxj2@XoeBUHJpKBKaisFQiKFx4bASyEzu@c4GGiFWWFscY3Dh@cKd7BAGTqPo5sgbBIUyEwF7vg0teknjN2fugvBGwNz5BBQXluINgWlTbtbWKHkT5rhKeZQ4MW0PeZQ4I2dtJhLmdRFrbSdjYTsK2WJaMm8OQNQsicw6C9ozlEpszEXqQcIfuMljmDbONRc2Tw5Aa@mbgEg0RWMwNuPFMY2k46rEAiLR1YpHBraULoaWFNXciFG2IFIk96i6DasjDt0Z4@NaQh28Ne/hGztwcEQQhCjgMUSACEQUUioj6a7QxxJFB8vgVi0T4s8R6rUkSDX5VVShrnvUwSxS97YMly@akVySRwiFmHYNYeNaDfylM3gFqJP1BSAR7ej0MPqujJOk0zJFvFokMkpE6j97AX5Cjf72VwBJVKIK4/YWFhv/rvdDelb0PkKdgXQbL89EPGr@YUCZ3Qf5ipIw9b7lIhwR1Ng7RAcDJQO4VsENm5I1ZY3GTxKL2x/ZkqOsgqtYOR133RsxepIDhOMjr69xhMHiH6N5i/gdV8D@4ev@BlfsPqtp/yBMhewjC5mjrgm1vUA4BgVkIBOcAb4Ac2sLqAGSFQUYYbGO1Ip5ZrbDSBge0IR7aoIA22AZ@URzyM2gCBd1LvUcoKAXeQ70nIDhYuExxA37ccEjUoAxFAdkSGJYgsFXhkEdmG/CwqedQfuDt3zaBOQRqiCltvNqmyGFZQwDJAjS3T5cHgAaOgz6kbRn2kxyKL7rL3Sbw3aGTBA6ALxyeJHBk8LJlBtcEmSGqgsyguiAzuDLIcBDAyai35uQdDmdHBLNDoexwIDvkRO@ANMSAn6YD8eav6pbr/UOWDIumTVSSaBih8qvuK8EBuKVtH7IpgsJiA5UAGiIwg9V9kdzLBrESuIegYJGn8zXiKL7GsysWSl4LrOR9BaYo0d5fVRWImvcWYEsWweTOAoeRFGIKh6FnLIUxTBILR1MI/2B2GE8RED2uw7S5A6q9/M1CiYEi1AXvk2f/wkz9CwqjJatIhjH7C0uhCQyVJQB4xvIaiwbvDkN117oZHW@92UNYtoj76fdIJZGGEWiheXw//Z54g0PX22rE9bYaut5Ww9fbataeB2SDqB6CgGzg2iLy5KbyA4VRFo/cu3agpCrOTdIxzjFn2EccYR@QSiIQqCHo1j23nvPoe7g/pL4PQ1qhsiOtcMGRjm23/8UwaE1DapoGFf5gO3/waNUk@BE4Ut3A/Nx4Nz2gbzq2qEEZinjQscGDjg1LrM24CBQwm4E34xJvIduAt7kBOwHgpyZb0oAIJPQ9wCUwRjz8IuACb3wElv4L7TgE2LEQsOMAaIdVsB1WIeywCrLDKtiO1/2@I2pIxurembYAne47soaBTgCogtZ5bABTwsOVH1sG6ZDx2qBDoBUZrQw6ANjB32xcAu2g7zgu8NoRWdxCOgTYEVnURjoA2JFR9bIBtCLDcmzLwIbBrJARm0ArJoJmbOC1IxHrrxJeapVYPHNzCAjKQsRTKCg87pWIca9J8C00NkMzBgkNjyU8PJbRcVwHgKBkeCDXkYGNOfKjYhHgnUSTF8hbvENgU2gjYGYBPco7ALRMNvEGtATXuVmydxVdRrerOgAmF9636sgguej6XBeAoZeD4OjKYeBjhIM0giAdGB9b9rbrDgHdqoO8XyEcomEANFhRIt6JA2GeCzy@WPzANILxMKp494QmS4QXK5dBNRlNbWUZzmxlFX2QsgF8taqKH0GvVkWlR8URU2FxUlEkv4GrDM05Aek54ncgGolAMbY3nHr3OB6QdoTBWvPtdRChKdbIzFvzHKBBYrYb4BFT9kRRQd6k7I3h5OrbnoI8UaDXqSMbzfdIPYI0khGIHBsfMBkyKI4uUUlCPgYI/gKikJ9AFPwNRCE@gig4G2AikB89C0CDMC0wivwGP4w7IpMgc6gbUniJUbEVB2mYIUsO8cZHllDL6xAYI1mCba8DQJxkiZhqOAzNNBzvpypBUIDQbYILQIDovLEF0IxFUa1hIRrwHCAM0KEwzD2DwfJEhjkI28NZ5hCvra1B42Gdi4AtmwFbLoG2iDGOi5AtPMpxideW7tzb4bXlImBLdy7yUNGDhC2VMKWSllRsSMV2dGIF3GZIDTu4cIlKEGgJubRwgYoBCkrQOcK0oHOkcUHnsDVB5wh7ImFNJG2J2JKI7YDWSufx9kAboWdAG6UTRVzHpVnn1SX6cGUjmIl4q6JNoB0ZTwIcAuMro0mAA0ACZAmbkQgrEjIiYRtoCQCviJkyfkM2QcGo6A3ZAARk7XxdobBsBoMjfdwcmEYwmPOEGxsL7QjPOgeKVIm2xEUwpSpuS1wC02oVJuRD4kBRsLyCQ@UVIlBeQWHyaNqjG7gJMHALYODhvU0QgDlqoPbAQMN2GwAZb29xCEwN3vDiAJgagSwFNkPxU1hCS2EJJWJH9B6iyKtElqlEo2kiFHkVt5E/Ihi32zIDgXfcboueCBtz5/s3/FR/oDoB0Qf7A9QB49HLthGPdyTsKcgZByJCDMMdhtTMQYeO1SwG1ZakX90D1I8xgdCEHnQPTD@CvDNRg9ePHBX/xTCeeLneIJbrDbRcb@DlegNvlTXQzlhDFImXIor4jdgjX2DGJhoi0LINgBXUgRAbqzW0sVrDG6s1s76pS8EgMnCPYYDYu5VLVJJoBMIEpk2B57H3QMMEgiNHsn8xVFaJgqziYqwu3Rn3QeZZkJnqCn/gtBGygod8tttVkOeqfdSVhtVetY@B0qjZ0Basoh/bUeT9BURgR4uoS3IIiJOFQH47wBvLHa3ioaKLkCUVDRRdAmyxNJpAOQRaYmk4gXIAtMPCRRULeBvjHfFRaEd@FfoRRXwu3GUgI39E6z5CrGYxrMahe0Rc5lXTaTSudIA3AyziTb8je5Kv07yA9h/YCOw1MIm7@fcg8uABAVxD5MgaBLzXnLCB6UANoI7PCujorICOzgro1t2rKnpEQu60dFphsTstl0E1tBWNmLqRMzcdudzAEzliHqfT6GyJA6BNeLbEkYENQyecVO8hTNEflKA/6Jk/MPJ/0NMyvmTMZUCNXXDSkUtVPJxQlxf4/qlfTCoTSd1TqMowSIthoAKoy6aI@jeLwHwGZZvl59boHhAGSKBhQG8ZrcMjjyo456wT1ajj30OYJOISGAchJeIOEZdBNXOWdiyv9xgpo5rhAPggrAmODG2gcf0eYTNgEL8nyBLuuvcQKeo8ka82g2q4jrJEHWVRHWVxHWUJP0l7pGEEU6fpOHUmEVGnsIdAkQMulg797eFHFep67tpC92wRd2zh@7V0Du621rFLVwd4Pxc5REMAfIhyiMaRBDrNNumRBsSFKEfIAu0wrKYSSipSsc/BQB37JAxU8m7B0O3bRSXvI15/UoeRzu@PoAKh@8vw3WXkvWXEnWU6BzZx6cjJriN7vrQ5QIMyaDRtoHEEAA61TajiGuQilAAV1SKXgKLIo09dLtE5hOCbsIHujaisSihKNoExMhGMkA1AfFS8l3WPoCUVbXDdE2hLpglbMk3akmlsS0ajWZ2Haz62rCJZw7IOAGiHeLC0ocM5vyN6Q2e9fx86yj3w2gVWwfdi6FQMvlBeZPFo1UJwtIq2EOt4B7G1iitglZVwRAnG0gYguRJSwD8TESFjgk1gG4oOdyHbBI0xZOSr2gIg22T8O/oZhkCY5wU8t3EZtEJ6B9dJ1@AmWlkXESw41rOB2KFoKOUwUGwsZC3r7B/ea8poWukSkNcWApntAG9uywrZUTgMJgFnBsoIY4FjYyyI2BgLFBtjgWODDuy7QEPEW@kc2RMX1SoaEpahAuycHKABskLuAh2EAlqzCyJn9hSpShpyAe5hWBH52PZADVG0Prpn@hHkXSw8QGwPLqLukU4Sz@rhgaFkWFu/8ajvlxPZo5jDUzxY/@VI/ZtFH7tcBtVY2lqegmo2w2o6oYQtgVpqjXUkcCuWjiYFRKjodLxLQPWwEKgeDvBWD5WfG/jY6B7CCPN4nUQlPgbaCAaIvw5Ct3mWdEj3gYDnYRyIhsVGSOmb3LVyoFAVX31uE6hiEMXCQIXCENG83gRAYYfP07kEDLt26DSdC7zDrh8Fz4IcoiECctgBmheQzfMP2Tz/qLSE5kk28ioZaARg4P7fgL2/gfp@Q6IXC1m09yp5kvWLvSmxKEe4iLQp9rRoSHPbe63zqeHHq73/Ado40CO6LHOEqceYRkIwJ7OhHddDtH6jezQNDiQ1Qba4SD2CNIJ5xygmE2SZQXlvM5jx@NILm0CVhTn1t1ypgBLzi0GpkY5do3Cg0C6DL76wEbpEwmKqexcK9Fvl@QW9CodbhoCTac8PMKtMLHjHEXuiYcSz6CmYdpPs4I5zh6E95CYkz8zsIcwis/@BtdAhoB5aCNREB4C6uLTXv0BwS3v9yxvYEl1fYBLsl9FEtnN91Db8UhgzF/NwXeLAfyCzHA3CNuUXwtS4FMymD9hbpTi853uPYDw5tBF8T0CoHLmP5xcie8ROnl8GbWJPEwcEM4dD3iYOBKb2x/oO413qsJnlsnDhUbNuRdaJ4udSGAqptUQZgDopQyJNwHyAXZaBNywbaLOyKVuNHanlUKh6xOv6HsJICfyGJUqrDdELEgw0NNoj9KgBB0d7AmyJ9JFa70AYO8JnuYOQksyQxmQG2yI9jrsMqpnjZqK3sBlSY1WizbYY0WgfuYNyD6HFYzc@HihWBZuzLeDdKG1IKtmhqEc6FPVI36@Sfe8R/1F7CON1zH2RIR1xMGRC@HFlD0Atxicx9wS2COSxeouhI@kmOnKg8EBRMsiN3XuIFPF@DAdBJR12qDp6AFdnvA7nEljL0GKbC0Ad00EXraM4wdZCx5VMR1Xs29137xGJ3@Hr/N5vzD/IKpGlNkMBubv3DyqmDF/tt@M5ACOQhzuWximyEAzKGaBgJDCgcDkjFhiDnVW2vOV0JxOt1E7GrdQP4erBZNhPgqEsoc8IEwBfC4bGqv/PWOL3lx9Mjw0Sfn/wJEUndno4yFtcvukF/oboIKgksISSwGIl3Od948vUv9GLtOUVdI36jWb2tgyOaDnkiNIPAN4XZosrcGvEN1wssEXvmS4HkCo/Hlmz1rhEFBMHggfZFZy8WgAq8N4fQRZ56yqqqbiewlr67V3/@4Y3RX0jj1HfYG3wGzRZ3yjqXj/6pBd97EMfe9An/OdbYGnda6UeY0gR1DgXIBVFBit/B4TUgCjI@KSOy@BLwm2eS1SSaATCBJROFt3RvQcaJhDohFkcYQnHTkLBaGQCNBQXfsETFdthIDCeWAR2EFRivX8zXsFbwVE3QXQSqIv4BgvZ38iN@zf06fENF7m/YVphZHdAAGsd6M4EdGMCvi/Bkn8LOUJQDVRoR4YKhwIOCVTySnicZBOY@8f8jB0ozBSNvNJhD6GiTlQXG8GAvwmdb6wCD@abMnhj8oKeG9jV7YGCGBnCinDfsIdIUWLVI1uBvT94H9jh/Xg7tPtuZ2@Mw9vlvFSD2O6KvFvnvNAbsCAg96sOgkpo09oOuTs1ZRV75XIZtPONEvmN7X7DRH/DYMh1ht2RVYYdscawI1cYiCGhA1QMNALAkMAgwZFVJGtY9sYCHbfcEactd@iw5Q6ftTTBRkARZTcCDNfrDMKW5irPeJwa4ZtTbNnbkOygAwm0mkeMnR0A4@0QDT/FewacLsHh6qAJc5DgHb3@IsKYBaUjutaOC/UoPKZKRglrgXAFULDQdNQBKgKge9ohBwg7704sS2CgxKJfUS6rDMwWlcE5ojIyEL0/CsKchek3CZyJW4hYY3AhWmWwqI6rnoVgRRJ0YsnYhWjNeMexLFijtoG34UObqnZ4U9WOs3dXMIiA@HA88ndjE1DHoMMUW/ytZB4IMsMC8M0jPytEcokJqEtAK@IijXiQ904GXUQEr8MxscMEMLv8ZaRBb40D/FDlSHpU@UjMCD0YumdmvEMrPo6sQhkUa@hgZMejuKoMEonfWZTfKoMy57feeZAMZfCzgF6rgN8p@Cpgi96az6PP5Q6AFuDHckeGNtBHeZcgK/ATtguAHWyFsIEs4Od1XMZ1ooTDI@@O7LUhz@coRx0CrFgImHEAsCML2I6Mzh3YBJqR4cmDnYxOCDoAxgWeD3RkEBN1g3a1HZCGGNjpdiAgPqhZlonvLTvsisQFGiYIgLZUxt9ndsh7iStrCAAZjwMdopFERwgFBI/P7MFvDv/AzvwHd@bkMt4P6rt/QLP0g5olYsnvBzZDP85GC08qfpydFp4oGgpwsO/IGgSeDtERf4P4S6O9hX9puJXwryzOvQE4sgaBJwBHPATg9/uTmmLOeOwlx3Bk@t//Obemn6hs/K/Az@NzWmMLuX@68ZvaxFRem7PRsEgr4QWn2gpJhrW2Rqhm4xl2dJN0KW9Bhg3/iZj/nADCkaWsnvw54aXJ/KxLq/Vs84mu@079g8EV@xxh5tHqrJKsUFSzmpSL62KzMP9gjejn5KNWLzYV9jEUD9LDXqpyM1hIy@h0VaWNbTfIFB7fp5X@Q7lSXd3W3/3J6qqtzxerRmk0ZH1SYxV/6tZjnWFyvRp@3SSkh2Z/GGYv1eHEr3Wb6zV9c715fmADz9PiF1PMLl7ad90@l@KEjHL3wcXyxj1FPSZeZgGpKb/6WtKUDz/F2bt4rH7D9d8ue82Icjni1/RmNpZiX/llLZi6kLo38/vZskadBb/oSnBUnPXfq88cUxJ8xfmpPkidNunTtnY3uUu2CtFuOZaTN4lwkDrzX3WXg9G9mN5uz78eV@dfHJukqLeAMk/XLuIvc13r@cQHwz8LxEtGImCU/aXKK0U9rWKN4YvGU9Tt1Tb1ML0ZDxS@0@z2KKrUeSu8VyZfs1gnx4SuepdhYZu8oahaNH8R51b0cLKZjjLT9FChKDoRD8R8rfD067UgrW7fX9vyZJ5uXyvnMl1@S6Xv6mtuMjD0PkXFjeJt@H5ZZV8M8WYaHpZS0dSq0kk991bL@b3cC0XimrFttSdX8/K03LurNzPj094w1Q9RZ/MZdUZH@9TZ1ygyDLZiH4thPkCvu61y6mXyzDSH5fFTuxZMhqvJRbmXjzHvD0ExWOyf9u7T@pw5D90HinKm@BEMf/SXD8vU9furEWAGn5lW7lKan7/elvrZj00@PO8nLpvSRBDbV6VtY0jXn2bny9VjrTuKvC6aw8u7olmIuE/f3CxzIbVRjNf917nRvH23fLzNtYJ09imYe1lflFPnF/ppL6KoT6WkGemeKq2abfEpMLtbnLeVwX32qUmdVSPVh3LufexbPyUadKL4Mc77@HNRCqQHd5Jcld6iwtNrjV3naolAiWGvT7Oj7PwzUOL1Lr15HmrlMUdR8lIPpZutWcn3qQlTety@SgmF4kWkej6OVka@drqQLs27YbNcJRLbl@encqi2faluh/KglpJ95e27EBkb5fwq0BkslPBXf/66Ol2uQ3QrEva9Xc7Yi@x75VG4G9Smwd70mX7IfDwps1Ghla1f8tP1c/stRVHSpeFP5jLiqhWczoXz2se40llcVoTg27Vvcbf13UwbSfGUonqPhffZe8d3/dXrtpbBarTbibyVbj/ikkyLyYEhKK3XeSq2it4swp1Yk39bPCT0Xrs1L1yP1Un2OvfA@x5SWTEaZlfU2dD/0OEr0uAx4PMLzKjWoM7yk02kyMWnN5/X/nJJCD3dfCx8mUHzxWxYeqHOlDpbJNrv01au9dl54j8bLeUzxH755EbzTc@FAw9MPpJPdn23scTFNu1vvg@u05tnuXvejyezkaYYrj/Q3cdKdv51qwYDHW4@LcuLdmweYqmz5@7LXamYZ9Va7qsc1IOl0u2ie3e3vKqMzv3RpRH4yLOzG@rMdxVZBm@KmwlFtQLhhpRIt/J@/@TlbnBZGyiZmB5dnioVU1E0JlXqrNTTtFqIolRjHLv2NeolOXMRyV9K4dB4c7m6fuaWysPpsHRzSp09MMN0nl9T1Ct1pjwVuI8LNu6jzj597ZepdL9WMpliWZjHfLXQY0y8flKT4@gkn06K3ab/pvTIUGfb84wSyhbe8vXTTvb@mqLaXX83YdxnrmeRt5i/ev8WTKeps8jb9EvqZNe54bWSnuQoqjpK@K4@iv3z00nqdtt947r8hRllkfENIuzLLHW17ZY@OhNfdb0pDGPlzJSifNHHHv/eH1JU9jxd64efOx05dy@XkvWPkviSjH1S1IvRaOWKqcDTXTxT6YeuaqMN/X5l1EfcsK98zkvy4MMQ6xehUX14u/jMBAI1LtKtjc7ibk/RyrbKidMP7jbFSi1xkW7W5MKIOmvo08Sy8PaoyuHnZmxyfZNRNv7JKFR4D55vhrFUYKD4g5Xqi9IuRYNK/mnJ1KYpNcUse@HgiqISLXl78@5vidtJ9WK77bxcSavG4pGhK1L7kQ1mu3P14/QtkqmMyjVfo3H7GPP5R9PTxMN1cVaJ39WaRj9GLzrV6EPFPx6@F1T67VLg35NZ@u51VWx/fPr1UugrOBXr0Vm19lqfhJe9xuV7avL@NKmsxK@v7ZAdVqrTx5W8CjGfwXrmPkgv5dfLgh74us2NJ4@Dq238YVUP8aOCTx754td3n@OaEXkPZHtFfhajK4n4@LmwUW4y1NndfJJZ3VNn600xpTwt78r8spUZfAblZeVOy2eUROytvv2caexi8JZ6/wrePGbEjvn21DeByfTbufx5gC5eFJXT6ovuM6qf7JS9KfqFSjGfW1Wvov75etoUry77TH6@6rYCzc9Jt3Ofv6eFh7nIpQtS9vaDXQTN2vNFnWUvk6m0f1KfvE18yeVnZ/2YLySHF4nMa2A0S89mFBV9jTDV9nYVoSsjVklfCzXRbHy49nI2p86uUjeDWj@aa1Uvv7j@ar2NnQ9vLgqNLPuyeq3OrjqxB7EZWxtK4raR3c7lzqR6Ox6YeRCdj3IPicamuGnXZ83mVSBQeK5TZ30zVp0BPWHNgIfay@w5@npZfOQTg2k0OyhX5CEdHwbZaCUTe1f7N5pQ3FysAvGL1/OROMltOr1VoMHrmXQkdfdmdl33KbP/jOYTsXojytS3Nf9V/DzVU@oGdaaJp21l4lcf25uo2fm2EsXrykAKb0fj0kf/XCp1K43e8yy@oCimI/hO77OxQG9buBys1uX2cpL8qsnde4Z5ilYbvsDpZNMcF5Z6ul@/nckTs7XRKpm32vY5w2fPxZu7lXJ/Vbte@jepktl3v/Dd81Su/SzQ03leHDDT11p9Vq3yZo/FDqaNOF1oFFafPjEbSzxwwVqnUr6tRc3KK31GH/1Z@ZEJdl8r8a9Qcl3ikqXHu5Q4nFTzjUtj0o28z9ikqgiNbCLbjYsRbnnfnU3G6VtxfKsmFuvbSTi3HmaelFfpopD8uB@wtKF2u8UiOzI7xo@ykObKD2KpUX6s81kxciGzn53wY2mdL4XMdunm6SPcb9bpm9eKwLXqQvdl@Payqq2vQtl36uxJuDMTt6wl2GX0q/H5rKWHyc514zo8XfpG465Ct7VFMT2OXubS@ebsNVGp3Iz7s7uvJymXvPdp9@1OamlWjeaEm3Tn0cqs0@He/O3n09sxdWa2iYmK@lIdrujUJN/N@aSXyqpAUcVq6Z1/8j2OtUhw0ls/S828LPeYbEFPZd/HpxdsosW/3SZmn@vwSJNb6R51VusNYsVW8@6RM5/PbguN@3p0LvUWNTOR@k3xY5urbWPP4ufD8DmdkT9GITbGT/mrz0Hl2hzk9d7Sm/60HZOyUYk@D2elBRs/T5rD5MVNJq290bnBda6Yf2@mPrLDQfm0wcT7l5/xREjY5Grvxn3zfJ2Vuv20dvk6GUXGjeH29UHMRMxOpBt80kZms1V8lum4HL1lMtpduVfIhwbafadm1o5Eaxq5aCZCIdn/@dpO@duf1eRL9C7U891P9XIpNeuGdIVdBzOzwX3vqiXx9PDxaxDs3bYv/b7m5yqhpehssmwWIy2U9PWD/uuP4vKpLgnZ/G2@8exfViZPb74vvhd5M/uyF/pNy43963rSHKh/nZ9r7XyC//hoSVKgOjNr/@27Itbvl7FoRBxsq43yPHXx7PffjrODVDOcD/iDrSVXyn1UZDqpXMwX@fZLv8MFKGpbTLf0mtl3bbdTLvLeSZZXaf71PaNVueiYDvuvE6ur8Vh4HAXm52aLl3x4EsqLs@n0n2VNoMU5Q59oFc2cl5x0T2Q1rJ1Ism5JNye0xJjToKTGWo7fwn7NnDz@y7Phuk9a/auJkX@tldd/raO2/rgWifxvdVI7mZv/U//8s6R5wfxrMjX/NGc9G/bHsqhX/vkPvzyZy7IQXoZNGImcfJ7oE/OvqfnTf6ynktZGT4kJWz/H3d8iEfPH@UmsdpL@5z@sOamzlFeO/I/leU8P@we0prGMP36yip/4O7S1k8AU5pH//R8)

You could probably save more bytes with a smarter regex. Basically, just a tradeoff between longer regex and shorter encoded strings.

`G` is the list of true cases, `H` is a list of false cases. `s in G or` makes it so if it's a true case, it gets marked as such. `s not in H and` makes it so if it's a false case, it gets marked as such. If neither is true, then it is checked with the regex `/seil|ie(?!ng|sm)|eing|eism/`. Finding a longer regex to match even just like 3-4 more words is certainly worth it, I just didn't want to spend too much time.

Comment: `zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(x)).decode().split()` saves a few bytes. And you have quite a few extra backslashes in your base-85 string, you can remove them with this script: https://tio.run/##bY5BCoMwEEX3OcXHTSpuKt2Fpmfo3slC0qEGREMMtp4@TarQTVfDZ96b@X6Lwzxdkp0fDI1QVZWU8nofe8tYiGJw05MIRAMHJnnL28wkl@GzeA1uZBS3c8ooAcSwlQH0y8Ihgtd@PBWghta/1Cln0Bxm0ypTf6WjxV8iA/y27ON@36HRaIXP/eL@IKUP